# PotW Theme: Christmas and the Holidays

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, themes

Many of us have discussed the option of having "theme" weeks for the Picture of the Week contest. It was recently proposed that the next two weeks after the current contest be themes for Christmas and the Holidays. It seems like no better time to start doing a periodic theme, so without further ado:

---

**Christmas and Holidays 2011 Theme**

The next two context weeks will require all submissions to be Christmas and Holiday themed. Anything related to Thanksgiving, Christmas, Hanukkah, New Years, and any other year-end holiday is acceptable. Things like trees and ornaments, stunning light displays, candle displays, etc. are all acceptable. Try **not** to submit somthing that "sort of" qualifies, like a photo of fall leaves, and anything not specifically related to the holidays would also (obviously) be excluded for the next two weeks (not counting the current week.)

Outside of the theme requirement for the photos themselves, all the rest of the rules will be the same. When each themed contest starts, the theme and theme specific rules will also be included in the contest rules.

Comment: I'm confused, the title has a question mark in it, but the description makes it sound like the decision has already been made. Is this just an informational post telling me to prepare some shots, or is this asking for votes to determine if this will actually be a theme?

Comment: Like dpollitt, I'm a bit confused about the purpose of this question/post. Is this a done deal, or are we supposed to post for and against answers that people can vote on, or is this the actual photo submission thread, or what?

Comment: I found this question's link on the top corner of the main page, and not sure why I thought this is the photo competition thread. :banghead: :)

Comment: I took this, "It seems like no better time to start doing a periodic theme, so without further ado:", as it's official. So I think this was just giving everybody a heads up.

Comment: @dpollit: Yeah, I accidentally typed a question mark, however StackExchange will not let me change it to an exclamation mark (which I intended). Vian has it nailed...I figured we might as well start themes when we have a really easy reason to do a really fun theme. So consider this a "Were doing this!" post! :) Additionally, this post is simply informative, nothing more...you do not need to submit any photos here (and preferably should not.)

Comment: It seems that since SEN is a "Q&A Forum", ending questions in an '!' is a hard-coded NO-NO. I've removed the ?, hopefully that alleviates the confusion.

Comment: FYI there's a recent meta SO question about that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/stop-rewriting-trailing-exclamation-marks-as-question-marks

Answer (score 1):

The Themed Christmas idea was fairly well received, generating some great pictures.  This has led to two follow-up questions.  One for [Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/picture-of-the-week-theme-ideas) and one for the [official line on themes](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes).

The winners for the Christmas Theme were:

[**26 December 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1746)
[Express Delivery - Matt Grum http://www.mattgrum.com/photo_se/express_delivery.png](http://www.mattgrum.com/photo_se/express_delivery.png)

[**19 December 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1726)
[image: The Snowman vs. the Flame - jrista]