# Weekly Featured Image: Dec 19, '11 (HOLIDAY THEME!)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 18 December** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Dec 18th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

### **THEME: CHRISTMAS and the HOLIDAYS**

**This week we are introducing PotW themes!** For the next two weeks, all submissions must conform to the `Christmas and Holidays 2011` theme. Anything related to the holidays, including Thanksgiving, and continuing up through the New Year, is acceptable. Shots of Christmas Tree Ornaments, Christmas decorations, Hanukkah, super-tasty holiday dishes and treats, light displays, etc. etc. all qualify. If you wish to submit something for a non-western holiday, feel free to do so, however please provide some information explaining the holiday and if possible, a link to Wikipedia or something similar. Additionally, please refrain from submitting photos that "sorta-kinda might qualify", such as late fall scenery, or simple photos of snow covered landscapes. Make sure there is something key and central to the shot, in the frame, that makes it a HOLIDAY shot! :)

As a theme rule, anything that does not qualify and is not removed on request will be deleted before the end of the contest, to keep things on-theme.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/weekly-featured-image-nov-28-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: "Last week's thread" points to Nov. 28th, 2011 thread.

Comment: +1 for themes!!

Comment: Everyone who submitted this week, PLEASE feel free to resubmit your items for the next two contests if you don't win! There have not yet been any submissions for this weeks contest, and some of the ones this week were pretty good.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### [The Snowman vs. the Flame](http://jon-rista.deviantart.com/art/Snowman-vs-the-Flame-273276709)

[image]

One of a recent series of shots taken when I was house-bound due to an injured back. I'd been stuck inside for days, and needed to do something to take my mind off of pain. I had a bunch of Christmas ornaments and holiday miniature stuff laying around, and I decided to take some still-life shots.

Comment: Awesome bokeh in this one.. telling a story.

Comment: I like it, it looks like a fun to arrange shot. :)

Comment: Cute! I like the "fire".

Comment: Well thought out and perfectly executed. Up voted!

Comment: This is really nice.

Comment: are you trying for this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/07/holidays-around-the-world-smashing-photo-contest/

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all the votes guys!! I didn't intend to steal the show this week...I just wanted to give people an example of what the theme was about.

Comment: @akshay1188: Hmm, I wasn't explicitly going for that...it looks like submissions are closed now, though, so I'm too late. Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: JoanneC: Aye, it was pretty fun! I'm actually working on a blog entry that explains how to do it, hopefully to give people some food for thought for the next couple weeks submissions. I'll show everyone how I did it, and some of the other shots I made.

Answer (score 12):

## [Christmas Tree](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/5243335837/)

[image]

Bit late but thought I'd give it a go anyway. :) The original is [on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/5243335837/) - I'm flipped it for this version as I thought that'd look better on the site.

Comment: Great light(filler text)

Comment: I like this shot. Great contrast, and that little tree is awesome.

Answer (score 9):

### [**~ It's almost Christmas ~**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sarego/6421425293/in/photostream)

[image: It's almost Christmas]

Taken at the Empire state building, NYC. 
They had two giant Christmas trees covered in ornaments in the lobby and looked really gorgeous.
Full Size photo [in Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sarego/6421425293/in/photostream)

Comment: Nice shot. The background bokeh could be fantastic if it was a bit farther away (or shot with a wider aperture, or shot from farther away with a fast telephoto). Out of curiosity...is that a wreath in the foreground?

Comment: thank you! Nope it is a christmas tree.

Answer (score 5):

## Christmas lights

[image: Christmas lights]

0.5s exposure of a Christmas tree with [deliberate movement](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17504/4039/why-would-one-shoot-a-fully-blurred-picture) of camera.

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-12-16).

Answer (score 3):

## Trimming the tree for the first time

[image]

It's amazing to me how serious everything is at this age...

Larger version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/reknight/6495671717/). Photo I would have entered but didn't meet size requirements [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/reknight/6495587463/in/set-72157628379222039/)

Comment: I really like the one that didn't meet size requirements. There is nothing against composing multiple shots...any way you could combine the vertical one with any other shots and make it fit in a wide format?

Comment: Thanks, never occurred to me to try to make a composite of the two photos. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 3):

The Happy Couple

[image]

I think jrista's gonna run away with it this week (I already voted for him), but I wanted there to be more entries this week, so [here it is](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/6508008619/)...

Comment: I love the figure! Think you could put together a more intriguing scene, maybe with some christmas light bokeh in the background? These little guys have SO much potential! :D

Comment: They are actually fixed to the wood background (see the black arms/springs on the sides?).  They are part of (what I recall was) a cuckcoo clock of some kind.  It was in my sister-in-law's house last Christmas.  I'll be back there next week, so I'll see what I can do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Same as last time when I got a runner up.

[image: Christmas Toys]

Comment: Ah, I remember this one from last year. Hopefully you'll have another chance to win this year.

Answer (score 2):

[image: angel]

My first submission to a photo contest ever! No flickr account yet. Happy Holidays!

Comment: Welcome aboard! :) We will have two more weeks of holiday theme potw's. Be creative with that angel, and see if you can put it in more "themed" surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reflection

[image: Reflection]

[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kiril_kirov/6522230781/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Christmas Lights!]