# Photo of the Week Theme Ideas Archive

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, themes

This thread contains all past ideas for the Theme of the Week. Ideas submitted by members in the PotW Theme Ideas thread will be copied here, and any ideas created by a moderator if there were no other community submitted ideas will also be tracked here. Please check this list FIRST before submitting a theme idea.

| Theme | Ran on |
| --- | --- |
| [Reflections](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7124/) | [2022-06-06](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129502/) |
| [Star Trail](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7242/) | [2022-04-25](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129205/) |
| [Claustrophobic](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7240/) | [2022-04-11](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129081/) |
| [Famous Buildings](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/) | [2022-03-28](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128968/) |
| [Freezing or Melting](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7231/) | [2022-03-14](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128851/) |
| [Cross-section](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7228/) | [2022-02-28](//photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128742/) |
| [Death](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7224/) | [2022-02-14](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128645/) |
| [Manipulations](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7223/) | [2022-01-31](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128477/) |
| [Wood](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7214/) | [2022-01-17](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/128315/) |
| [Environmental Destruction](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7208/) | [2022-01-03](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128177/) |
| [Shot with film](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7206/) | [2021-12-20](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128032/) |
| [Sliver](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7202/) | [2021-11-29](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126838/) |
| [Landscapes](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7196/) | [2021-11-15](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126700/) |
| [No Landscapes](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7194/) | [2021-11-01](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126574/) |
| [Black and White, Metaphorically](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7193/) | [2021-10-18](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126471/) |
| [Festivals](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7187/) | [2021-10-04](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126354/) |
| [Metal on metal](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7181/) | [2021-09-20](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126200/) |
| [Relationships](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7178/) | [2021-09-06](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126078/) |
| [Cats](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7174/) | [2021-08-23](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/125915/) |
| [Food](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7173/) | [2021-08-09](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/125744/) |
| [Music](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7169/) | [2021-07-26](//photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125609/photo-competition-2021-07-26-music) |
| [Surprise!](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7168/) | [2021-07-19](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/125555/) |
| [Inspired by Photo-SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7163/) | [2021-07-05](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/125387/) |
| [Street Photography](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7160/) | [2021-06-22](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/125278/) |
| [Long exposure](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7158/) | [2021-06-09](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/125104/) |
| [Symmetry](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7154/) | [2021-05-24](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/124948/) |
| [In Deep Thought](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7153/) | [2021-05-10](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/124789/) |
| [Typography](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7145/) | [2021-04-26](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/124613/) |
| [All Blur](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7132/) | [2021-04-12](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/124455/) |
| [Up There](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7126/) | [2021-03-29](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/124247/) |
| [Transportation](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7125/) | [2021-03-15](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/122987/) |
| [Straight out of camera](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7123/) | [2021-02-15](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/122599/) |
| [Reflections](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7124/) | [2021-01-15](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/122805/) |
| [Lomography](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7121/) | [2020-05-12](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/116976/) |
| [Imperfectly Beautiful](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7122/) | [2020-02-01](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/114433/) |
| [Portraits by Candlelight](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7119/) | [2020-01-20](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/114104/) |
| [Tis the season for a fresh start](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7120/) | [2019-12-12](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/113600/) |
| [Science](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2623/) | [2012-08-06](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2405/) |
| [The Classical Elements: Fire](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2029/) | [2012-04-02](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2125/) |
| [The Classical Elements: Water](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2029/) | [2012-03-19](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2073/) |
| [The Classical Elements: Earth](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2029/) | [2012-03-12](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2028/) |
| [The Classical Elements: Air](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2029/) | [2012-03-05](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2056/) |
| Christmas and the Holidays | [2011-12-12](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1726/) |

Answer (score 0):

### The Classical Elements

This would be a four-week series, with one each for

- Earth
- Air
- Water
- Fire

(I made this one proposal rather than four as it would be nice to see them run all in a row..)

---

**Originally proposed by:** [mattdm](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm)
**Ran on:** March 5, 12, 19, 26, 2012

Answer (score 0):

### Science

Any subject that is related to science, or the study of science.

Examples:

- Refracting light
- Scientific instruments
- Fluids
- Astrophotography
- Magnetism
- Chemical reactions
- Biological processes

---

**Originally proposed by:** [maynard-case](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2127/maynard-case)
**Ran on:** Aug 6, 2012

Answer (score 0):

### Portraits by Candlelight

Inspired by [Is it practical to shoot portraits by only candlelight?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17116/is-it-practical-to-shoot-portraits-by-only-candlelight), but not, I promise, as an excuse to submit the ones I already took. I want to see what everyone else can come up with!

---

**Originally proposed by:** [mattdm](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm)
**Ran on:** [Jan 14 – Jan 29, 2020](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/114104/)

Answer (score 0):

### Tis the season for a fresh start

The concept of the theme combines the winter season with the idea of fresh starts. Give us your best seasonal photo, or your favorite new beginning. Bonus points for new starts with a seasonal flair!

---

**Originally proposed by:** [scottbb](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11924/scottbb)
**Ran on:** [December 16–30, 2019](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/113600/)

Answer (score 0):

### Lomography

The challenge is to post the best picture that would fall short of "professional" photographic standards. For example, photos taken on old or cheap digital cameras that have low resolution, photos taken on long-expired film, or photos which exhibit significant "mistakes" such as light leaks. For more information, see the [Wikipedia article on lomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomography).

For clarity, the word "lomography" refers to the genre of photography, not to the photographic brand Lomography. Photos submitted need not necessarily be taken on Lomography-brand equipment.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [gparyani](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/77292/gparyani)
**Ran on:** [May 12 – June 1, 2020](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/116976/)

Answer (score 0):

### Imperfectly Beautiful

This theme challenges you to find beauty in unexpected places. Appreciating it not only in spite of imperfections, but perhaps even because of them.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [LightBender](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/68136/lightbender)
**Ran on:** [February 1–14, 2020](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/114433/)

Answer (score 0):

### Straight out of camera

This theme seeks your best straight-out-of-camera JPEGs. This also means no processed raw images: shoot RAW+JPEG if you want, but only submit the JPEG produced from the camera.

Scans of film shots are welcome to submit too. Please use your best judgment as to what constitutes "creative darkroom techniques" or scan touchups. Follow the spirit of the rule as best as you can.

There's no way to enforce the SOC rule, this is all on the honor system. Let's have some fun and see what we can get, Polaroid-style. =)

---

**Originally proposed by:** [scottbb](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11924/)
**Ran on:** [Feburary 15 – March 1, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/122599/), [June 6–19, 2022](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/129502/)

Answer (score 0):

### Reflections

The theme of this contest is simple: photos where mirrors, windows, water, or other reflective surfaces were used to get reflections.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [Eric S](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/60648/eric-s)
**Ran on:** [March 1–15, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/122805/11924)

Answer (score 0):

### Transportation

The theme of this contest is simply transportation. Trains, cars, ships, planes, bicycles, etc.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [Matt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/80733/matt)
**Ran on:** [March 15–29, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/122987/)

Answer (score 0):

### Up There

Subjects in the photo should be unsupported by the ground. Examples include airplanes, balloons, bubbles, water splashes, astrophotography, clouds, birds/insects/animals in flight, etc.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [whackamadoodle3000](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/97631/whackamadoodle3000)
**Ran on:** [March 29 – April 12, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/124247/)

Answer (score 0):

### All Blur

In the spirit of [Why would one shoot a fully blurred picture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/17504), let's see some abstract and semi-abstract works.

---

**Originally proposed by**: [mattdm](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1943)
**Ran on**: [April 12–26, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/124455/)

Answer (score 0):

### Typography

A photo with a focus on typography. Letters, numbers, words and so on. The shapes of them, the layout or where they're placed. Address numbers on buildings are sometimes quite interesting. Writing on roads, signs and so on.

I imagine the focus being on the presentation of the words, rather than the meaning of them but I can see that latter working too.

<s>We would probably have to avoid trade mark slogans and logos though, but I'm not exactly sure on the legality of that. Aside from legal reasons, SE or the Logo's company may not want to be associated with each other as the photo would be in a prominent place on the site.</s> *[Note: I didn't run the contest with this caveat. Probably not an issue. –scottbb]*

---

**Originally proposed by:** [Vian Esterhuizen](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4124/vian-esterhuizen)
**Ran on:** [April 26 – May 10, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/124613/11924)

Answer (score 0):

### In Deep Thought

Capture a photo of a subject that demonstrates "deep thought", contemplation, intense musing, etc. The subject may be a person or animal, even an inanimate object, so long as the key concept of deep thought is the central focus of the photograph.

**Requirements**

1. The subject of the photo must be in, or appear to be in, deep thought
2. *Should* be a portrait shot of a person, people, or pets/animals

   - Self portraits are allowed
   - Inanimate objects or trees may qualify, but only if they depict deep thought
   - An example might be the contorted silhouette of a tree that emulates a person in deep thought
   - Another example might be a statue, small, large, even huge, that depicts deep thought
3. The *object* of the subject's thought can be anything

   - i.e. Another person
   - i.e. The sky
   - i.e. The relationship between *being* and *time*, wherein each reciprocally determines the other, yet the former cannot be addressed temporally, nor can the the latter be expressed as a being.
   - i.e. Chocolate-pecan pie

---

**Originally proposed by**: [Aquarius_Girl](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5205/aquarius-girl)
**Ran on**: [May 10 – May 24, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/124789)

Answer (score 0):

### Symmetry

The photograph must display some form of symmetry.

---

**Originally proposed by**: [Maynard Case](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2127/maynard-case)
**Ran on**: [May 24 – June 6, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/124948/photo-competition-2021-05-24-symmetry?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

### Long Exposure

Either a picture containing motion blur (star trails, cars on a road etc.) or a combination of several photos to create a time-lapse in one photo.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [damned truths](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths)
**Ran on:** [June 9–21, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/125104/)

Answer (score 0):

### Street Photography

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_photography) says it quite well:

> A type of documentary photography that features subjects in candid
> situations within public places such as streets, parks, beaches,
> malls, political conventions and other settings.

I feel that's a fairly broad theme, and basically anyone with any type of camera can take a photograph like this. Also, I think it would help a lot of us, including me, get over the self consciousness of carrying a camera and photographing in public.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [Vian Esterhuizen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4124/vian-esterhuizen)
**Ran on:** [June 22 – July 5 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/125278/)

Answer (score 0):

### Inspired by Photo-SE

Craft a picture that was inspired by a question, answer, or comment here. Include a link to the inspiration (and a sentence or two about how you got from the original question to your photo).

---

**Originally proposed by:** user2910
**Ran on:** [July 5–19, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/125387/)

Answer (score 0):

### Surprise!

Any photo that will surprise the viewer.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [Caleb](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4262/caleb)
**Ran on:** [July 19–26, 2021](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/125555/)

Answer (score 0):

### Music

Either *literal* (instruments, musicians, performance) or figurative (geometric or natural patterns which evoke the patterns of music).

---

**Originally proposed by**: [mattdm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm)
**Ran on**: [July 26 – August 9, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125609/photo-competition-2021-07-26-music)

Answer (score 0):

### Food

Candidates can be:
**•** A mouth watering cooked dish.
**•** Raw vegetables.
**•** Raw fruits.
**•** Desserts.
**•** Beverages like tea, juices etc.

---

**Originally proposed by**: [Aquarius_Girl](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/5205/aquarius-girl)
**Ran on**: [August 9–23, 2021](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/125744/)

Answer (score 0):

### Cats

Pictures of your cats. Kittens. Cats in baskets. Cats hanging from stuff. Cats in costumes. Cats with things on their heads. More kittens. Cats making funny expressions. Cats on fire, perhaps from attempts to shoot them by candlelight. Possibly lions. Cats, cats, cats.

---

**Originally proposed by**: [mattdm](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm)
**Ran on**: [August 23 – September 6, 2021](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/125915/)

Answer (score 0):

### Relationships

A photo which shows a two (or more) people sharing moment. Like Mom-kids, Father-kids, Siblings, Person-pet, Person-Teacher.

---

**Originally proposed by**: [Sudarshan Kadam](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9677/sudarshan-kadam)
**Ran on**: [September 6 – September 19, 2021](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126078/11924)

Answer (score 0):

### Metal on metal

All things metallic. Gears, heavy machinery, drilling metal, cutting metal...

---

**Originally proposed by:** [spikey_richie](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/94572/spikey-richie)
**Ran on:** [September 20 – October 4, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/126200/)

Answer (score 0):

### Festivals

Capture a photo of a scene that demonstrates a "*festival celebration*", or something which highlights what the festival is about, etc. The subject may be a person or a group of people, or even an inanimate object, so long as the key concept of festive season is the central focus of the photograph.

Festival doesn't have to be *necessarily* something "*official*" like *Christmas*. People may have local customs and hence accordingly local festivals too.

So, any sort of festival pictures are welcomed.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [Aquarius_Girl](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/5205/aquarius-girl)
**Ran on:** [October 4–20, 2021](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/126354/)

Answer (score 0):

### Black and White, Metaphorically

In this theme, black and white should be represented *conceptually*, not literally.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [mattdm](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1943)
**Ran on:** [October 18 – November 1, 2021](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126471/)

Answer (score 0):

### No Landscapes

As many of the photos have been landscapes, I think we should try to encourage photos that are not landscapes and more macro, portraits etc.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [damned truths](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths)
**Ran on:** [November 1–14, 2021](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126574/)

Answer (score 0):

### Landscapes

Candidates:
 1. Open wide areas with some point of interest.
 2. Mountains/Valleys.

Open wide areas are a must. "Close ups" shots of a tree/hut won't be acceptable.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [Aquarius_Girl](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/5205/aquarius-girl)
**Ran on:** [November 15–28, 2021](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126700/)

Answer (score 0):

### Sliver

An image that captures only a small part of a much larger whole.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [LightBender](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/68136/lightbender)
**Ran on:** [November 29 – December 19 2021](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/126838/)

Answer (score 0):

### Shot with Film

Kodak Portra, Tri-X, Ilford Delta, Fujicolor Pro, ... any film you want, digitized however is convenient — but shot on film, with minimal digital post-production.

Entries should be photographs taken recently, well into the digital era, rather than older works. There's no way to enforce this, of course, but please follow it in the spirit of the theme.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [mattdm](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm)
**Ran on:** [December 20, 2021 – January 3, 2022](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128032/11924)

Answer (score 0):

### Environmental Destruction

Deforestation, plastic pollution, chemical spills, quarrying, deliberate burning.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [niemiro](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/44811/niemiro)
**Ran on:** [January 3–16, 2022](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128177/)

Answer (score 0):

### Wood

Living wood, dead wood, burning wood, wood with nails or screws. Pictures that elicit the smell of resin or sawdust.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [xenoid](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/75947/xenoid)
**Ran on:** [January 17–31, 2022](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128315/11924)

Answer (score 0):

### Manipulations

Something heavily 'photoshopped' - replaced backgrounds, inserted people or objects, etc. The resulting image can be pseudo-naturalistic or abstract.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [Tetsujin](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/57929/tetsujin)
**Ran on:** January 31 – February 13, 2022

Answer (score 0):

### Death

Photos with dead stuff. Examples can include decomposing matter, dead trees/plants/animals, animals with their prey, food that was once alive (plant, fungi, or meat based), or other symbolic representations of death.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [whackamadoodle3000](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/97631/whackamadoodle3000)
**Ran on:** [Februrary 14–27, 2022](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128645/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Cross-section

A piece of fruit cut in half, the inside of a model, the end of a building under construction, where the end wall is missing...

---

**Originally proposed by:** [spikey_richie](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/94572/)
**Ran on:** [February 28 – March 13, 2022](//photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128742/photo-competition-2022-02-28-cross-section)

Answer (score 0):

### Freezing or Melting

Anything that is frozen or melting, literally or metaphorically. Examples include anything to do with snow/ice, movement that is frozen, something that is "frozen through time", a chocolate or candle melting, or someone having a meltdown.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [whackamadoodle3000](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/97631/)
**Ran on:** [March 14–27, 2022](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128851/)

Answer (score 0):

### Famous Buildings

Any structure that is know relatively widely. It could also include not just buildings but structures such as tunnels, radio masts etc.

For example: the Eiffel Tower; Sydney Opera House; Statue of Liberty; St. Peter's Basilica; the Great Wall of China; Taipei 101; Sagrada Familia; The Mezquita (in Córdoba).

---

**Originally proposed by:** [damned_truths](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/)
**Ran on:** [March 28 – April 11, 2022](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128968/)

Answer (score 0):

### Claustrophobic

Photos of enclosed spaces, or confined areas. Anything like small areas (think opposite of landscape/open spaces)

---

**Originally proposed by:** [BruceWayne](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/57637/)
**Ran on:** [April 11–24, 2022](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129081/)

Answer (score 0):

### Star Trail

A long exposure shot of a beautiful star trail.

---

**Originally proposed by:** [Soham](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/44923/)
**Ran on:** [April 25 – May 9, 2022](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129205/)