# Why have my posts been deleted here on - photo of the week ideas?

Tags: discussion

[Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/photo-of-the-week-theme-ideas?rq=1)

My posts have been deleted by a moderator.
They had lot of upvotes. Why have they been deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideas are deleted as they are used. This is the only practical way to keep the page in a state where people can see which ideas are "active".

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the explanation. I did not know that they were actually used.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl Hi, yes, I deleted them as they were used. They're not listed by user in the top table, but the themes used, with their "ran on" date and who suggested it, are listed at [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1741/photo-of-the-week-theme-ideas-archive)

Comment: @scottbb thank you for the explanation