# Anouncements of the theme of the week in ADVANCE

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to let the public know in ADVANCE the themes for the next n weeks?

Reason: In order to "create" a photograph for submission one needs to know the topic. If the competition starting time and the topic announcement time is SAME then people won't get the time to "create" the photographs, and they won't be able to participate fully, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually the case. Not only that, we had the announcement thread linked in the header on the main page, so everyone would know ahead of time:

[PotW Theme: Christmas and the Holidays](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1704/potw-theme-christmas-and-the-holidays)

Were doing themes for at least two weeks, maybe we can do them until the end of the year (so three weeks). Given that we announced this theme on Dec. 5th, and that it is ongoing for several weeks, that should be enough time for people to plan and take shots.

Comment: Question: 1. Will this themes thing go on for ever now OR is it only for Christmas or other special occasions?

Comment: We won't always have themes every week. The mods and other core members have chatted a few times in the photose chat room. We figure maybe once a month is probably good. They would always be announced ahead of time, to give everyone time to get a shot that fits the theme, and they would be run pretty much like this one. All other weeks would be normal weeks. We don't want to do themes too frequently, as that would probably greatly reduce the amount of submissions, as not everyone will be able to take a photo that qualifies. We still want to allow people to simply submit their best work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. :) But, perhaps having an "easy" theme would help. Like: "happiness", "sadness", "hungriness" etc. Also, asking people what theme would they like to have for the next week might help.:) Well, anyway it is your decision, but thanks for the info. :)

Comment: Try this: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes :-)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that before.

Comment: I just created it, largely in response to your questions. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it does. :) Asking people what they want is a better way to make the site successful, IMO.