# Photo of the Week Theme Ideas

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, themes

This is the official thread for submitting theme ideas for the [Photo of the Week competition](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7109/).

Whenever a new photo contest rolls around (currently they are running bi-weekly) we will take the top-voted idea from this thread, move it to the archive thread, and start a theme announcement thread linked from the PhotoSE header. If, for any reason, a theme week is canceled or a theme idea is determined impractical for that week, it will be returned to the pool here, and the next highest one used.

**Rules for Submitting Ideas**

1. **ONE idea per answer**
2. Multiple answers per member are allowed, but *please don't spam suggestions*. We're aiming for quality, not quantity.
3. Check the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first

   - Don't submit ideas that have already been done
4. Duplicates will be deleted (so check this thread first, too!)
5. Photo-SE is an unrestricted public site that the underage can visit

   - Please keep ideas civil and legal!
6. **Vote up for the ones you *like!!***

As with the PotW contest, please refrain from down votes. If a particularly offensive theme is suggested, that is a time to flag for moderator attention and comment.

Comment: I've converted this thread to wiki, so it can be freely edited. I think it would be helpful to allow improvements and refinements to any idea to be made by the community as a whole. PLEASE discuss major edits with the originator before making them, however, so you don't dilute their original intent. Minor edits such as to clarify an original concept or expand an original concept with greater detail are acceptable without prior consultation.

Comment: I think we are well past the point where the plethora of 40 already used themes are ALL superior to pretty much ANY of the 15 remaining unused ones.

Answer (score 9):

**Geometric.**

This could be a pattern on a piece of cloth, a vase, a plate... Or it could be repeating patterns in nature, such as the leaves on a succulent, a spider's web, honeycomb in a bee hive...

Answer (score 7):

## Spring.

Seems rather appropriate, this time of year.
Get out. Shake off those winter cobwebs. Feel the new spark of life.

Comment: Hmm. Might have to pull an "executive privilege" and elevate this for timeliness purposes. Otherwise, this would almost certainly pop off-season...

Comment: On the other hand, if it's meant to be "current", it suffers from being north/south hemisphere-specific.

Comment: I suppose that's going to be true for many things, from seasons to 'mother's day'… we all have them at different times :)

Answer (score 6):

### Renaissance

Now that we have [guidelines on achieving various Renaissance styles](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18696/how-to-reproduce-renaissance-painting-styles-in-photography), why not put them into use? If a photo can communicate values of Renaissance era in some other way, that'd be welcome too.

Answer (score 3):

### Bespoke

Photographs that:

1. show a custom made or crafted object, or the process of making a bespoke thing; **and**
2. are bespoke for this contest — that is, created after the contest has begun.

Comment: I like both parts of this, but it feels like they should be two separate themes. It will be hard to judge the two categories against each other.

Comment: @LightBender Hmm. I wasn't thinking of it as 2 categories. I was suggesting a theme for photos that show a custom object (or the crafting of it), and the photo was taken _for this contest_. That is, not one-or-the-other, but both conditions.

Comment: @LightBender I've made a slight edit. Does that improve the theme or clarity?

Comment: yes, the "and" makes it much more clear 

Answer (score 3):

**Sleep**

Photos of people or animals asleep, pictures of occupied beds or nests, piles of leaves etc.

Also pictures of "sleeping" landscapes - eg winter scenes, quiet towns, empty buildings

Comment: This is interesting, but I wonder if your 2nd paragraph might be too open for interpretation.  Does an empty building imply sleep, or decay/abandonment? (I suppose the _nature_ of the emptiness matters: empty because it's just after hours / holiday, or because the business has shut down...). Hmm.

Comment: @scottbb - I wanted to open it up to some less literal ideas of "sleep" as well, but am not sure how to phrase that (I hope the photographers will be more creative about it than me)

Answer (score 3):

### **Forced perspective**

According to Wikipedia: "a technique which employs optical illusion to make an object appear farther away, closer, larger, or smaller than it actually is"

Answer (score 3):

### Unplanned

An image where something unexpected happened that was better than what you had planned to shoot. For example, trying to capture a picture of a flower only to have a bee land on it as you hit the shutter.

Answer (score 2):

## Nuclear and Radiological

Radioactive chemicals or signage in scientific laboratories, medical facilities, military weapons or power stations.

Also including human or physical damage caused by radiation, such as power station meltdowns and environmental contamination.

Plus the positives: patients undergoing radiotherapy, rifle sights etc.

Comment: This one seems... particularly dangerous, if you get my drift. I'm sure most people don't have access to high power nuclear centers, or don't live near one, or don't want to get near one.

Answer (score 1):

**Calmness**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calmness):

> Calmness is the mental state of peace of mind being free from
> agitation, excitement, or disturbance.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calmness) It also refers being in a
> state of serenity, tranquillity, or peace.[2] Calmness can most easily
> occur for the average person during a state of relaxation, but it can
> also be found during much more alert and aware states.[3]

Answer (score 1):

**Old Town Alleys**

Residential streets in old towns, maybe cobblestone, flower pots, etc. Not people.

This has some relation to 'street photography' but I think it has enough different focus to be worthy by itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Ethereal**

Hazy, soft, dream-like images.

Comment: So, taken with either Vaseline smeared on it, or pantyhose stretched across? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Frozen Lake**

As winters are going on. Hence, I think it can be a good theme for the week in which travellers/photographers can share the pictures of frozen lake.

Comment: I guess this could have been covered under https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128851/photo-competition-2022-02-28-freezing-or-melting/, but is also quite a specific subject.

Answer (score 0):

### [Chiaroscuro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiaroscuro)