# Picture of the Week Theme: Classical Elements 'Fire' for week of April 2, '12

Tags: discussion, themes, featured-photo

### Picture of the Week Theme Announcement

The first community-elected Picture of the Week [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) will be running for the week of March 12th, 2012. The theme is [The Classical Elements, 'Air'](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1750/124), one of a four-part series of elemental themes. We are announcing this theme today to give our membership time to go out and capture photos that comply with the theme rules.

This theme was recommended by [mattdm](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm).

---

**March 5th -- Elements: 'Earth'**

**Marth 12th -- Elements: 'Air'**

***Marth 19th -- Elements: 'Water'***

**April 2nd -- Elements: 'Fire'**

All photos must involve these primordial elements in some way or another. Keep in mind, a normal picture of a landscape probably won't quite do it for earth, neither will a simple photo of water or fire or clouds, you'll need to get more creative than that. ;) I think we can allow for "opposites" or "complements" type photos, where in two elements are intertwined. If you don't win with such a photo the first week, feel free to submit it again for any other week so long as it conforms to that weeks theme.

*Official Description from [Ideas Thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/picture-of-the-week-theme-ideas):*

### The Classical Elements

This would be a four-week series, with one each for

- **Earth**
- Air
- Water
- Fire

(I made this one proposal rather than four as it would be nice to see them run all in a row..)

---

This theme was recommended as a four part, four week theme. As PotW themes are a relatively new idea we are trying out here on PhotoSE, I would like to offer the community the opportunity to choose how we play this one out. The options are:

- **Four consecutive weeks**
- **First week of each month for four months**

If you have an opinion, please vote up the matching answer below, and we'll conduct the theme that way. Voting can continue until the week the theme runs, as we would need to announce the next theme right away if they are to be consecutive weeks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Option 1: Four consecutive weeks

Vote up this option if you would like to see the entirity of @mattdm's theme recommendation run four weeks in a row. The weeks the theme would run would be:

- March 5, 2012
- March 12, 2012
- March 19, 2012
- March 26, 2012

Comment: Just so everyone knows, this is official. If you do win one week, the standard rule about not being able to enter the next week will STILL APPLY. To Imre's point, if you take photos of the full series, PLEASE LINK TO IT! We'll all love to see what you've come up with. Flickr, 500px, 1x, etc. are all capable of hosting your work, not to mention offering great ways to display it.

Answer (score 3):

### Option 2: First week of each month for four months

Vote up this option if you would like to see @mattdm's theme recommendation run the first full week of the month for four months in a row. The weeks the theme would run would be:

- March 5, 2012
- April 2, 2012
- May 7, 2012
- June 4, 2012

Answer (score 1):

If the consecutive-weeks option wins out, will we relax the rule about not being allowed to submit a picture if you're the currently-featured photographer?  If someone makes a series of great pictures to fit the theme, and wins one week (or even the week before the Elements theme begins), I'd hate to see them get punished by not allowing them to submit the following week's element.

If you don't mind me hijacking this question, how about just having people vote this answer up or down if they agree or disagree?  Then just leave the rules as-is unless the upvotes significantly outweigh the downvotes.

Comment: I think we can relax the rule a bit for the next week. We could use the number of up/down votes on this answer as a gauge of how the community feels about that, too...if it gets more down votes than up, we'll keep the existing rule in place.

Comment: I'd go farther than that: we're talking about (temporarily) changing a rule that the community agreed on and that has been around for a long time. I'd suggest something like, this answer needs at least half the score of the winning option (which has 9 votes as I type this; so if that doesn't change then this answer would need at least 5). I'm not angling for some meta badge, promise ;) I just think that in order to *change* how we do things, there should be a significant amount of support in favor of it.

Comment: I think a better rule would be that you can submit every week, you just can't win 2 weeks in a row.  If you do finish on top again, the 2nd place vote-getter "wins".  Or the mods can quietly downvote you so you lose by 1 ;)

Comment: The idea behind that rule is to ensure that selection of PotW's represents a bigger share of community. Sometimes it even feels like [the rule is too loose](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/limitations-on-potw-submissions-within-a-given-time-period). A great series can be linked from a contest entry. The primary purpose of contest is to find next PotW, so entries that are ineligible to win should be deleted - they give a false impression of current standing, and may discourage others from posting.