# Weekly Featured Image: April 9, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 9 April** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on April 8th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**THIS WEEK's theme is FIRE**

(And the last of our classical elements series.)

---

This theme is the fourth of a four-week series. The NEXT WEEK will conform to the theme below. Each week will be for a different element: Earth, Air, Water, Fire. The idea is to depict the ancient "Classical Elements", often involved in magic, fundamental to the workings and creation of the universe. Opposing and complementary.

This week's theme is about the **Classical Element of Fire**. All photos must involve this searing element in some way or another. We encourage you to show you creative side here - show us fire in a whole new way.
[See full details about the theme here.](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/picture-of-the-week-theme-classical-elements-air-for-week-of-march-12-12)

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/weekly-featured-image-april-2-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 14):

### Ignition

[image: Match igniting]

A very literal translation of the theme. Bigger version [here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/Gallery/Odds%20and%20Ends/flamewings1.jpg).

Nikon D5000 w. Tamron 70-300 at 135mm, f8, 1/640, ISO 200

Comment: Nice capture. The one thing I'd try to change is to add some fill light so we see the details of the match head.

Comment: Thanks - tricky to add fill light in such a small area with such a fast shutter speed.

Comment: Fill with a poorly focused laser?

Comment: I'm all out of lasers as it happens.

Answer (score 11):

## Vigilante Justice

[image: Vigilante Justice]

Larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/5043819653/in/set-72157624954249951). Probably a little busy for this size, but what the heck, I like the image. :)

Comment: +1 There are no words for how much I like this

Comment: @rfusca - Thank you! :)

Comment: *Burn! Burn! MUHUHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!1* ...Yeah.

Comment: "If you strike me down now I will become more powerful than you can possibly imagine"

Comment: Wow... this definitely gets my vote.

Comment: This town ain't big enough for the two of us. +1

Answer (score 10):

**The Dragon**

[image: The Dragon]

This photo was taken using Canon PowerShot. I was playing with long exposure and trying to draw something using the fire that we set for warming on the lake, I guess I was lucky to get this dragon.

Larger version can be found [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mellice/7040649215/in/photostream)

Comment: voted for you, even though I have myself posted a pic here. :)

Comment: @AnishaKaul Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 7):

**Abstract Flames**

[image]

Very late submission,
an upside down photo of rooibos tea. [Larger Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ksmit/6898561076/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Very nice! Great colours.

Comment: @Jakub thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

### Birth and Death

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Agni - God of fire

[image: Fire]

According to Hindu culture, `Agni` is the god of fire.

Larger version at [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/navaneethkn/6124476780/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 1):

### The forge

[image]