# Weekly Featured Image: April 16, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 16 April** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Apr 16th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/weekly-featured-image-april-9-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 11):

### **White Oak, Red Dawn**

[image]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/6021634)

Answer (score 7):

### Yummy Yummy

[image: Yummy Yummy]

[Large version here](https://picasaweb.google.com/111686726285372367385/Indonesia2011#5719845264059150226)

Answer (score 4):

**Resting**

[image: Resting]

Large version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mellice/7062571245/in/photostream)

Answer (score 4):

**Loner**

[image]

Larger version available at [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/7061168493/lightbox/).

Comment: interesting photo it kinda messes with my brain, the larger version more so. Did you just zoom in, or was it done in post?

Comment: lol, actually both, I was trying out long-exposure-zoom but the effect was not something I was very happy about, so I had to enhance it in post.

Comment: cool, I particularly like the difference in the size and texture in the wall.

Answer (score 2):

**Who is looking at whom?**

[image]

[Larger version](http://mitulnakum.in/picture.php?/90/category/1)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose I might as well make a submission. Black sands of Punakaiki Beach.  I recently traveled to NZ, and this is one of my favorite pictures of the trip.

[image: Black Sands]

[Large version](http://robertdahlstrom.com/2012/03/26/westcoast2.jpg)

Comment: This is quite plainly a macro shot of a pint of Guinness!

Answer (score 1):

**Cutie Pie**

[image: Julianna in 18th century cap]

Comment: I'm posting this mostly because my niece is ZOMG CUTE! in it, not because it's a particularly good photo...

Comment: Without wanting to start any arguments, @Martha, I will state for the record that this *is* a particularly good photo. Backgrounds are easy to change (if you want to morph this from "snapshot" to something other), but there are legions of professional children's portraitists who struggle in vain every day to elicit that sort of expression in their work.

Answer (score 1):

**he doesn't like me**

[image: the duck]

[large](http://my.opera.com/k102/albums/showpic.dml?album=11496932&picture=150157192)

Answer (score 1):

**Abstract spring colors**

[image: Bubbles!]

Larger version on my [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/68578194@N03/7053737987/in/photostream)