# Weekly Featured Image: April 23, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 23 April** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Apr 22nd at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/weekly-featured-image-april-16-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 20):

### Playing In Twilight

[image: PlayingInTwilight]

This was taken on Brean beach in Somerset, England. You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6875401032/).

Comment: +1 like the colors

Comment: +1 .. Great job!

Comment: I see Flickr is doing it's regular rounds of posting random "awards" all over the page. I really dislike those "awards". Great image though, I like.

Comment: They don't give you award unless you post your image in their group and award a few other images yourself! @dpollitt

Answer (score 10):

**Night view of Mysore city**

[image: Night view of Mysore city]

Larger version at - [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/navaneethkn/6995395843/in/photostream)

Comment: Nitpick: This looks like a view from a mountaintop, not from the air, so *"aerial"* is perhaps the wrong word to use.

Comment: Nice colours and composition!

Comment: @Martha - yes. you are correct. changing it to "night view"..Thanks

Comment: @Jakub - Thanks...

Comment: See now, if I was to attempt the identical shot, I would leave out the tree and my image would've only been 5% as good as this one! Nice work!

Comment: @dpollitt - I doubt that :). You have taken amazing photos. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[Pittsburgh Moonrise](http://www.flickr.com/photos/coneslayer/2772359216/in/set-72157604959344927/lightbox/)

Comment: Really nice shot for that lens. I expected you to be the one with the big white lens on a tripod after seeing how clean and sharp this image is.

Comment: The Tamron 70-300 f/4-5.6 has served me well in the bottom half of its zoom range. This was 90mm, f/5.6, and I'm very happy with the sharpness even when pixel-peeping in Lightroom. At the long end, it's not very satisfying, so I got a Pentax DA* 300mm f/4. [ElendilTheTall](http://stdw.us/HRc7ra) just wrote a blog post comparing the Tamron to the Nikon equivalent, and it looks about right to me.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Kipling Station]

[Kipling Station](http://500px.com/photo/6617598)

Comment: Nice composition!

Answer (score 5):

**Still got you!**

[image: Atleast I have got you]

Larger version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/photovolt/6473933893/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 4):

**Elements**

[image: Point Sur Lighthouse]

[Point Sur Lighthouse](http://www.flickr.com/photos/vikask/6895611063/lightbox/)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Mountain Bridge, Austria]

### Mountain Bridge, Austria

A roadway through the Austrian mountains, shot from a train.

Canon EOS 500D, f/8.0, 1/160 s, ISO 100.

Larger version at [**flickr**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/abhranildas/6820166564/).

Answer (score 1):

**Humble**

[image]

[Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/68837326@N06/6950046604/)

Answer (score 1):

### Frozen lake

[image]

[Flickr link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/nunomarquescruz/6844594184/)

Answer (score 0):

**Treeless**

[image: Treeless world]

full image @ http://anubhavsaini.com/exphotos/treeless.jpg