# Weekly Featured Image: April 30, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 30 April** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Apr 29nd at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/weekly-featured-image-april-23-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### **Driftwood**

[image: Driftwood]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/6769505)

Comment: like the colors

Comment: Very nice tone.

Comment: Thank You Appu & Akram!

Comment: +1 really a great photo

Comment: The thing that makes this photo is the water clarity - It adds another dimension to the shot.

Answer (score 10):

Alrighty, 'portrait' has to start having some representation here.  So here's a shot from this weekend.

[image]

85mm, f/1.8, ISO 100, 1/200th

A reflector just filling in a little on camera left.

Minimal post processing

[Bigger Version](http://www.spottsphoto.com/Portfolio/Portfolio/15852003_Vt9dgn).

Comment: Nice shot, great bokeh!

Comment: @Jakub - thanks

Comment: Does the tattoo say "faith not fair"?

Comment: @Vikas - I believe it says 'faith not fear'

Comment: Voting up simply because I think it's time for us to let go of our inhibitions and have a face on PotW. (Nice photo too). I'm assuming she won't mind...

Answer (score 8):

**Spring**

[image: apricot in bloom]

Bigger version [here](http://500px.com/photo/6826977)

Comment: I really like the colours

Comment: +1, but it looks like it could use some brighter whites.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[Bigger here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sridhar/7105322665/). Shot at Ghost Marina, Alviso.

Comment: Good One! Very clean, nice composition! +1

Answer (score 4):

### Yumm Yumm

[image]

[bigger here](https://picasaweb.google.com/111686726285372367385/Indonesia2011#5719845264059150226)

Answer (score 4):

**What's a cuttlefish?**

[image: Cuttlefish]

[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/59920867@N06/6968289604/)

Answer (score 3):

**Butterfly**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### **Big Bunny is Watching You**

[image: bunny, eating grass]

[Bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkVNb.jpg)

Comment: wow bigger is quite larger, that is one big bunny