# Weekly Featured Image: Week of May 7, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 7 May** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on May  6th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/weekly-featured-image-april-30-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Sorry for splitting hairs, but May 6th, not 6nd :-P

Comment: No problem , just a product of copy and pasting ;)

Answer (score 8):

### Old Adidas

[image: OldAdidas]

They've seen better days, but they're well loved! You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/7110273747/).

Answer (score 8):

**Joy Ride**

[image: joy ride]

[Large](http://samsaffron.smugmug.com/Holidays/Smart-Gallery/18479427_zh4pCb#!i=1425970586&k=7wf7ThW) (though I think it works better sized down)
5D Mark 2, f/14 iso 100, 1/5sec at 70mm ... hand held

Captured it in Ubud, Bali last year.

Comment: Awesome! It reminds me of all the people there doing everything by scooter.

Answer (score 7):

Waiting

[image]

[Large](http://www.flickr.com/photos/76980161@N02/6970667310/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Very nice clarity. Making it black & white was a wise decision.

Answer (score 6):

**I Don't do mornings!**

[image]

[Flickr](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8160/6983654620_c3402ccee6_z.jpg)

Comment: I like this, but the color balance looks a little too cool (blue) to me.

Comment: Ya, I'm still learning. It's the sky reflecting off his white fur. I was more excited about taking the picture through the fence.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't suggesting that the color balance was a fatal flaw, but rather suggesting a small tweak that could strengthen your submission. If you need any help adjusting the color balance in whatever software you use, there's a great Q&A site next door! :-)

Answer (score 6):

**Golden Canyon**

[image: **Golden Canyon**]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/7163335)

Answer (score 5):

**Stuck Indoors**

[image: Stuck Indoors]

[Large](http://www.flickr.com/photos/59920867@N06/6982413298/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 5):

**Mountain Bridge, Austria**

[image: Mountain Bridge, Austria]

A roadway through the Austrian mountains, shot from a train.
Larger size on [**flickr**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/abhranildas/6820166564).

Canon EOS 500D F/8.0, 1/160s, ISO 100, 0 EV. Edited in Photoshop.

Answer (score 5):

[Patterns on a manhole cover](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sridhar/6852913654/in/photostream)

[image: Manhole cover]

Answer (score 4):

#### Rifugio Chivasso, Italy

[image: Rifugio Chivasso]

In Italy during a ski touring week.

=> [Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/maxime_tignes/5644782820/in/photostream)

Comment: Nice one! Almost no star trails. My personal favorite this week!

Answer (score 2):

**feathery down**

[image: A feather stuck in the middle of a gutter pipe]

Here is the [larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ksmit/7131023603/in/photostream/) version