# Weekly Featured Image: Week of May 14, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 14 May** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on May  13th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/weekly-featured-image-april-30-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Please change the link of 'Last week's thread' to May 7, not April 30.

Comment: Re "Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide; Images must be in landscape orientation": Would it make sense to combine those to "Images must be 210 px high and 210–375 px wide"?

Answer (score 14):

### Eva

[image]

Bigger version on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/68578194@N03/6987445156/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: +1 - Love it!  Very nice.  (Its better bigger though!)

Comment: Instant +1. Great photo, excellent composition and colour!

Comment: Like it - the shadows look like mountains.

Comment: To me shadow looks like giant pair of wings :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 9):

### Bicycle Against Wall

[image: Bicycle Against Wall]

This is a photo of a bicycle standing against a wall that I took with a Canon EOS 500D in Copenhagen, Denmark, on a backpacking Europe trip last year. It turned out nicer than I had thought.

[Click the photo or here for a larger version.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/abhranildas/6315951656)

Comment: Good photos here this week. This is great!

Answer (score 7):

### Herd of Shells

[image: Herd of Shells by Vian Esterhuizen]

This photo was taken with 49mm of Fotodiox extension tube on a Canon 70-200mm. Each shell is probably around 1-2 cm and it was on a support beam in the ocean. I was standing in waist deep water being knocked around by small waves. The waves, along with the extension tube, made this shot very tough. At points I was just shooting bursts hoping one of the shots would be framed correctly.

[Larger version](http://500px.com/photo/4262483)
<sub>Secret: This is actually a portrait picture with the shells on the side of post but I like this a lot better.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

[image: The Coffee Pot in the Rain]

This shot was a throwaway. When I went to process it I didn't like the rain drop "orbs" in the shot. Fortunately, I didn't delete it and "found" it months later.

Comment: You need to scale this down to the contest dimensions.

Comment: Fixed the size!

Answer (score 3):

****Sunrise****

[image: Sunrise]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/7342461)

Comment: I like the flare, looks a bit like photoshop, but I still like it.

Comment: This photo is beautiful.

Comment: Thanks suknic & Abhranil

Answer (score 3):

### Lost Glasses

[image: Photo]

Took this picture a rainy day. Found some lost glasses on a blue bench, returned them to the police after I was done with them!

Larger image is here: http://500px.com/photo/7340577

Answer (score 1):

### Protector!

[image]

I personally like this years old photo for the memories.
 Unposed spur of the moment.
 Unedited - ie background white is original due to overall lighting. The "bat like" cat was defensive and Janet was using it as a friendly shield.

Janet, daughter of friends of mine, & her cat.
Janet wasn't quite sure that she wanted to be friends with me at first.
The cat was very sure it didn't!
It took a while to persuade it otherwise.

[**Larger version here**](http://public.fotki.com/RussellMc/atw/rm01/janet-her-cat.html).
 For full resolution upload click icon 2nd from right at top of photo.

Answer (score 1):

**Boardwalk**

[image]