# Weekly Featured Image: Week of June 4, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 4 June** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on June 4th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/weekly-featured-image-week-of-may-28-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 13):

Autumn Road

[image: Autumn Road]

This image won the 1. prize in a local photo competition out of 47 submitted photos.

Larger version here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/stroiman/7302404682

Answer (score 12):

### Symmetry

[image]

Bigger [here](http://500px.com/photo/8033764)

Comment: +1 Good one! Like the colours.

Comment: Thanks @Jakub :)

Answer (score 4):

### Brunelleschi's Dome

[image: Brunelleschi's Dome]

Answer (score 4):

**Buzzing around**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Well Red

[image: Red Dinghy]

The Well Red is a small dinghy in Provincetown harbor. Recently I've become fascinated by the paintings of Andrea Sawyer, who manages to paint scenes that are blurry and sharp at the same time. I've been trying to do that with my photography.

This shot is a 15 second exposure, a few hours before sunset, just before golden time really hit but the boat would be in shadow during golden time. It was taken at f22 with a ND400 filter attached to a Canon EF 24-105mm lens set to 105mm. The body was a Canon 40D at ISO 100. Obviously a tripod was used. You really should see the larger version to check out the specular highlights on the prow of the boat. [Larger version here](http://www.notthedeadpaulcezanne.com/Fine-Art-Photography/ProvincetownAndCapeCod/15629656_trwgJk#!i=1873853972&k=CvDXrms)

I sat there for about half an hour watching it sway on the mooring and was particularly amused when another red striped canon lensed photographer stood about next to me, snapped off a quick shot, and walked down the pier. He didn't even wait for it to turn on its mooring, missing the golden light along the starboard side. Oh well, he probably thought I was crazy using a tripod in broad daylight!

Comment: I really like this one in its large version.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it just appears fuzzy small unless you look closely. If you look closely, bam, you see the wave patterns over time.