# Weekly Featured Image: Week of June 18, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 18 June** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on June 18th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2283/weekly-featured-image-week-of-june-4-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Last weeks competition appears to have ended in a tie.  Doesn't that usually mean that this weeks competition should run for two weeks, to allow each of the pictures a week on the front page?

Comment: @forsvarir yup! fixed

Comment: I thought we had agreed to a rule that allowed downvotes, but only for cat pictures?

Comment: @dpollitt — that was for the idea of a _cat theme_ in general. I think you're going to have to _out-compete_ the cat picture here if you want something else. :)

Comment: I'm pretty anti-cat - if the cat photo wins, I'm not sure I can post it in good conscious ;)

Comment: @rfusca: I'm GMT, but it seems like maybe this should have closed by now?

Answer (score 20):

## Winter in Provincetown

[image]

I live in a tourist town, Provincetown Massachusetts to be exact. It is crowded in the summer and pretty empty in the winter. My girlfriend and I had been out night shooting and stopped by our local for a drink. She headed off to the ladies' room and I looked to my right. The place was almost completely empty. So I grabbed my gear (and Susan's Sigma 8-16mm ultra wide), laid the camera on the table and snapped off three shots of 4/5th, 3.2, and 13 seconds at f4 on a Canon 40D crop body, ISO 100. Tone mapped using Photomax Pro.

Click [here for a larger verion](http://www.notthedeadpaulcezanne.com/Fine-Art-Photography/ProvincetownAndCapeCod/15629656_trwgJk#!i=1698141531&k=cTxd5m2)

Comment: I like how relatively subtle your HDR work is. You have some very nice samples in the gallery you link to. I really liked "Richard and Arnold". You should submit it as well - maybe next week?

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 20):

**The Remnants of a Glorious Past**

[image: The Remnants of a Glorious Past]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/7388516)

Comment: Wow. Thank you all for all the votes...

Comment: great work indeed.

Comment: Thunder Bay, sweet!

Comment: I don't get it. Do people really *want* to look at such a grey and depressing picture for a whole week?

Comment: It's that or an empty bar... :- )

Comment: Oh, I think this is a *fantastic* picture! Look at those colors. And the texture in the clouds. Jakub captured the mood of an overcast day perfectly. I would love to be there (well, maybe somewhere similar, a lot farther west), just walking around and taking it all in, whenever I see this picture.

Comment: Thanks @drewbenn! much appreciated. Usually, we are one of the sunniest places in Canada but this year it's more gloomy than ever. After all the flooding we've had I must be the only person who looks out the window in the morning and says: "stormy skies, great!" I am very happy i was able to capture the mood of what I was seeing in an image. ..and yes, grey and depressing were some of the feelings I wanted to invoke with this...

Answer (score 13):

### Family Of Four

[image: FamilyOfFour]

This was taken at Leadenhall Market in the City of London. You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/7319326280/in/photostream).

Comment: +1 Cool title, it creates hidden relationships in the photo. It would be much less impressive without it :)

Comment: I think the rightmost one helps satisfy the rule of odds :)

Answer (score 8):

### Jungle Road

[image: Jungle Road]

Comment: This looks like a scene from Dead Island.

Answer (score 7):

**Alien - Rock Hugger**

[image]

An alien in our world.
 Nicely adapted to its own.

There's a story that I'll add to this shortly, plus a link to a larger image.
 We followed it for some way by its trail. Until we found it we had no idea of what we were following and were duly surprised when we found out.

Comment: Ok, so what the heck *is* it?

Comment: @Martha - wait until I tell the accompanying story :-). To find it we followed its tracks - which were even weirder than it was :-)

Comment: Nice picture, but it's a bit too weird for me to have it in the homepage :)

Comment: It's not at all weird - just not what our brain is used to seeing. I imagine we look similarly strange to it. It's about as big as my hand

Comment: It looks like a kind of crab to me.  Is there more to the mystery than that?

Comment: Where's the story?

Comment: You don't get a story for 2 votes :-) . But no, later maybe.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: I'll reverse it, and say that you won't get more votes without the story :)

Comment: @clabacchio  - I was aware of that when I said it :-). I like the picture. If it needs a story to make it more attractive than eg an (admittedly very cute and cheerful) pussycat then I've misjudged what's required :-).

Comment: So where is the story that we are waiting for?

Answer (score 7):

Oh Hai

[image]

[Flickr](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7104/7323588382_92bcf8126d_z.jpg)

Comment: This is a great photo, sorry everyone is hating on it because it's a cat

Comment: lol, I did notice that. I do like how it came out thou. I didn't even have to edit it!

Answer (score 7):

### **The Demon's Paw**

I've never shown any of my photos online.  I guess this is as good a place as any to start.  So know what happens when you are burning piles of wood from a project and said wood is pressure-treated lumber?  Awesome flame colors.  And the occasional fire demon trying to escape from Hell.

[image]  [Here's a bigger version.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/80159901@N05/7178714321/)

Comment: Pretty. Don't breathe the smoke! 
Beware burning fibrolite sheet - it literally explodes - sometimes after a considerable while.

Comment: Yes, the flames are quite toxic.  The green flame comes from mercury in the wood treatment!

Answer (score 4):

#### How to resist to winter

[image]

<sub><sup>Click on the image to enlarge</sup></sub>

I want to give a shot too :)

This is a narcissus that I found on the side of my road to work, just after sunrise. It astonished me because it was the only one and it was quite cold.

Sadly my equipment is very limited - a Nikon Coolpix 3200 - but I like to have it always with me, to not lost such things. And I try to use this limited resources to practice the composition

Comment: I took over 12,000 images with my Nikon Coolpix 3100 before it finally gave out. Great little camera!

Answer (score 4):

**Drop Effect...**

[image]

[Bigger version](http://500px.com/photo/8266144)

Answer (score 3):

**Slice of Life**

[image]

[High Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wN6P.jpg) - Denver Airport

Answer (score 3):

Amnye Machen - A Great Protector in Tibetan Buddhism.
[image: Kora (circumnavigation) of Buddhist Great Protector Mountain, Tibet]

A bigger image of this can be found [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-wUrDINWrdEk/T886ycIGPSI/AAAAAAAAAUg/Vq6uElXL6rI/s640/DSC_3225+-2.jpg).