# Weekly Featured Image: Week of June 25, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 25 June** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

### .: Voting Closes on June 25th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/weekly-featured-image-week-of-june-18-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Should we mention that a title should not be more then 29 characters?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Untitled

[image]

And here in [big](http://500px.com/photo/8488322)

Comment: Great photo! Nice bug!

Comment: Thanks @Jakub :)

Comment: nice colors....

Answer (score 15):

### On Its Last Legs

[image: LastLegs]

This was taken at Dungeness, Kent, England, on a very windy morning! You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/7386923942/).

Answer (score 10):

[image]

The arm of the Milky Way.  Taken from San Pedro de Atacama, Chile.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Sorry, no larger version online.]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Just outside of my kitchen window I watched an American Robin's nest. Once the eggs hatched I took photos roughly every 12 hours.

- [Bigger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/danwolfgang/7181883261/in/photostream/)
- [More](http://www.flickr.com/photos/danwolfgang/sets/72157630053660179/with/7181883261/)

Answer (score 5):

## Winter in Provincetown

[image]

Well that was a nail biter election, lets try again...,

I live in a tourist town, Provincetown Massachusetts to be exact. It is crowded in the summer and pretty empty in the winter. My girlfriend and I had been out night shooting and stopped by our local for a drink. She headed off to the ladies' room and I looked to my right. The place was almost completely empty. So I grabbed my gear (and Susan's Sigma 8-16mm ultra wide), laid the camera on the table and snapped off three shots of 4/5th, 3.2, and 13 seconds at f4 on a Canon 40D crop body, ISO 100. Tone mapped using Photomax Pro.

[Click here for a larger version](http://www.notthedeadpaulcezanne.com/Fine-Art-Photography/ProvincetownAndCapeCod/15629656_trwgJk#!i=1698141531&k=cTxd5m2)

Comment: agreeed about the nail biter... +1 a great photo. I've been thinking about getting this lens but am not sure about the rounded front element. (use filters a lot) do you use filters with it? If so what's your setup?

Comment: The lens cannot take filters, not on the front, not even on the inside. You'll need one of the tripod mounted external filters. The lens isn't mind, my GF lets me borrow it.  But It will either be mounted on my Canon 40D or her 7D. The lens is fantastic and awful. :- ) Fantastic when you get it just right, and awful when the perspective distortion (which is natural in such an ultra wide lens) affects the composition. I have a love/hate relationship with that lens.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[Click here for a larger version](http://500px.com/photo/8634987)

Answer (score 2):

### Full Steam Ahead

[image: Full Steam Ahead]

[View larger version](http://matthewwild.co.uk/uploads/full_steam_ahead.html)

Answer (score 2):

Objects in mirror are closer than they appear :)

[image: Objects in mirror are closer than they appear]

Answer (score 0):

Uncertain ...

[image]

[**Full resolution original here**](http://goo.gl/xYZ5b)

He was playing with the drinking fountain and not at all sure of how to react to the "rather larger" person with a camera who took an interest in his playing.

I chose this by jumping randomly through my "Random Maybes" folder until I found a photo that both "felt good" and which would have a strong visual element when presented at the allowable size and resolution. Many 'nice' photos prove unsuitable when presented in this way.

The original is in portrait orientation which further adds to the atmosphere - but this subset still has much of the original 'feel'. For this entry I cropped the image 320 x 210 rather than the full allowed 375 maximum because, while this makes the area somewhat  smaller it also allows slightly more vertical content which adds substantially to the impression. (Cropping 375 x 210 trims the bottom off the basin and "it's not the same". 
 The 'original' that I cropped this from was 4.8 mp and the camera was a Minolta 7D 6mp so I've cropped the out of camera image slightly already previously.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rainy night through my window]

Rainy night through my window