# Weekly Featured Image: Week of July 2, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 2 July** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

### .: Voting Closes on July 2nd at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/weekly-featured-image-week-of-june-25-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Twilight Magic]

*Twilight Magic*

Bigger Image:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/45220395@N04/7434533834/in/photostream

Answer (score 8):

**"You lookin' at me?"**

[image]

[**Higher resolution image here**](http://goo.gl/kO3qZ)

100mm* - about right for a head and shoulders portrait :-) - even without the shoulders.
At f/8 depth of field was "only just enough".
Beak is nicely sharp to back beyond nostrils but softening by the eyes

(150mm @ 35mm FF equivalent)

---

**Some thoughts on "composition":**

Original is portrait mode - how else do you shoot an Ostrich with attitude! ? :-)   Despite the limitations of the landscape crop and the low resolution allowed, most of the attitude still comes across.

How much to crop? - while this is always a challenge for best results, the small size, low res and given aspect ration make it harder than usual.

Photos on the page need visual impact and filling the frame seems desirable
 (based on other images, winning images and trials with this guy). Cropping off part of the top of his (her?) head is not unacceptable in any context but makes you think twice about the visual effect.

Head 'hairs' go to an appreciable height above the head and, while on an A4 higher res print you have the luxury of including them, at 210 pixel total image height they are hard to see, and reduce the overall visual impact for no real gain.

The long Ostrich neck is part of demonstrating its visual pride factor and attitude - but unshowable here without reducing the head to a minor part of the page. After some trials with various amounts of neck visible it seemed that no neck at all achieved  best results in conveying the bird's "in your face attitude" which is much of what the photo is about.

All the preceding makes more sense when the full size image is viewed.

Answer (score 6):

## Nymph-yeah

[image]

[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCa0u.jpg)

This is my humble try. I've been looking for about a week to those nympheas, trying to remember the camera to take them a picture. Finally I did it, and I really love this one (now my wallpaper). :)

Picture taken with a Nikon Coolpix 3200, not processed.

Comment: I love how this looks totally symmetric and perfect... until you get to that one recalcitrant petal in the middle. That misbehaving petal somehow humanizes the flower. :)

Comment: @Martha: Very nice analysis! I also like the simmetry, and also the fact that there are about 4 petals for each "layer"...:) and the rebel one :)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Rainy night]

Rainy night thorugh my window

Answer (score 2):

**On vacation**

[image: on vacation]

[bigger version](http://500px.com/photo/8915256)

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as a photograph any more - it's digital art. I also find it odd to have that desaturated vegetation on the right.

Comment: @Martha thanks for suggestions. I didn't spend much time for post processing - I want to know the common impression.

Answer (score 1):

## Old Mack

[image]

[Original Size](http://photoblog.toorajam.com/index.php?tg=postView&pid=24)