# Weekly Featured Image: Week of July 16, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 16 July** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

### .: Voting Closes on July 16th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/weekly-featured-image-week-of-july-9-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Uh, it's Tuesday. Isn't it time to post the winner and make a new thread?

Comment: I've been waiting for the photo to appear in the banner. Will it run till next Wednesday?

Comment: @Jakub - Ugg, things have been so hectic at work, this just completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 27):

### **Bumped the glump**

[image]

Just found this place last week and I am milking this location for all it's got.  Can't wait to take some winter photos here.  [LARGER version](http://500px.com/photo/9519841)

Comment: Its a shame, the details really don't translate well from the big size to the small size to me.  Maybe additional sharpening or such?  The big version looks great to me.

Comment: Stupid question: what does "glump" mean?

Comment: @Martha - a made up monster from Shel Silverstein's children poem "Don't bump the Glump". My kids favorite poems. And mine too I must admit. Very abstract but very beautiful. He's the author of the more well known "The Giving Tree" - oh so good... This shipwreck is a bit of a mystery, no one really knows for certain exactly what ship this is. A photo of a mysterious shipwreck deserves a mysterious title...

Comment: Holy crap @Jakub! Again an excellent photo (especially the larger version)!  Do you mind to tell us the location?

Comment: Thanks @gsharp! Not at all, like 99.9% of all my photos this is withing 50km of where I live. This particular location is in Thunder Bay, Ontario, Canada, Neebing Township, end of the Sturgeon Bay Road in the Sturgeon Bay, Lake Superior. About 1/2 hour drive from the city of Thunder Bay. (3.5 hours north of Duluth, MN or about 6 hours from St. Paul/Minneapolis) Access from the lake via a boat is easier, access over land requires owners permission (which is what I have).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was in Canada long time ago unfortunately not so much interested in photography at that time :-/ however one of the most beautiful Countries I've ever been.. maybe time to visit again.

Comment: That shot has some seriously excellent mood going for it. I have to remember this for the next time I'm anywhere near Thunder Bay.

Comment: Thanks Joanne! Only a 15 hour drive from Toronto but well worth it especially from Sault Ste Marie to Thunder Bay.

Comment: Too bad this is 6 hours from Minneapolis or I'd head up! Also, did you use ND filters and what strength?

Comment: @dpollitt - I used a 3 stop (0.9) ND filter along with a CP filter. I would have gone even a few stops darker if I had a such filter that's why I closed to f22. The CP is to add an extra stop and to get the reflection-transparency-glare just right. Turned out a bit soft as a result but still ok.  If you decide to go bring a wider lens it's actually very close to the shore so it's not easy to get the right angle. (And lot's of mosquito repellent. The bugs were brutal) I have a few more photos from this location on 500px there is another boat skeleton in the same place.

Answer (score 11):

**It's SUMMER!**

[image]

Summer has recently hit my part of the world with full force, so it only seemed appropriate to submit a vivid, watery summer shot for the contest this week. I just found this site from an ad on SO. Looking forward to hanging out here!

Large version on Flickr: http://www.flickr.com/photos/braedenpetruk/7430404168/in/photostream

Comment: nice photo, the girl seems a bit upset though :)

Comment: Thanks! :) And nope; she (and pretty much everyone there) was having an absolute blast! She's squinting to keep all of the splashes out of her eyes.

Comment: Cool, hot, and vibrant.

Answer (score 8):

### La mariposa

[image: mariposa]

A little fellow I met on Tenerife. Got quite close with a 100mm macro lens.

Answer (score 5):

**Gimme kiss**

[image]

[**Higher resolution version here**](http://goo.gl/6whp6)