# Weekly Featured Image: Week of July 23, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 23July** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

### .: Voting Closes on July 23rd at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/weekly-featured-image-week-of-july-16-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 10):

**Birds**

Bulgaria, Black Sea

[image]

[Bigger version](http://500px.com/photo/10108239)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Rain on Leaves]

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/coneslayer/3730856212/in/set-72157604959344927/lightbox/). Submitted version flipped horizontally to work better in its position to the right of the masthead.

Answer (score 6):

**Introspection**

[image]

[Larger Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/braedenpetruk/7123096887/in/photostream)

For me, photography is an opportunity to focus my entire being on observing the world around me. I experience life in other peoples' perspectives, and capture the day-to-day memories that make life the wonderful thing that it is.

Watching this girl, completely terrified to go near the glass-covered edge of a high platform, be comforted by her father enough to actually touch and lean on the glass was absolutely incredible. It was a moment of gratitude and love for herself, a moment of extreme pride for her father, and a moment of awe and inspiration in my eyes.

People are so cool! :)

Answer (score 2):

[Summer](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/7601102432/in/photostream)

[image: Summer]

Stratford, Ontario

Nikon D90, 1/400s, F10, ISO 200, 105mm

Answer (score 1):

**Calm n Cool!!**

[image: Cool evening shore]

Enjoying the other side of shore calmly..

Larger Flickr version: http://www.flickr.com/photos/vivek_jonam/7587636860/lightbox/

Camera         : Sony DSC-W510
Shutter speed  : 2 sec
Aperture       : F/2.8
ISO            : ISO-80

Answer (score 1):

### Hideaway Sunset

[image: Sunset near Hideaway Island, Vanuatu.]

On a holiday in Vanuatu. Saw this from the island.

[Larger version here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/82981524@N03/7602790890/)

Canon EOS 550D
1/30 sec
f/9.1
ISO-100

Answer (score 1):

**I'm Real!**

[image]

Some people think I have a cardboard add on.
Many think my picture has been faked in some way.
But, this is the real me. Really!