# Weekly Featured Image: Week of July 30, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 30 July** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

### .: Voting Closes on July 30th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/weekly-featured-image-week-of-july-23-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Is there no theme, or the [Science theme](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/picture-of-the-week-theme-for-week-for-july-30th-science)?

Comment: I think that the Science theme will be next week... Hope I am right...

Comment: Yeah, the science theme will *run* the week of the 30th. You should be out getting photos for it now, so they are ready by next week. The winner of the science theme will go up Aug. 6/7th.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to clarify the Science announcement. It was completely unclear to me, since we name these threads based on the display date, not the opening date for submissions.

Comment: @jrista - Is there summat aglae with the scoring system - I think the snail had some votes and now all photos have zero votes. Seems v unusual for all to have 0 over an extended period.

Comment: Someone down voted the snail shot. We'll ignore that downvote in the final tally, as down votes are not accepted for the PotW contest. As a reminder to everyone, DO NOT DOWN VOTE!! This is a contest to select what you **want to see** on the home page, not a place to voice your opinion about any given entry. Down votes will be ignored, so don't bother making any.

Comment: @jrista:: The snail picture is not in the right size, so I've voted it down. I am keeping an eye on it and as soon as the author fixes it, I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: @jrista: As promised, downvote removed :)

Comment: Thank you... :)

Comment: Its shaping up to be a competitive week! Three really great entries so far!

Comment: @jrista - Beauty, with photos, as with other ephemeral intangibles, is in the eye of the beholder :-). But, you know that. Hopefully :-).

Answer (score 18):

### Milky Way

[image: Milky Way]

Taken on a recent camping trip.  16mm, 20 second exposure, ISO 3200, f/4

[Larger Image](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8005/7649024186_2af528e7ce_b.jpg)

Comment: Very cool shot man.

Comment: Agreed, but if it's not selected this week, it would also be great for the Science theme next week.

Comment: Wow, great! Did you tell the guys to stand still for 20 seconds?

Comment: Yes, it was two of us - I had the camera on a gorillapod on the ground.

Answer (score 14):

### A sunny day

[image: A sunny day]

Pentax K-5, Sigma 8-16 at 14mm f/10

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/66518020@N08/7642240114/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Great photo! Like the perspective and colours.

Answer (score 11):

### A Snail's Pace

[image]

Slovenia, Ptuj

EXIF INFO:

- Model: NIKON D7000
- Exposure time: 1/160
- Aperture value: F/5.6
- ISO speed: 1000
- Flash: Off
- Focal length: 105mm

[*(large version here)*](http://www.slo-foto.net/galerija_slika-101084.html)

Answer (score 8):

**Small Spirit of the Falls**

[image]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/9829881)

Answer (score 5):

### **Duck and Fish**

[image]

Tale of a duck who meets a fish. The two animals tell one another about the joys of flying in the sky or swimming underwater. Once they go their separate ways, Fish finds himself imagining what it would be like to fly while Duck ponders life underwater. What would happen if they could live such different lives? Would they be happy?

Larger version in [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/7455156932/).

Comment: I was just looking at this photo yesterday, the first thought that came up was 'wow that water is super clear'

Comment: It sure is very clear! ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Look for Trains**

[image]

- Look for trains.
- Camera on rails
- Look for trains.
- Prop with rail ballast to adjust angle.
- Look for trains
- Take photo
- Look for trains ...

Answer (score 2):

Sunrises Off the VALLEY!!

[image: Artificial Sunrise]

Larger version: http://www.flickr.com/photos/vivek_jonam/7644573246/in/photostream/lightbox/

Camera       : SONY DSC W510
Aperture     :  F/2.8
Shutter Speed:  1/4 sec
ISO          :  ISO400

Answer (score 1):

### Noisy Silhouette

[image: a noisy miner in a tree.]

[Larger Version Here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/82981524@N03/7636144954/lightbox/)

Comment: is it just me or do you need to be signed into flickr to view the larger version?

Comment: That should be fixed now. Sorry I had stupidly set it to be private. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sunset at Dal Lake, Srinagar, Jammu & Kashmir - India.

[image]

[Larger Picture](http://withmycam.blogspot.in/2012/07/sunset-at-dal-lake.html) at my blog.

Comment: FYI - Picture is larger than allowed for this 'competition'. Should be 210 pixels max tall and 375 max wide.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon sure. let me update it. anyway thanks for mentioning. Did you like it, otherwise?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon check it now!

Comment: pretty - I'd like to see the area myself. I know the aim here is silhouette, but I think I would prefer either more exposure on the boats so more detail can be seen or having them slightly lower down in the picture so you get a more complete silhouette of each **BUT** that's just a personal preference and there is no certainty that others will agree.

Answer (score 0):

## Dingo

[image: Dingo]

View larger version [in this album](http://eurofoto.no/shared/album/image/186969912). To download a full size version, click the [download link](http://eurofoto.no/images/download/186969912) at the right above the album image.

Camera: Canon EOS 400D DIGITAL
Aperture: F/4.5
Exposure time: 1/60 sec
ISO: ISO400