# Weekly Featured Image: Week of August 6, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 6 August** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on August 6th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**THIS WEEK's theme is SCIENCE**

---

This week's theme is all about **Science**. All photos must primarily involve some aspect of science. This can be the act of science...as in scientists studying chemicals in a chemistry lab, tools of the scientific endeavor such as scientific instruments, or subjects of scientific study such as refracting light, astronomy, etc.

[See full details about the theme here.](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/picture-of-the-week-theme-ideas/1765#1765)

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/weekly-featured-image-week-of-july-30-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Application of science OK. eg electronics?

Comment: I guess I would consider the application of science to be engineering (e.g. electronics, or electrical engineering), which seems a bit different to me. Maynard Case would be the one to ask as he proposed the idea.

Comment: Could this please be confirmed or not "officially"? Usually there would be a number of submissions by now. Having a clear "official" idea of the subject would be useful as either "finding out" unofficially is going to add time and will need a "special pleading note on entries" after private checking in each case  or  - if submissions are made without being "approved" they risk disqualification and/or - risk personal judgement of eligibility by voters.

Comment: Lets officially say engineering (applications of scientific knowledge, rather than science itself) are off-limits for this contest. I'm not sure why no one has submitted yet either. Perhaps we should have called out the theme this week more clearly last week.

Comment: I subsequently had a look through the list of examples (relatively 'hidden away' above) and there are a number  that are so "grey"* that you'd have to exclude them too on that basis. So I sent a message to Maynard Case with some example photos and asked him for his views. | * eg "Scientific instruments" - things that you do science with. "Magnetism" - um. It's not going to be a photos of magnetism :-) - but using magnetism or ... .

Comment: Well, magnetism is a subject of scientific study...a "science". You could photograph a superconducting plate hovering objects in the air to demonstrate the science of magnetism. I'd say that particular example is epitome, almost cliché even, example of science, its so frequently used at science fairs and in the science wings of museums, etc. Magnetism is a lot different than engineering...if we include fields of engineering, then this becomes far, far greater than just "science".

Comment: "Scientific instruments" is given as an example. It seems a bit of a reach to apply your argument to that. Maybe not. | "Magnetism is a lot different than engineering" seems not to compute. Levitation = effect of magnetism. Voltage current illumination inductive power transfer and much much much more are (engineering) effects of magnetism. Just as levitation is an engineering effect of magnetism.

Comment: That I be the better edified. You said: "Maynard Case would be the one to ask ..." - what is the proper way to do that? I had to go outside this site to achieve it. Is there some better internal manner to do so?

Comment: Enough mincing of words. Lets end the discussion. Levitating objects over a superconducting plate, as my example was, is an "exploration of magnetism". It has no practical purpose at the current time, other than to wow watchers and float frogs for the purpose of pure study. The exploration of reality, rather than the application of knowledge gained by such exploration. This contest is about "Science", not "Engineering". You asked me to clarify and make official, I clarified and made official...the issue is settled.

Comment: As for contacting Maynard...the simplest way would have been to write a comment on his proposal for this very contest, via the link in the PotW contest description above.

Comment: @jrista Maglev trains use MAGnetic LEVitation and so magnetic levitation has a practical purpose

Comment: Re " ... the simplest way would have been  ..." -> OK. I learn something new. I'm still discovering all the secret mason's handshakes and ways of doing things. Should have got it fairly right in a few years time :-). [PS: I don't do 'mincing'].

Comment: A very enjoyable MagLev experience may be had in Shanghai. A Maglev train runs from Pudong airport to the edge of the city proper. Top speed is about 430 kph (~=265 mph) and the ride is smooth, almost silent and very aircraft like. Passing 60 mph cars in a 260 mph train is awesome. Passing the other train of 2 going the opposite way at over 500 mph relative is "an experience" - a few ghostly frames on my 30 fps video camera. Recommended if in Shanghai. This train does NOT use the Meisner effect which involves superconductivity but uses "conventional" magnetics. No floating frogs noted.

Comment: @damnedtruths: True, I guess maglev would be a practical application. However my example still remains valid...showing the experimentation and exploration of magnetism via the most ubiquitous example of that study would be on-topic for this contest, while a photo of a mag-lev train would not.

Comment: Well, seems this theme might be a bit of a flop. I thought it had been advertised for about two weeks before hand... There seemed to be a fair amount of interest in the comments of last weeks contest as well, so I'm confused by the lack of participation. If this one doesn't get any more shots than Imre's, we might run it longer, through next week to get more entrants. **For everyone who is interested in participating in this theme, go out and take photos now!!**

Comment: You don't want to tighten the scope a bit more first? :-)

Comment: I think it's one of those things that a lot of people want to *see*, but few have the imagination (or the access or equipment) to *do*. And no, "technology" and "science" are not synonyms; the product is not the principle. A "pack shot" of a microscope might be an interesting niche advert, but out of scope; the same microscope *in use* would fit the theme.

Answer (score 8):

### Achromatic lens

[image: Achromatic lens]

Optics is the science that photography gains most directly from. Being [skeptic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography) about earlier research is an important underpinning of being a scientist. Luckily Isaac Newton was proved wrong about futility of chromatic aberration in refractive optics.

Camera: Pentax K100d Super
Lens on camera: 58mm f/2 at f/5.6
Lens on photo: 64mm f/1.7

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-02-08)

Comment: Awesome! Love the concept and the link to photography. :)

Answer (score 7):

### Magnetism

[image: Magnetism demonstrated by mirrored ball bearings]

Magnetism allows these ball bearings to dangle without any visible means of support.

Comment: F$%&ing magnets, how do they work?!

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - It's a simple matter of engineering :-)

Comment: Bucky Balls! I used to work with a guy who had two kits of bucky balls and he would mess with them all day. He made some interesting things too...

Answer (score 2):

**Halo around sun ..(natural scientific phenomenon) captured on 3rd Aug 2012**

Similar to a full circular rainbow..but the colors are in a reverse order

[image: Sun's Halo]