# How do I add a link in the comments that auto resolves to the question title?

Tags: support

This is a stack exchange markup question. When I add a URL to another post such as:

[Weekly Featured Image: Week of August 6, 2012](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/weekly-featured-image-week-of-august-6-2012)

Stackexchange auto updates the URL to display the question title. I know that a way exists to do this in comments, but can't figure it out.

Comment: This is really a basic question, sorry, but it's been bugging me!

Comment: Would this make sense as a feature request?

Comment: check [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments) too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of an automatic manner, but you can do `[Link title](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/weekly-featured-image-week-of-august-6-2012)` still, and it will do the "right thing"

Comment: That will have to work! I'm not so concerned about the amount of work, I just find it much more useful to see the post title rather than the URL. It should generate more clicks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is nothing automatic. You have to insert an inline markdown link yourself. (If there is a better way, I will feel silly, since I've been doing it the tedious way.)

(Exception: when you mark a post as a duplicate, the appropriate comment is generated automatically with the title rather than raw URL.)