# Weekly Featured Image: Week of August 13, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 13 August** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on August 13th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/weekly-featured-image-week-of-august-6-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: great entries this week!

Comment: Too many great entries! We need to spread out the love, as I'd like to see quite a few of these win!

Answer (score 18):

### 110 and 6th

[image: 110 and 6th]

Went in search of a place to capture the ever busy freeways around downtown Los Angeles and found it along the 110. Then I set up the tripod and waited for the sun to set.

Shot at 24mm, 30s, f/13 and ISO 100. Processed in Aperture with the built-in curve, dodge, burn and sharpening tools.

[Bigger versions](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Street-Scenes/Los-Angeles-July-2012/24481704_NTm4tW#!i=1997790426).

Answer (score 17):

**Rock Balancing, Grand Marais**

[image]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/11052897)

Comment: People love to do this up the north shore, can't say I understand why!

Comment: @dpollitt - the spirit of the lake perhaps? The force is strong. In Ontario you don't see many of these by the lake but they line the roads and highways. 100s of them. But up here these seem to be related to the aboriginal culture and the inukshuk legacy.

Answer (score 16):

**Sunflowers**

[image: sunflowers]

[bigger version](http://500px.com/photo/10661489)

Comment: Nice one Igor! +1

Comment: @Jakub thanks...

Answer (score 9):

**Temporary**

[image: Temporary]

Larger version available [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/photovolt/7521219400/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 9):

### **The Cellist**

### [image]

Larger version: [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/7710728176/in/set-72157629782573734/lightbox/).
Processed using DPP, Photoshop, Silver Efex

Answer (score 8):

**Antique Cameras**

[image]

Portobello market, London, UK

Nikon D90, 45mm, F7.1, 1/200s, ISO 200

Larger version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/7730092348/sizes/l/)

Comment: Awesome connection to photography

Answer (score 8):

[image: Oslo after a Storm]

Full size: http://500px.com/photo/11127051 or https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=422697631113659&set=a.416810228369066.108963.403842676332488

Answer (score 5):

[image: What time is it?]

Answer (score 5):

### Blue

[image: Blue]

Just minutes before I was shooting portraits, and for a moment of break I looked up, and it payed out...

```
Camera:       Canon EOS 450D
Lens:         Canon EF 24-85mm f/3.5-4.5 USM
Focal Length: 85mm
Aperture:     F/4.5
Exposure:     1/400s
ISO:          100
```

Larger version [here](http://miljenkobarbir.com/photograph/blue/)...

Comment: its a nice minimalist piece full size, when its small it loses something

Comment: I totally agree, and was thinking of removing it from the list, but then again, someone might enjoy seeing it...

Comment: Love the bigger version of this!

Comment: For a header image, this would work better if cropped much more closely. Right now, you kinda have to click through to the large image to see what the heck that white speck is.

Comment: @Martha: That very second I published the answer, I just realized that "you kinda have to click through to the large image to see what the heck that white speck is". On the other hand when I crop this image it loses "that something"... I'll choose something more appropriate next week...