# Weekly Featured Image: Week of August 27, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 27 August** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on August 27th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2417/weekly-featured-image-week-of-august-13-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Two winners last week, this week runs for 2 weeks.

Comment: Title has not been changed.
Building balancing?

Comment: Two weeks is long over...

Comment: Seriously, @rfusca, is something wrong? //worried now

Comment: @Martha - Oh I'm sorry, I'm in the middle of packing a house to move across the country on a super short time frame.  I won't be around much for the next couple of weeks.  At this point, I'll go ahead and update this one, the next one will run the remainder of this week and then next week.  Another mod will need to handle this for the next couple of weeks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Sunset in Kyiv, Dnipro river**

[image]

[bigger version](http://500px.com/photo/11337879)

Comment: Good catch! What/where is Dnipro? My Google fails me, I only find "Hotel Dnipro" (in Kyiv), but that's not exactly by the coast.

Comment: @koiyu  [Dnipro river is one of the major rivers of Europe - fourth by length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnieper_River). Try to type "Dnipro river" in google map.

Answer (score 19):

### Mountains on the Horizon

[image: Mountains on the Horizon]

(Click image for bigger version.)

Mt. Untersberg photographed from the Hellbrunner Strasse, Salzburg, Austria. Canon EOS 500D.

Comment: Resembles one of the [Windows 8 lock screen](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Yht9gIAWh5k/TsCbUYoTh4I/AAAAAAAAKVo/tjHwJddIJs8/s1600/Windows+8+Wallpaper1.jpg) wallpapers! :)

Comment: Great capture. +1

Answer (score 17):

[image]

Found this female yellow-headed blackbird with a dragonfly in it's beak getting ready for a meal. Taken at the Finley National Wildlife Refuge in a marsh filled with cattails. This species of bird has returned to this area within the past three years.

[Larger Version](http://dailysnapshots.org/index.php?showimage=297)

```
Canon 10D
Canon 300mm f/4L IS USM + 1.4xTC
Tv( Shutter Speed ): 1/1000
Av( Aperture Value ): 7.1
Hand Held
Natural Light
```

Comment: That is a great capture! This week might be a little too late, so don't forget to post next week!

Comment: Thank you @ShutterBug.

Comment: Excellent capture!

Answer (score 14):

## Caribbean Angel

[image]

I'm in love with cultural expression and candid captures, and since there's no theme this week, I thought a fun, bright photo of a lovely Caribbean performer and her *huge* angel costume would be a nice addition to the collection as a perfect representative of many Caribbean cultures.

Large version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/braedenpetruk/7767001446/in/photostream).

Comment: Love the spirit of this photo, it is so much fun, filled with life and beauty. I know this isn't a thread for commenting on photos, but a good photo is worth commenting on wherever it is seen :D Good job, I like it.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

click image to see it, and the rest of the set, on Flickr.

```
Nikon D7000
Nikon AF-S VR NIKKOR 70-300mm f/4.5-5.6G IF-ED
1/1250 at f/4.8, ISO 1600, 140mm
Handheld, ~30-40 minutes before sunset
```

Comment: This is slightly oversized, 225px high instead of 210px. Good shot though.

Comment: Just edit your answer and resize it, I think it'll be fine.

Comment: Is this a real wildlife photo or is this a staged shot of an animal in captivity and using bait?

Comment: real wildlife photo. The pair of owls live on my golf course, after playing one evening, I went out and waited for them to hunt as they do each evening in the spring. Just before I was going to give up and leave, he came down for a mole cricket. I have many more pictures of him perched, coming down, landing and then going back to his tree on flickr.

Comment: @Jakub - "Staged using bait" can cover a wide range of situations. We have a National Birds of Prey Centre where injured birds are taken for hospitalisation and recovery. Getting them back into the wild takes care. By the time they are about ready for release a Falcon attacking a lure is just as liable to be or have been hunting rabbits. It doesn't care, it's within a few weeks of being truly wild and can come and could leave if it wished. A few weeks after release they are fully wild and will not come to their prior "handlers".

Comment: @camflan - in this case a spectacular shot!

Comment: @jakub - thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

**Time Flies..**

[image: Time Flies]

[flickr version](http://maben.aminus3.com/image/2008-11-24.html)

```
Panasonic DMC-FX10
1/200 second
F/2.8
ISO 400
35 mm
```

Comment: This is too big, see size restrictions at top.

Comment: @damnedtruths: Sorry, will reupload. Thanks

Comment: Is this supposed to have the black bars on the right and left sides?

Comment: @dpollitt: No. I guess that happened after the crop I made :(

Answer (score 9):

[image: Sunset on Langkawi, Malaysia]

Here is my first contribution to this lovely weekly contest, good luck all!

Taken at Langkawi, Malaysia in May 2012. We had food at a restaurant on the beachside earlier and having scoped out the place we returned our last evening on the island to capture some sunset shots.

My ND filter wasn't strong enough for the intense sun, so I had to up to F22 to maximize the exposure time to get some fluff in the waves.

```
0,4s @ F22, ISO100
Canon 5D mk2, EF24-105 f/4L @ 24mm
```

Flickr version: http://www.flickr.com/photos/alendri/7787871168/

Comment: Aack, I'm gonna fall off the right edge! (IOW, there's a reason landscape photos ought to keep the horizon, well, horizontal.)

Comment: @Martha The main reason why it is not horizontal is simply because the camera was perched on a wall made of stones held together by a wire mesh. The only way to not have the stones in the shot was to put the camera on the edge stone, and it was leaning. However I did keep it this way through editing because I think it is interesting, different, maybe it will make people pause for reflection :D Maybe I should name it "What if the world leaned right", creepy thought! Think how many sports would be ruined heh

Comment: Agreed @Alendri. I voted for this one because I found the slanted horizon interesting. When in some photos a horizon is slanted just slightly it personally does bother me but I immediately knew this was intentional and I think it works.

Answer (score 7):

**Taj Hotel, Mumbai, India**

Always wanted to see it and finally day arrived. After sustaining [terror attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Mumbai_attacks) its still standing tall and beautiful as always.....

[image: Taj Hotel, Mumbai, India : Still standing tall and beautiful]

Answer (score 6):

### Curves

[image: Curves]

Curves, on concrete pillars. Not much else to say...

```
Camera:       Canon EOS 450D
Lens:         Canon EF 24-85mm f/3.5-4.5 USM
Focal Length: 85mm
Aperture:     F/4.5
Exposure:     1/200s
ISO Speed:    100
```

Larger version [here](http://miljenkobarbir.com/photograph/curves/)...

Answer (score 5):

[image: Main Street exit, Bethlehem, PA]

Answer (score 5):

**College reflection on the swimming pool!**

[image]

Image was rotated 180 degrees for better viewing!

Answer (score 3):

**Arrival!**

[image]

- That special moment when "mother's little girl" arrives from places far away.

  [Larger version](http://goo.gl/t2IMD)

Answer (score 3):

### Two Famous Buildings

[image: Sydney Harbour Bridge and Sydney Opera House]

They both seem normal and almost mundane to me. But I do live in Sydney.

[Larger Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/photobby_001/7787606778/lightbox/)

> ***Details:***
>   Camera: Canon EOS 550D
>   Focal Length: 55mm
>   ISO: 100
>   Shutter: 1/250 s
>   Aperture: f/7.1

Comment: I only see 1 famous building(sydney opera house), what is the other?

Comment: @dpollitt The Sydney Harbour Bridge, which happens to be the largest steel arch bridge in the world, and it is quite big.

Comment: @damnedtruths, but a bridge is not a building. Perhaps you could retitle this as "Two Famous Structures"?

Comment: @Martha  - the name is good enough as a title and would be understood by many people. It's not too important but eg [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building) says "Any human-made structure used or intended for supporting or sheltering any use or continuous occupancy, ..." . Noting the use of OR as meaning one of several valid choices that in this case includes "Any human-made structure used or intended for supporting or sheltering any use". A bridge qualifies.

Answer (score 2):

### Tourists: They Always Look

[image: Father and daughter inspecting a map outside the Tate Modern in London]

While they were taking a look at the map I was taking a look around. Shot facing about 45 degrees away from the Tate Modern in London.

[Larger Version on Flikr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/69323083@N08/7786748084/)

Comment: Did you mean "Tour-sits " as a pun or is it a typo instead of Tourist?

Comment: I wish it was a pun. Thank you for pointing it out.