# Weekly Featured Image: Week of September 10, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 10 Sept** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on September 10th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/weekly-featured-image-week-of-august-27-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Because of the delay from last week, this one will run the few days left for this week and next week.  I"m in the middle of a cross country move on a short timeframe - so I'll not be around much for the next couple of weeks.

Comment: You'll probably spot this, but there's a mistake in the HTML on the link to the picture on the front page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## *Dawn at the Pool*

[image: Dawn]

Wai ‘Opae tide pools, Kapoho, Hawai‘i, USA

Nikon D300, AF Zoom-Nikkor 18-35mm f/3.5-4.5D IF-ED
ISO 200, 1/250 sec., f/8.0, 18.0 mm FL
Raw processed with AfterShot Pro

[Larger Version](http://www.blrfl.com/photos/dawn-at-the-pool.jpg)

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Sunrise at Whitley Bay

[click here for larger picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/i-azure/7957983674/in/photostream)

> Canon 500D
>   Tokina 11-16mm
>   f/16
>   30 sec
>   ISO 100
>   11mm (1.6x on full frame)
>   Processed with Camera Raw 7

Comment: Nice! Do you have larger versions posted somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks Kim .. I uploaded this picture to my flickr and put a link up there ..

Comment: Very nice seascape!

Comment: Thankss Jakub !

Comment: I do love this shot. Great work!

Comment: Thanks dpollitt :D

Answer (score 9):

## *ATTACK!*

[image: ATTACK!]

[Link to this picture and more of this set on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/camflan/7302192024/in/set-72157629969057124)

```
Nikon D7000
Nikon AF-S VR NIKKOR 70-300mm f/4.5-5.6G IF-ED
1/1250 at f/4.8, ISO 1600, 140mm
Handheld, ~30-40 minutes before sunset
```

Answer (score 9):

## The Bridge

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqIrj.jpg]

Click Image

Taken from a ferry crossing Sydney harbour.
Unedited or retouched.

> Camera: Canon EOS 550D
> Aperture: f/3.5
> Shutter: 1/30 sec
> ISO: 100
> Focal length: 18mm
> Lens: 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 (kit)

Answer (score 8):

### Mountain Bridge

[image: Roadway through Mountains]

(click for bigger size)

A roadway through the Austrian mountains, shot from a moving train.

Canon EOS 500D F/8.0, 1/160s, ISO 100, 0 EV. Edited in Photoshop.

Answer (score 8):

### Final Descent

[image: Iceberg Lake - Glacier National Park, Montana]

Iceberg Lake - Glacier National Park, Montana

```
Canon EOS Rebel
f/22
30 sec.
ISO 100
18mm
Processed RAW with Lightroom CS5.1
```

[Larger Image](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-xGK4h6_6Nz4/UBk4IhL9gjI/AAAAAAAAAmY/0LFoAGUw15s/s1237/IMG_5104.JPG)

Answer (score 7):

[image]
Took this picture on a business trip to Naples Italy. The image is of the Sirens off of the island of Capri.

- Camera: Nikon D3000
- Lens: AF-S Nikkor 18-55mm DX VR
- 4 Images stitched together with [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

**Glory of Sunset**

I took this pic on last sunday in Bangalore,India. 
[image]

```
canon camera modal- Powershot SX150IS
exposure time 1/160
ISO speed = ISO-80
focal length - 41mm
max aperture -4.65625
```

Comment: Please see the sizing requirements in the question.

Comment: i understand,Please give time i will update it.

Comment: Please check, i have added the details.

Comment: the image height should be 210px exactly. Your image is 720px. Re-size it so that it can be accepted.

Comment: All the details are not needed. Some basic details are nice though. Camera, lens, aperture, shutter, ISO, focal length. All the other details just make the post longer.

Answer (score 2):

[image: I took this last week]

Nikon 5100, ISO:280, 1/60s, f/10.0, 28mm