# How does one post a weekly featured image?

Tags: support

What is the correct way to post a photo for the weekly featured image?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the directions on [this question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/weekly-featured-image-week-of-september-10-2012).  Answer the question with an image that conforms to the proper size and rules posted in that question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply post an answer to the Weekly Featured Image "Question" for that week, including a correctly sized image.