# Weekly Featured Image: Week of September 17, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 17 Sept** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week. 
.: Voting Closes on September 17th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/weekly-featured-image-week-of-september-10-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: The original post needs to be edited, It says that voting closes Sept 17. obviously past that now!

Comment: @rfusca - can you post the winner for this week and start a new contest?

Answer (score 18):

Sunrise at Whitley Bay

[image]

[Click here for larger picture. Thanks.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/i-azure/7957983674/in/photostream)

> Camera & Exif
>
> - Canon 500D
> - Tokina 11-16mm at 11mm
> - f/16
> - 30 sec
> - ISO 100
>
> Filters
>
> - Hitech Reverse ND Grad 4 stops
> - Hitech ND STD 4 stops
> - Cokin Z-Pro ND Grad Soft 3 stops
> - Hoya HD 77mm CPL
>
> Taken RAW and processed with Camera Raw 7

Comment: good shot, bravo!

Comment: Thanks garik :)

Comment: Laurence, one question. How did you thread Cokin filter holder on Hoya CPL filter via Cokin Z-pro adaptor (77mm wide angle adaptor, I think)? :) It's impossible for Lee's ones :)

Comment: Hi Garik ,, I have Lee foundation kit .. I just screw in the polariser on the lens, 77mm Lee wide angle adaptor on it, and fit all three filters in Lee foundation kit (all the filters are 100mmx150mm (100mm square for ND STD) that all fit on Lee's holder) .. Thanks.

Comment: So it's possible. Thanks, Laurence. It makes sense to not buying Lee 100x100 Circular Polarising Glass filter (~ £147), if you have Hoya one.

Comment: so far, my Hoya HD does the job ... Lee one would triple the price :D But I have 2 sets of Lee filters and they are awesome ..

Comment: agree, so do I :)

Answer (score 17):

## *Big Sand Lake*

[image: Big Sand Lake]

```
D7000, 10-24mm at 10mm
0.6s, f/16, ISO 100

LEE .9 Hard Grad ND
```

[See on flickr here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/camflan/7883765014/in/photostream)

Comment: Really like this photo! Great colours and composition. Nice "filter" work.

Comment: @Jakub thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

**Gone Fishing**

[image: Sunset at a fisherman's village]

I was walking down Versova, Mumbai. The colors were just magical and the fisherfolk were celebrating the end of the hurricane season.

Slightly Larger Size [Here](http://www.shaunak.ws/media/gone-fishing) (Please click on the image)

```
Camera: Canon EOS 500D
Aperture: f/4
Shutter: 1/2500 sec
ISO: 100
Lens: 50mm Prime
```

Comment: Please see rules in regard to size.

Comment: @damnedtruths I apologize - Il modify right away

Comment: Thanks for all the votes! :)

Answer (score 6):

Morning Fog @ Nandi hills, Bangalore

[image]

It took by Nokia 5230 Mobile Phone,Sorry don't have details.

Comment: Good result for your 5230. Extensive post processing?

Comment: No Extensive  processing,just keep mesure the light fall on tree and angle that's it.

Comment: Its the best I have seen with 5230.

Answer (score 5):

### The Bridge

[image]

The Sydney harbour bridge from a ferry crossing the harbour 
Click image

> Camera: Canon EOS 550D 
> Aperture: f/3.5 
> Shutter: 1/30 sec 
> ISO: 100 
> Focal length: 18mm 
> Lens: 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 (kit)
>
> no post processing

Answer (score 1):

Eagleowl at Villach Falconeering show taken on my honeymoon.

[Larger version](http://www.sequoiagrove.dk/images/eagleowl.jpg)

[image: Eagleowl from my honeymoon]