# Image of the week “hall of fame” (2012 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning in reverse chronological order.

**This is the Hall of Fame Archive for 2012**.

[**24 December 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697/sean)
[image: Kings Cross Lattice - Sean]

[**10 December 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Naveen Sharma](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13881)
[image: Pushkar Camel Fair - Naveen Sharma]

[**3 December 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2649) - [Giuseppe iPichy](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13518)
[image: Santa Maria della Pietà - Giuseppe iPichy]

[**26 November 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2637) - [Vian Esterhuizan](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4124)
[image: Landing at YYC - Vian Esterhuizen]

[**19 November 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2627) - [dpollitt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4892)
[image: La Sainte-Chapelle on Île de la Cité in Paris - dpollitt]

[**12 November 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11356) - [ckoerner](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11356)
[image: Last Daylight - Jakub]

[**5 November 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2589) - [ShutterBug](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2476)
[image: Kanchenjunga - The first light - ShutterBug]

[**29 october 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2570) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: Last Daylight - Jakub]

[**22 october 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2557) - [Dejo](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13067)
[image: Windows - Dejo]

[**15 october 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2540) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: Driftwood - Jakub Sisak]

[**8 october 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2524) - [Fanis](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3837)
[image: Untitled - Fanis]

[**1 october 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2508) - [camflan](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11295)
[image: Big Sand Lake - Camron Flanders]

[**17 september 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2494) - [Laurence Nyein](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11384)
[image: Sunrise at Whitley Bay - Laurence Nyein]

[**10 september 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2469) - [Blrfl](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6508)
[image: Dawn at the pool - Blrfl]

[**27 August 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) - [garik](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3399)
[image: Sunset in Kyiv, Dnipro river - garik]

[**20 August 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2417) - [Kim Burgaard](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2559)
[image: 110 and 6th - Kim Burgaard]

[**13 August 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2417) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: Rock Balancing, Grand Marais - Jakub]

[**6 August 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2405) - [Imre](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4390)
[image: Achromatic lens - Imre]

[**30 July 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2387) - [MikeW](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4191)
[image: Milky Way - MikeW]

[**23 July 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2373) - [garik](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3399)
[image: Birds - garik]

[**16 July 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2364) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: Bumped the glump - Jakub]

[**9 July 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2351) - [garik](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3399)
[image: Wheat in clouds - garik]

[**2 July 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2338) - [sat](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1980)
[image: Twilight Magic - sat]

[**25 June 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2322) - [gsharp](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1361)
[image: Untitled - gsharp]

[**18 June 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: The Remnants of a Glorious Past - Jakub]

[**11 June 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2283) - [gsharp](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1361)
[image: Symmetry - gsharp]

[**4 June 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2283) - [Pete](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4559)
[image: Autumn Road - Pete]

[**28 May 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2270) - [Russell McMahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263)
[image: 2000 years! - Russell McMahon]

[**21 May 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2246) - [Paul Cezanne](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7310)
[image: Days' Cottages - Paul Cezanne]

[**14 May 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2230) - [Petr Újezdský](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9321)
[image: Eva - Petr Újezdský]

[**7 May 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2208) - [Sam Saffron](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/230)
[image: Joy Ride - Sam Saffron]

[**30 April 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: Driftwood - Jakub]

[**23 April 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2170) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697)
[image: Playing In Twilight - Sean]

[**16 April 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2148) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: White Oak, Red Dawn - Jakub]

[**9 April 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2125) - [ElendilTheTall](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3205)
[image: Ignition - ElendilTheTall]

[**2 April 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2073) - [Vian Esterhuizen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4124)
[image: After Sunset - Vian Esterhuizen]

[**26 March 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2056) - [rfusca](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1917)
[image: Air - rfusca]

[**19 March 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2056) - [Kim Burgaard](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2559)
[image: Smoke Signal - Kim Burgaard]

[**12 March 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2028) - [coneslayer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2138)
[image: Dunes, Death Valley National Park - coneslayer]

[**5 March 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2008) - [Joanne C](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/472)
[image: Golden Coast - Joanne C]

[**27 February 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1977) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697)
[image: Shoot First, Sightsee Later - Sean]

[**20 February 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1950) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: Cracking - Jakub]

[**13 February 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1937) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697)
[image: To The Jubilee Line - Sean]

[**6 February 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1919) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: At Camp - Jakub]

[**30 January 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1896) - [Mikew](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4191)
[image: Arch - MikeW]

[**23 January 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1869) - [Mark Whitaker](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3644)
[image: Nemo - Mark Whitaker]

[**16 January 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1839) - [scenic_star](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7895)
[image: Winter sunrise! a New year , a new morning, new hopes - scenic_star]

[**9 January 2012**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1780) - [dpollitt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4892)
[image: Tractricious - dpollitt]

## Archives

- [Hall of Fame 2011](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740)
- [Hall of Fame 2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)