# What happened to week of September 3, 2012?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

I was just updating the [Hall of fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) (what a talented bunch you are!), and couldn't find any reference to a featured photo for the week of September 3, 2012. Was there one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The competition the previous week was extended to account for the image not being updated. This was [commented](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/weekly-featured-image-week-of-september-10-2012#comment4622_2469) on in the thread that was meant to be the 3rd of September.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm not round here much, so don't keep up with FOTW.