# Weekly Featured Image: Week of October 1, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 1 Oct** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week. 
.: Voting Closes on October 1st at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

**NOTE: Due to the lag in moderators getting the winner up for the last weeks contest, we will be exhibiting their win through the next week. This contest will be for the week after that. *Apologies for the delays!!***

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/weekly-featured-image-week-of-september-10-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Why don't we have a fall theme next time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## *Big Sand Lake*

[image: Big Sand Lake]

```
D7000, 10-24mm at 10mm
0.6s, f/16, ISO 100

LEE .9 Hard Grad ND
```

[See on flickr here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/camflan/7883765014/in/photostream)

Comment: You have to win! :)

Comment: I would love to! I think I've taken 2nd the last few. And when I posted my Owl picture, it got almost enough but landscapes kept beating it...now a bird is going to beat the landscapes :P. so it goes :-)

Comment: Perhaps, but perhaps not! :P I'm surprised my Chickadee received as many votes as it has. Well, here's to the battle for the win! :)

Comment: Haha! I jumped in front somehow. I like a good battle :-) good luck!

Comment: great atmosphere, +1

Comment: my congratulations

Comment: Congrats on the win! :)

Answer (score 17):

### Black-Capped Chickadee

[image]

[See full size (slightly different frame)](http://500px.com/photo/14291951)

An energetic chickadee in my back yard that was storing seeds under bark for winter gave me the prime opportunity to get some frame-filling photographs with the Canon EF 300mm f/2.8 L II IS lens and my Kenko 1.4x PRO 300 DGX teleconverter a couple weeks ago. This is one of the many shots taken with my Canon 7D and the 300mm rental lens. A 100% crop (only the top was chopped off to fit the site header.)

**Gear:**

- Canon 7D
- Canon EF 300mm f/2.8 L II IS
- Kenko 1.4x TC PRO 300 DGX

**Exposure:**

- 1/800 second
- f/4.0
- ISO 800
- -2 EC (Av mode)
- 420mm

Comment: Great capture! Personally, I think this frame is more interesting.

Comment: Thanks. :) I guess we'll see if people are interested in seeing a bird on the home page. (Seems landscapes are historically the favorite picks...but I thought I'd throw in something new and different to see how it went.)

Comment: It would be a refreshing change. Personally, I don't take bird/animal pictures but I do appreciate them.

Answer (score 10):

**A Gorge**

[image]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/14314211)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Magic Fountain]

Tivoli, Copenhagen, Denmark. [Larger version here](http://www.neoluminance.com/slide.php?id=v037copenhag0350).

Beautiful colors and well-maintained. Looked out of place in northern Europe :)

Answer (score 5):

**On the river**

[image]

[Larger version here](http://500px.com/photo/14040147)

Answer (score 5):

Near Point Reyes in California. Canon 400D with Canon 28-135mm IS USM lens.

[image: Shipwreck]

[Larger version](http://www.sequoiagrove.dk/images/ship_pointreyes.jpg)

Comment: What software did you use to resize the image? The edges of the boat appear distorted. Maybe try resizing again?

Comment: Fixed. I had resized it with the wrong setting for extreme shrinkage.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Leysin, Switzerland]

Swiss mountains and a few trees.

EOS 30D, Sigma 10-20 @10mm

Answer (score 4):

**Sunset by the bay**

[image: Sunset by the bay]

Location : Mumbai, India

Answer (score 3):

**Spring**

[image: Spring]

I had some problem with the resizing and sharpening of the flowers hopefully it came out ok. [Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ksmit/8008433917/in/photostream/lightbox/)