# Weekly Featured Image: Week of October 8, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 8 Oct** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week. 
.: Voting Closes on October 8th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/weekly-featured-image-week-of-october-1-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Epic storm a couple days ago]

Canon 550D, Canon 70-200 F4 IS @70mm at F4, 1/6 seconds, ISO 1600. Added a little contrast and dialed down on the highlights to reveal more cloud detail.

Used [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/)'s exposure change detection for the shot itself.

[Larger](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-RlGhf_FOToI/UHF80shoBwI/AAAAAAAAI-8/zIqr1Nru7RE/s953/IMG_2971.jpg)

Comment: Very dramatic. This would make a great backdrop for some digital art. Some _Hellboy_ style tentacles reaching out of another dimension perhaps!

Comment: very beautiful!

Comment: Cheers, it was an insane storm. 20-30 strikes per minute at peak. I was half expecting to see Mumra appear in the clouds.

Answer (score 7):

### [Flying Sunset](http://www.flickr.com/photos/photobby_001/7994997863/in/photostream/lightbox/)

[image]

Taken out the window of a plane, flying from Sydney to Brisbane, Australia.

> **Camera**: Canon 550D
> **Lens**: Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS
>  **Focal length**: 21mm (35mm equiv.: 33.6mm)
> **Aperture**: F/3.5
> **Shutter**: 1/6 sec
> **ISO**: 100

Answer (score 7):

### Escalator

[image: Dupont Circle Metro Escalators]

Escalators seen from the bottom of the Dupont Circle metro station in Washington, D.C.

Hand held, available light. 24mm, f/2.8, 1/40 and ISO 800. Curves, dodge and burn in Aperture. No HDR.

Comment: I don't think I've seen a photo of yours that doesn't involve a tunnel. Freud would have a field day. Nice shot though ;)

Comment: Ha! Well, my last three entries didn't. But you're right, I do have a lot of tunnel photos too :-)

Comment: @Kim - another good one! +1

Answer (score 5):

## [Licking Crumbs](http://500px.com/photo/13324073)

[image]

A black-capped chickadee, licking the last few crumbs still on its beak, eyes a nearby feeder as it prepares to snatch another seed!

**Camera:**
 Canon 7D w/ 600mm lens
 Canon EF 300mm f/2.8 L II IS + EF 2x TC III

**Exposure:**
1/250s @ f/5.6
ISO 1600
EC +2/3 EV

Answer (score 5):

### What Are *You* Looking At?

[image: What are you looking at?]

Red-Veined Darter Dragonfly peeping at the camera.

Nikkor 105mm ƒ2.8 Micro @ ƒ5.6 1/400s ISO 200 on Nikon D5000.

Larger version [here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/Gallery/Odds%20and%20Ends/whatareyoulookingat_zps8e7e60f4.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

**Fall Colours in the Squaw Bay**

[image: Fall Colours in the Squaw Bay]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/14923769)

Answer (score 4):

#### Stove

[image: Stove]

Stove in the naval fortress at Drottningskär

Hand held, available light.
Date: 2012-07-18
Place: Aspö, Sweden
Exposure: 1/50 s, f/4.0, ISO 320, 41mm
Camera: Canon EOS 5D mk II
Lens: Canon EF 28-135mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM

[Larger](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=26204)

Answer (score 3):

Cloudy Day at the Cottage

[image: Cloudy Day at the Cottage]

Nikon D90 w/18-105mm at 18mm, ISO 200, F/13, 1/640s

Larger version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/8052385240/lightbox)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Color Spark]

Spark of colors. [Larger here](http://www.neoluminance.com/slide.php?id=v032montp1010037).

Panasonic Lumix DMC-GF2

ISO 800 - F/5.6 - 1/6s

Focal-length somewhere between 14 and 42mm :) EXIF says 21mm

Answer (score 0):

Frog in my garden. Canon eos 400d, canon 28-135mm IS USM lens

[image: Frog in my garden]

[Large](http://www.sequoiagrove.dk/images/frog.jpg)