# Weekly Featured Image: Week of October 15, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 15 Oct** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on October 15th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2524/weekly-featured-image-week-of-october-8-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: voting has ended, the image needs to be on the front page

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Driftwood**

[image]

[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisakphotography/8073844779/in/photostream)

Comment: Wow, the B&W is amazing! Best one without doubt :)

Comment: Great shot, really like the combination of B&W with the water.

Comment: Thanks guys! I actually took 2 shots of this tree and I personally prefer the [portrait orientation](http://500px.com/photo/14996111). Initially, I didn't even process the landscape orientation but I really wanted to submit a B&W this week so I used the same processing including the grain for the landscape.

Answer (score 15):

**Monsoon Greens**

[image]

[Larger Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/akshaymhatre/7988255076/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: +1 Looks good in small version. The large one has scary noise :( Maybe a lower ISO or a trip through Noise-Ninja can help.

Comment: +1 Like this one a lot. Agree with @Itai - large version is noisy but the small version works. Nice mood and colours.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[Larger Image](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-GmzhnWIikMY/UBk3nIOvBxI/AAAAAAAAAiw/8VuUGEdJ7sQ/s1237/CRW_4513.jpg)

Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL

F-Stop: f/5  - Exposure: 30sec -
ISO Speed: ISO-100
Filters: B+W 110 ND 3.0

Comment: +1 any ND filters?

Comment: @akshay1188 oh forgot to mention that, yea B+W 110 ND 3.0

Answer (score 8):

#### Boat with a view

[image]

Place: Aspö, Sweden
Date: 2011-07-18
Camera: Canon EOS 5D mark II

[Larger](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=25183)

Comment: +1 I like the composition

Answer (score 6):

### Long-tailed Tit

[image: Long-tailed tit]

Long-tailed Tit looking fluffy. Larger version [here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/longtailedtit_large_zps770ba419.jpg).

1/250s @ ƒ5.6 420mm (Nikkor 300m ƒ4 + 1.2x teleconverter) ISO 800 on Nikon D5000

Answer (score 6):

**Clouds**

[image]

Larger version [here](http://500px.com/photo/15459179).

- Focal Length: 12mm
- Shutter Speed: 1/30 sec
- Aperture: f/19

Answer (score 6):

## *Portrait of a Barred Owl*

[image: Portrait of a Barred Owl]

```
Nikon D7000
Nikkor 70-300 VR at 125mm
1/800, f/4.8, ISO 1600
Handheld about 45 minutes before sunset
```

You can view the entire series [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/camflan/sets/72157629969057124/with/7302194758/), where he swoops down and attacks his prey

Answer (score 3):

**Shining on the edge**

[image: Shining on the edge]

Amager Strand, Copenhagen, Denmark

Larger version [here](http://500px.com/photo/12098965).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Place: Thrissur,India
Date: 2012-01-17
Camera: Panasonic Lumix DMC-FS42

Answer (score 0):

[image]

'The end of the world'
Golubac, Serbia