# Weekly Featured Image: Week of October 22, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 22 Oct** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on October 22nd at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/weekly-featured-image-week-of-october-15-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

**Windows**

Belogradchik, Bulgaria

Comment: Like it. Looks like a spooky painting at a first glance.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to get that spooky effect :)

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Click [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/i-azure/8097917617/in/photostream/lightbox/) for larger picture.

This image is taken at St Mary's Lighthouse, North Shield, North East England.

Nikon D700 with 24-70 f2.8

- f22
- 5 sec exposure
- iso 100

Comment: good work. voted

Answer (score 3):

### I Want You

This image was taken in Venice, Italy. The padlocks are placed by a couple who swear undying love, lock the padlock to the railing and throw the keys into the canal.

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/8032327687/).

[image: IWantYou]

Answer (score 1):

### *Walt Disney Amphitheater*

[image: Walt Disney Amphitheater]

```
 Nikon D7000
 Nikkor 35mm f/1.8
 1/1600, f/1.8, ISO 100
 Handheld 45 minutes before sunset
```

Comment: 45 mins handheld?

Comment: The shot was taken 45 minutes before sunset, and was handheld...

Answer (score 1):

### Flying Sunset

[image: Flying Sunset]

A sunset taken from a flight.

[Bigger Here](http://500px.com/photo/14030483)

Answer (score 1):

### Hoiho

Hoiho - Yellow-eyed Penguin.

The Hoiho is among the world’s rarest penguins with an estimated total population of about 4000.

[image]

[Larger version here](http://goo.gl/ZwU2F) - 7 MP crop from 24 MP original.
[24 MP original here](http://goo.gl/SAiUn)

Minolta 500 mm Reflex, f/8. Sony A77.
Saturation increased on cropped version to make image better viewable in 210 high format.
More natural saturation in uncropped version.

This and related photos were taken in the birds natural habitat while observing permitted viewing distances.