# Weekly Featured Image: Week of October 29, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 29 Oct** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on October 29nd at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2557/weekly-featured-image-week-of-october-22-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Last Daylight**

[image: Last Daylight]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/15214343)

Answer (score 18):

Top of the Rock, NYC

[image: Top of the Rock, NYC]

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/35106989@N08/7981740332)

Comment: +1 Nice perspective. Is there a total B/W version of this? I would like to see it.

Comment: +1 Like it. But I would love this if it was either B&W or full colour.

Comment: Here it is, black and white: http://www.flickr.com/photos/35106989@N08/8119551693/

Answer (score 16):

**Foggy morning**

[image]

[Larger version](http://500px.com/photo/16311231)

> **Camera:**           NIKON D90 
>   **Focal Length:**     13mm 
>  
>   **Shutter Speed:**    1/4 sec 
>   **Aperture:**         f/13

Comment: Excellent! Nice work @Garik.

Answer (score 11):

### Fall is Falling

[image]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/16046443)

Answer (score 8):

Lonesome

[image: Standing tall and alone]

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/akshaymhatre/7988247488/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 7):

## *Sunrise at Navy Pier*

[image: Sunrise at Navy Pier]

```
Nikon D7000 + 10-24 DX at 10mm
2 minutes, f/13, ISO 100
LEE Big Stopper, Lee 3 Stop ND Grad
```

Comment: I really like Lake Point Towers in this shot. Nice work!

Answer (score 3):

### Lazy Daisy

[image: A daisy]
One daisy in thousands
[larger](http://500px.com/photo/16280451)

> Camera: Canon EOS 550D
> Lens: Sigma 50mm f/2.8 EX DG macro
> Shutter: 1/800 sec
> Aperture: f/2.8
> ISO: 100

Answer (score 3):

### Penny Farthing

[image]

Vintage "Penny Farthing" bicycle.

f/1.8, 75 mm, 1/30s.

[Larger version](http://goo.gl/SiSTZ)

Stored in "Dropbox".
Opening with Chrome return an ~= 2 mp image.
Saving to disk and opening returns the full 12 mp image.
In the latter you get the marvellously ancient feel of the pedal metal.

Comment: +1 Nice photo. Has a nice "steam-punk" feel.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Cloud Set**

[image: Cloud Set]

[Larger](http://photographybyjay.com/blog/a-beautiful-sunset/)

Answer (score 2):

Saas-Fee Vista

[image: Saas-Fee Vista]

[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/simon_hughes/5750233385/)

Answer (score 2):

Crouching Cat Hidden Dragon [The dragon is hidden :P ]

[image: Crouching Cat Hidden Dragon]

Canon PowerShot A3100 IS
f/5.6
ISO 400

Answer (score 1):

### Beauty in the Weed

[image]