# Weekly Featured Image: Week of November 5, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 5 Nov** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on November 5th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2570/weekly-featured-image-week-of-october-29-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: sorry guys .. just one quick question .. why I can't delete my post ? I am still seeing it .. or is it just me who can see it ? Thanks ..

Comment: I don't see yours.

Comment: Thanks Bro .. that's good .. I deleted it but I can still see it .. so it's just me who can see it then .. Ta

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kanchenjunga - The first light

[image]

Larger version: [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/8127081297)

```
Camera: Canon 550D
Lens: Canon EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 USM @75mm
Exposure: 0.1 sec (1/10)
Aperture: f/11.0
ISO Speed: 100
```

Comment: It's like a painting!

Comment: Very nice, I would have expected this to be shot with a very long lens, and when you said 75 I was blown away. Great shot!

Comment: Actually this is a slightly cropped version, hence the additional magnification. Please check out the original. However, I wasn't that far from the mountain.

Answer (score 11):

Lights on a Bus - at Dusk

[image: A large well-lit city bus turns a downtown street corner]

- Camera: Canon EOS 5D Mark III
- Lens: Canon EF 17-40mm f/4 L USM
- Shutter: 13.0 sec
- Aperture: f/22
- ISO: 200

[Larger Version](http://photographybyjay.com/blog/night-photography/)

Comment: On your blog it says that this is a 30 second exposure, but here you said it was 13. :P Very cool either way!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  It was a mistake on my blog, and I have corrected it there.

Answer (score 7):

### **"Blow the wind Southerly ..."**

[image]

Probably the most wind-distorted trees I've ever seen. Well worth a look at the high res version (even if you don't vote for it :-) ).
A very "character filled" group of trees.

Located on the "Catlins Coast" in the very far south of New Zealand.
The bitterly cold and usually near gale force wind comes off the Southern Ocean, with  no land between there and Antarctica.

Choice was to wash out sky to or lose darker detail in foliage. Very little sky detail present due to cloud and strong winds.
There's a shed buried in the tree - easier to see in the [**larger version.**](http://images57.fotki.com/v1354/fileGd5R/9fc34/1/760471/8789792/DSC03007BlowthewindSoutherly.jpg)

(http://goo.gl/nhLl7)

Chrome displays a reduced size page for some reason.
Internet Explorer displays a full resolution 6000 x 4000 image.

Comment: really unique shot!

Comment: The Dropbox link shows full-sized in Chrome (but you have to click it to override the "scale to fit" behaviour). Perhaps fotiki is doing the scaling based on the user-agent (if that's the version that shows up differently in Chrome and IE)? I've seen individual trees at least as bad (in Nova Scotia and Newfoundland), but never a dense copse like that. It almost looks deliberate.

Comment: that is a ridiculous tree

Comment: @StanRogers - The current link is to Fotki which works OK in Chrome. It does the usual fit to screen / full size toggling when clicked. I would not usually link to Fotki full sized image long term as the links die after a few weeks. I can swap to the Dropbox or other version before then. 
The goo.gl link that I left on screen but not 'live' is to Dropbox. It never shows full size in Chrome, clicked or not. BUT if you download the image from Dropbox via Chrome and save to  disk, it is downloaded at full size. ie Chrome is making some decisions "for you" in the middle when viewing/

Comment: @dpollitt - Ridiculous is good! :-) It's quite likely that the "copse" was planted as a 'shelter belt' when the shed was built as there are isolated tree-clusters like this but not a consistent line. A VERY windy and VERY cold location.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon -- it was the Dropbox (goo.gl) link that worked full-size opened in Chrome for me (not downloaded as a file to local, just middle-clicked to open in a new tab); the fotiki link was a little larger than 1/4-screen on a 1080p monitor for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Watkins Glen]

```
Camera: Canon EOS Digital Rebel
F-Stop: f/22
Exposure: 4secs
ISO: 200
```

[Larger - And Series](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/116020399780443126980/albums/5801485488115025265/5801485564416707858)

Answer (score 5):

A tiny flower

[image]

Shot with a reverse 50mm. [Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/akshaymhatre/6707573177/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 3):

The two elements, Water and Light

[image]

[larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ukgraphy/5142864152/in/photostream)

Captured this at Fateh Sagar lake in Udaipur, Rajasthan , India.
Udiapur is also known as City of Lakes. A beautiful city indeed !!

Answer (score 2):

### I'd Have Gotten Away With It, Too

[image]

This was taken at The Tunnel, a place near Waterloo station in London where people are able to go and spray graffiti.

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/8139512001/).

Comment: What lens was this?

Comment: The Nikon 10.5 f2.8 fisheye

Answer (score 2):

[image: Saas Fee]

[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/simon_hughes/5750233385/)

Answer (score 1):

## *ATTACK*

[image: ATTACK]

```
Nikon D7000 + 70-300 VR at 140mm
1/1250, f/4.8, ISO 1600
Handheld, just before sunset
```

[See the rest of this series here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/camflan/sets/72157629969057124/with/7302188598/).

Answer (score 1):

### Fleeting Fall

[image]

[Larger version](http://500px.com/photo/17074153)

Answer (score 1):

Deer in Yosemite. Canon 400D, Canon 28-135 IS USM.

[image: Deer in Yosemite]

Answer (score 0):

### [Lazy Daisy](http://500px.com/photo/16280451)

[image: Lazy Dasiy]
A daisy, one in thousands
[larger](http://500px.com/photo/16280451)

> Camera:  Canon EOS 550D
> Lens: Sigma 50mm f/2.8 EX DG macro
> Shutter: 1/800 sec
> Aperture: f/2.8
> ISO: 100

Answer (score 0):

[image: Crystal in Lucas Cave at Jenolan NSW Australia]

[Larger version of photo](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/_Bdlr81EDtyD_knIYn6taNMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink)

```
Crystal in Lucas Cave at Jenolan NSW Australia

Camera: Nikon D3000
Lens: 18-55mm VR kit lens
ISO: 3200 (Hi-1)
Shutter: 1/250sec
Aperture: 5.3
Handheld
```

I took this photo on a [road trip through NSW Australia](https://picasaweb.google.com/117214900519819472119/RoadTripPhotosNSWAustralia2012#5801700408179282802) visiting the Jenolan Caves.
This was my first time taking pictures in a cave with my kit.  I found it challenging taking reasonable photos that were going to have a lot of digital noise because of the extreme low-light conditions.