# Weekly Featured Image: Week of November 12, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 12 Nov** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on November 12th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/weekly-featured-image-week-of-november-5-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Hasn't our November 12th got away on us?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I have a lot of things going on right now, and I think I'm currently the only mod paying any attention at all to the PotW contest.

Answer (score 13):

Saline Valley

[image: A hidden valley surrounded by a growing small town.]

A little valley I use to pass through when I was younger. There's a funny story included if you click through to the high-res version.

```
Nikon D800
50mm 1.8G
f/16 1/125
3 exposure HDR in Photomatix
Shot a little before the golden hour
```

Comment: very nicely done hdr

Answer (score 10):

### The Orbit

[image: Orbit]

This is the Arcelor Mittal Orbit an the London Olympic park. You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/7908108998/).

Comment: That is one odd structure

Answer (score 10):

Butterfly Farm in Oranjestad, Aruba

[image]

[Larger Image](http://photographybyjay.com/blog/aruba/)

Comment: Is it a screenshot? (noting the white line to the left)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  It was a cropping error and it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

"Blow the wind Southerly ..."

[image]

Probably the most wind-distorted trees I've ever seen. Well worth a look at the high res version (even if you don't vote for it :-) ). A very "character filled" group of trees.

Located on the "Catlins Coast" in the very far south of New Zealand.
The bitterly cold and usually near gale force wind comes off the Southern Ocean, with no land between there and Antarctica.

Choice was to wash out sky to or lose darker detail in foliage. Very little sky detail present due to cloud and strong winds. There's a shed buried in the tree - easier to see in the [**larger version**](http://images57.fotki.com/v1354/file8Kj6/a0341/1/760471/8789792/DSC03007BlowthewindSoutherly.jpg)

(http://goo.gl/nhLl7)

For me, Chrome displays a reduced size page for some reason.
Internet Explorer displays a full resolution 6000 x 4000 image.

Answer (score 5):

The Silent Moment of a Death Metal Drummer

[image: The Silent Moment of a Death Metal Drummer]

Eos 400D, 28mm 1.8 USM @ F1.8,1/50s

[Larger Version](http://www.sequoiagrove.dk/images/TheSilentMomentofaDeathMetalDrummer.jpg)

Comment: oh man, this would look awesome if it was on a 40D :P Sorry just had to give you a hard time, I'm kidding.

Answer (score 4):

Manaslu, Mountain of the Spirit

[image: Manaslu]

This picture was taken on my way to Manaslu base camp.
[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/rozan/8154182531/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Flying Sunset](http://500px.com/photo/14030483)

[image: A sunset from a plane window]

Taken out the window of a plane, flying from Sydney to Brisbane, Australia.

[larger](http://500px.com/photo/14030483)

```
Camera: Canon 550D
Lens: Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS
Focal length: 21mm (35mm equiv.: 33.6mm)
Aperture: F/3.5
Shutter: 1/6 sec
ISO: 100
```