# Weekly Featured Image: Week of November 19, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 19 Nov** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on November 19th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/weekly-featured-image-week-of-november-12-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Lockand switch header when you get a chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

La Sainte-Chapelle on Île de la Cité in Paris([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sainte-Chapelle)).

[image: Sainte-Chapelle]

[Bigger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4bOf.jpg)

Another shot of the upstairs of this church [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dpollitt/6638977273/in/photostream). 
Yes, this is the basement!

Comment: Nice shot, D! That lighting is awesome!

Comment: I think "luscious" is the appropriate word to describe this. (And I *so* want to go there.)

Comment: Love the colours and the symmetry is perfect!

Comment: Ooh la la! Cracking shot sir.

Answer (score 9):

**Dragon Warrior**

[image: Male blue crown tail betta]

My betta checking out his future home, currently he lives in a small container. The plants are floating water lettuce. Sorry I don't have a bigger version :(

Comment: gear and exposure settings?

Comment: That is a HUGE home for a betta!

Comment: @Meysam 18-55mm and 550D, no flash, ISO 1600, Shutter 1/50, f/5.6

Comment: @dpollitt Yes, its ~20 US Gallons, with plants, decors and DIY 3D background, it should be at-least ~15 Gallons. I intend to put a few shoals of Neons, Cardinals and Harlequins as well :)

Answer (score 7):

### Landing at YYC

[image: YYC in BW]

500px has the [larger version](http://500px.com/photo/18259155) as well as all the data about the photograph. There's also a [series of similar photos](http://500px.com/heyvian/sets/yyc_calgary_international_airport).

Comment: Awesome shot, dramatic, abstract and striking.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Shore of the Azores São Miguel.

[Larger](http://www.sequoiagrove.dk/images/azoreslarger.jpg)

[image: Azores]

Answer (score 1):

## *Great Smoky Mountains*

[image: Great Smoky Mountains]

```
 Nikon D7000 + 70-200 2.8 VRII at 200mm
 1/320, f/6.3, ISO 100
 Lookout Mountain, Chattanooga, TN
```

[See it full size on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/camflan/8167292226/in/photostream)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Higher resolution link to follow.

An insight into flying styles and aerodynamics. 
No - not 'photo-shopped' and not stuck on the fence :-)
This is just how they happened to be departing. A frame by frame slow motion video view would be fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

Happy Diwali !
[image]

Diwali lighting at out place.
Larger version and other info [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/31011032@N03/8185864779/).