# Weekly Featured Image: Week of November 26, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 26 Nov** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on November 26th at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/weekly-featured-image-week-of-november-19-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 14):

### Landing at YYC

[image: Landing at Calgary International Airport - Vian Esterhuizen]

500px has the [larger version](http://500px.com/photo/18259157) as well as all the data about the photograph. There's also a [series of similar photos](http://500px.com/heyvian/sets/yyc_calgary_international_airport).

Comment: nice capture... ;) I like the focus, perpective and the colors...

Comment: @pacoespinoza Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

[image: morning]

We went camping with the entire family for my father in law 50th birthday the past weekend, we all woke up early 5:30am had some coffee and when the sun started to show I took this image. It was taken in the Little Karoo on a hot mostly overcast day.

[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ksmit/8204422511/in/photostream)

canon 600D f6.3 1/200s iso100 @ 170mm

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The Chase**

When a dog gives chase, there is nothing else than the dog and it's prey.

[Larger](http://www.sequoiagrove.dk/images/The_Chase.jpg)

[image: The Chase]

*Canon 40D, Canon 28mm 1.8 @ F4.5 ISO 800, shutter 1/200s*

Comment: So, I know this isn't supposed to be a place for feedback on photos, but since this got zero upvotes I thought maybe you'd appreciate a little bit. For me, the monotone yellow/green palette doesn't sit well. But more importantly, I don't see what you describe in your caption: I see the indistinct rear end of a dog. In the larger version, _maybe_ those are ducks in the water? The theme is interesting, but maybe the photo would be more successful from a different angle and with closer framing?