# Weekly Featured Image: Week of December 3, 2012

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 3 Dec** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on December 3rd at 9:30pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

**There is no theme this week**

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/weekly-featured-image-week-of-november-26-2012)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: I made a mistake with the link to the larger version of my photo for the POTW winner. I know you're busy so it's not super urgent but if you could update it when you get a chance that would be awesome. http://500px.com/photo/18259155 @jrista or anyone else that could help.

Comment: @VianEsterhuizen: Fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Rista.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Santa Maria della Pietà**

GranSasso National Park, Abruzzo Italy

[image: Santa Maria della Pietà GranSasso National Park Abruzzo Italy]

You can see large image [here](http://i.images.cdn.fotopedia.com/giuseppeandreamosca-AbBdKEj8kiE-original/Countries_of_the_World/Europe/Italy/Santa_Maria_della_Pieta.jpg)

Comment: Is this the raw image or you worked additionally in softwares? (just asking for my reference, hope you don't mind!)

Comment: Yes, of course, I used a graduate filter to dark the sky and on the blu of the sky I added a little bit of saturation and contrast. On the face of the church I used a lighter brush.

Comment: ok fine ! done in photoshop or lightroom?

Comment: I usually use Lightroom

Comment: oh nice. Really awesome click !

Comment: Nice shot! Like the mood.

Answer (score 8):

## *Command Module*

[on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/camflan/7399127164/)

[image: Command Module]

```
Nikon D7000 + 10.5 DX Fisheye
1/30, f/2.8, ISO 360
Handheld, overhead at Kennedy Space Center
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I really liked the colours/textures of the capsule so I made a few modifications and used it as a wallpaper. http://heyvian.com/misc/apollo-14.jpg

Answer (score 4):

**Neon Tetra**

[image]

Neon Tetra, roaming around Hornwort leaves.
Sadly, I do not have a larger version.

Answer (score 3):

Knock Knock

Canon 40D, Canon 28mm 1.8 USM @ F4.6 1.100s, in Lecce, Italy

[Larger](http://www.sequoiagrove.dk/images/knockknock.jpg)

[image: Knock Knock]

Answer (score 2):

### [Shadowy Daisy](http://500px.com/photo/18818813)

[image]

A daisy with shadows cast by its center.
[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/18818813)

> Camera: Canon 550D
> Lens: Sigma 50mm F/2.8 EX DG
> Shutter: 1/400
> Aperture: f/2.8
> ISO: 100