# Why Weekly Featured Image doesn't use the proposed ideas?

Tags: discussion

We have this [question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/picture-of-the-week-theme-ideas) that lists lots of ideas for weekly featured image, why we are not using it? Every week people upload their photos which is fine but I see lots of really good ideas and it will be enjoyable to use them. We did that couple of months ago, the last one I remember was an idea I believe from @mattdm about the four elements.

Comment: Here ya go :) http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/picture-of-the-week-theme-for-week-for-july-30th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, no particular reason.  We've discussed having another go at it, just haven't.

If the community would like a theme week soon, we can do that.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to start them again.I don't wanna say that I'm starting to get bored of landscape and nature photos :) but even using theme ideas is good for practice