# Time for a pic-of-the-week theme?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, contest

There are a lot of theme ideas [queued up](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/picture-of-the-week-theme-ideas).

Maybe we could start having a theme the first (or second) week of every month?

Comment: I agree, we are way overdue for a theme. I am wondering if I could enlist the help of high ranknig members, such as yourself, to assist me in the PotW stuff. I have a LOT of things going on in my life right now, and I am the only one addressing PotW lately. I am not always on time, and that seems to frustrate a number of people. Having some additional help from the community members who are vested in the contest would be a GREAT help to me. One of those things could be preparing and helping run themed contests.

Comment: @jrista I know I'm not up there with reputation but I'd be willing to help you out when you need it.

Comment: @VianEsterhuizen: I appreciate it, however some permissions only come with a reputation above 10k, and some of them might be required to actually help manage PotW.

Comment: @jrista — so what all is needed?

Comment: @mattdm: Well, we have had fairly low participation in most of the previous themes. I am not sure of the specifics, but we need some better way to advertise them when they are coming, fire people up about them, and get people out taking pictures so they have something good that qualifies when the theme starts. Rfusca and I talked about that a little, I forget what we came up with, and I can't manage the entire PotW contest + themes entirely on my own...so help in these areas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, here's a more concrete proposal:

Let's use a themed photo **the first full week of every month**. Since we haven't had a lot of entries in the previous themed contests, these should run *in parallel with the normal contest* for the entire upcoming month.

(So, looking at the current list, December would be Black & White, with the winner to run the week of January 6th.)

In order to do this, we need:

1. A blog post about the new plan (Um, I can do that since I'm halfway there with this q+a)
2. A blog post every month announcing that month's theme (anyone with blog privs)
3. Other promotion

   - across stack exchange network (needs SE employees?)
   - twitter and whatnot (anyone!)
4. Move chosen theme to Theme Idea Archive (needs a mod, although anyone 1ith 15+ rep could help by flagging the answer)
5. Create meta "question" with the contest boilerplate (anyone with 5+ rep)
6. Someone to close that thread when it's done (needs to be a mod)
7. Someone to actually modify the PotW in the header (mod again, I think)
8. A blog post with the winnder (anyone with blog privs)

Anything else? I'm marking this community wiki -- fix the steps as needed.

Comment: I think this sounds like a great start. We are starting a new month now...do we want to start a new theme thread, or wait until January and some preliminary blogs to be posted?

Comment: @jrista: I'm good either way. Maybe depends on whether I get a chance to write that blog post in the next few days. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I would love to see some more themes going! Maybe it would encourage some more entries too.

Also, bit of a side note, but maybe the Twitter account could post a "Picture of the Week contest now open. [insert hashtags here]" type of message to increase participation? I feel like POTW is actually a good entrance into participating in the site as a whole, but that's just my opinion.