# Weekly Featured Image: Ongoing Contest

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, contest

**After a continuous run of almost a decade, contest participation has gotten extremely low.** See [Contest is definitely dead. Now what?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/contest-is-definitely-dead-now-what) for more, and for possible next steps to revitalize it.

Also, you may instead want to check out the **[new Photo Competition on the main site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition?tab=Newest)**! See also the Meta post, [New Photo Contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7109/).

---

This is the place to submit and vote on photos to be featured on the  [the main site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/). This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they **LIKE** (not what they dislike), so downvotes aren't allowed — see below for more.

### Contest Format

Starting in December 2012, this contest follows a new perpetual format with continuously-rolling voting. Submit and vote on photos whenever you like. Every Monday (give or take; it's done by hand when site moderators have a spare moment), the top-voted image will be selected as the winner, and:

- moved to the [Winners' Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)
- featured on the main site header for the next week

Then, the contest will continue with the remaining photos in the thread.

(Note that the [*themed*](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/picture-of-the-week-theme-ideas) photo contest will work on a different scheme.)

### Voting Rules

- Vote up as many images as you like.
- **Make sure to look at the "[active](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/?answertab=active#tab-top)" tab for this question to see new submissions.**
- **Up votes only!** Do *NOT* vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote. (If you notice a downvote on an entry, make a note in a comment, and that will be taken into account when the weekly winner is selected.)
- When you vote, consider the small size primarily, even if a larger image is linked. This contest's primary function is to select a header image, and we need the winners to be successful at that size.

### Submitter Rules

- Showcase your best work in any genre of photography by providing your image inline in an answer.
- You may enter **one photo per week**. This is on the honor system, but abuse will eventually earn a strong talking-to.
- Don't re-enter the same photo. Since the contest is continual, there's no need. You may withdraw an image from the contest at any time by deleting the answer.
- You may edit your entry to fix problems or to add missing information, but don't switch the photo itself for a different one, or make gratuitous edits simply to "bump" the entry.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.** This is the requirement for the header. Please feel free to provide a link to a larger version, but as explained above, the primary focus is on the header image.
- For the same reason, **images must be in landscape orientation**.
- **Images must not contain any artificially added borders, watermarks, or decorations of any kind.**
- Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) instead, or ask a specific question about your image on the [main site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/).
- The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). If you're not comfortable with that, this isn't the contest for you.

### Submitter notes

**Be patient!** This contest is relatively obscure, and it takes a while for images to accumulate votes. It's normal for *really excellent* images to have only one or two upvotes even after a time. The format of the contest should let them rise to the top eventually.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotions behind it, and so on, and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings. This site is a collaboration for teaching and learning, so it's great to know those things — but it's not required for the contest.

When we get up and running with featuring these photos on the blog, this will provide the opportunity to go into more depth and to engage in conversation about your work.

Comment: As with all past contests, I'd like to stress the *up-vote only policy*. Let's keep our contest *cordial*. This is not a place for critique or a forum within which to *express dislike*, **choose what you like, have fun, and let the contest roll!**

Comment: See also: [Regarding ties](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2709/what-to-do-about-ties-in-the-photo-contest). [Regarding image size/shape/orientation](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/what-exactly-is-landscape-mode-in-the-contest).

Comment: Please use [this thread](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4387/what-thread-format-do-you-prefer-for-picture-of-the-day-contest) for discussion  of what we should do about the PotW contest threads going forward. I agree that there are issues involved with a single everlasting thread, and we should be open to suggestions.

Comment: I suspect very few people are digging down to the bottom - based on dates and my past upvotes on other pictures and where they are in the heap now. A link to the entry page may help (or may exist and I've missed it).
Something like [**ENTRIES START AT BOTTOM OF THIS PAGE - HAVE A LOOK**](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest?page=8&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It does say **Make sure to look at the "[active](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest?answertab=active#tab-top)" tab for this question to see new submissions.** which is like that but better. :)

Answer (score 27):

**Perfect reflection**

[image: Perfect reflection]

Nikon D3500, Nikkor 18-55mm at 26mm, aperture f/16, shutter 1/50s, ISO 100.

⛰️ Lake Matheson in New Zealand.

Answer (score 23):

[image: ‘Ferns' Orb, occluding the sun - Wellington Civic Square]

‘[Ferns](https://www.sculpture.org.nz/the-sculptures/ferns)' Orb, occluding the sun - Wellington Civic Square.
Shot on RPX25 35mm film

[Full Size](https://photo.darcythomas.com/post/182677463026/wellington-civic-square-fern-orb-shot-on-rpx25)

Comment: Nice pic! What's a Ferns orb?

Comment: @deschelescilder It s a sculpture in the Wellington Civic Square. More info and views from different angles: https://www.sculpture.org.nz/the-sculptures/ferns

Comment: Great work of art!

Answer (score 22):

#### Monochrome sparrow

[image: Tree sparrow on log]

[Full size on Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/taylor_pj/33454988742/in/album-72157678212507264/)

The subject is a tree sparrow (*Passer montanus*). Taken in the Delta del Ebro national park in Spain. The thing which I love about this is how a one-colour palette<sup>1</sup> can still allow so much beauty.

<sup>1</sup> If I convert to HSL, change the hue for every pixel to be the average of the whole image, and convert back, only someone who knows their sparrows would spot that something was wrong without doing a side-by-side comparison. If I ask the GIMP to reduce to an optimal palette of 9 colours (the minimum to allow the cap to be a different hue to the background), it really does take a side-by-side comparison.

Comment: Excellent photo, excellent write-up. Bravo!

Comment: That is an excellent photo, and kudos for using GIMP, it really is a very capable piece of software.

Answer (score 20):

**Dusk at the beach**

[image]

Larger image - [Dusk at beach](http://500px.com/photo/72209431/dusk-at-the-beach-by-kundan-bora?from=user_library)

CameraNIKON D5100

Focal Length18mm

Shutter Speed1/3 s

Aperturef/6.3

ISO/Film100

Comment: Hi, please see the rules of the contest with respect to the size of your image.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke It was taken with film. How can you resize that?

Comment: @10Rep Don't know, but somehow they did it (all the way back in 2014). If you've a question on how to scale photos taken on film, [feel free to ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) after you've [done some research](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfilm%5D+size)

Answer (score 19):

**Sunset through a peekhole**

This picture was taken via my mobile camera (ASUS Zenfone 2 ZE551ML) at Lake Pichola, Udaipur, Rajasthan. I kept the EV at -2 and ISO at 400. The image hasn't been photoshopped or edited via any software.

[image]

Comment: Please resize to comply with the requested format.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy: Is the image format okay now? I resized it via an online picture editor without cropping it. Please do let me know. Thanks! :)

Comment: You should crop it. Instructions say "210 px high and **up to** 375 px wide", so just drop the white borders around the picture.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy: Done! :)

Comment: Nice photo! Imagine what you could do with a DSLR...

Answer (score 19):

[image]

Nikon D3200

> Focal length: 260mm
>   Aperture: f/5.6
>   Shutter: 1/640s
>   ISO: 400

Answer (score 19):

[image]

A colorful bench mosaïc somewhere in colorful Amsterdam

Comment: Accidentally downvoted this, sorry

Comment: I'll edit. No problem.

Comment: @the_limey You can vote back up again.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Two Lion brothers sharing an affectionate moment.]

Answer (score 18):

### Hamburger Bahnhof - Berlin

[image]

An [Enfuse](http://enblend.sourceforge.net/index.htm) composite of three photos. [Bigger version](http://500px.com/photo/25344567)

Comment: Why is there a 'Hamburg station' in Berlin though?

Comment: It's a former train station of the Berlin-Hamburg railway line. Hence the "Hamburg station" I guess. [Now it's a contemporary art museum.](http://www.hamburgerbahnhof.de/text.php)

Comment: Note that this entry has an illegal downvote, which should not be counted for contest purposes, because downvoting is against the rules.

Answer (score 18):

### ***Portrait of a Barred Owl***

[image: Portrait of a Barred Owl]

[See the rest of the set here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/camflan/sets/72157629969057124/)

Comment: Note that this entry has an illegal downvote, which should not be counted for contest purposes, because downvoting is against the rules.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this, sorry

Answer (score 18):

### Taxi Noir

[image]

An urban abstract shot with a modified square-aperture lens.

Higher-res view and more info on Deviantart: http://fav.me/dan283o

Answer (score 18):

**Icicle melting of a flower bud**

Captured this moment on a cold April morning as the frost was starting to melt.

> Nikon D5200 f/18 1/200 ISO-620 taken with reverse ring method (hence focal length not known)

[image]

Answer (score 18):

[image]

I was sitting near a wooden hut and saw this little kid playing and had to take a photo of this kid with such a background in the alps.

Full-sized picture can be found [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/143056154@N07/29096093921/)

Comment: lol. I couldn't tell that the kid was swinging just by looking at the small picture. I thought maybe he was climbing a 5.15 or 6.0 pitch like a world class rock star. Nice picture!

Comment: @scottbb haha thanks!

Answer (score 18):

### "Hey, what's up?!"

[image]

This photo was taken in June 2018, in the Gobi desert.

```
Camera: Panasonic Lumix G DMC-G81
Focal Length: 140mm (full frame equiv.: 280mm)
Aperture: f/5.6
Shutter: 1/1000
ISO: 320
```

Answer (score 17):

Willow in a foggy autumn morning...

Taken handheld with Canon 700D and 70-300mm lens.

Settings: 70mm, 1/8 sec, f/16, ISO 200

[image]

Comment: See item 4 in the "Submitter Rules above - It says:  "Images must be 210 pix high and up to 375 pix wide. This is the requirement for the header. Please feel free to provide a link to a larger version, but as explained above, the primary focus is on the header image." - you'll need to downsize this tomeet this requirement.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon done, thank you for the notice

Answer (score 17):

[image: Borderline]

Full image version: https://unsplash.com/photos/_5JtKjB3mto

I loved how the ocean waves merged the water with the shore, and the two "smiles" in the water were like some kind of audience.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

Shot with Sony A7R and adapted Carl Zeiss 25mm Distagon (for C/Y mount), ISO 100, f/8, bracketed around 1/500s (3 exposures combined in Photomatix with final adjustments in Lightroom)

Answer (score 16):

[image]

```
Camera        Canon EOS 5D
Exposure      0.02 sec (1/50)
Aperture      f/2.8
Focal Length  50 mm
ISO Speed     1600
```

Original in portrait, available at [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/eddypoon/8876583170/sizes/l/)

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Taken with my first DSLR, a Nikon D3200.

Shot at Lake George, NY.

```
ISO 100 @ 1/400
```

Comment: Hi pobourgeois, please read the rules in regards to size. Your image must be 210px in height (As a requirement for the site header on the [main](http://photo.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: I did my checkout dives for my scuba diving on Lake George.  Always forget that it is actually someplace people visit.

Comment: Yes ! We are from Quebec, Canada and I went there with my family. Awesome landscapes and great city with all the outlets and little shops/store around the lake. We really enjoyed our trip !

Comment: Note that this entry has an illegal downvote, which should not be counted for contest purposes, because downvoting is against the rules.

Answer (score 16):

## [Sun-rays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqDSA.jpg)

Taken while hiking through Bymarka in Trondheim, Norway.

[image]

Comment: The link had died...

Comment: @FighterJet Thanks for the heads-up. Unfortunately I do not have a Flickr account anymore, so I a afraid the link will stay dead for a while.

Comment: That's fine; I was thinking it would make a great desktop background, which is why I wanted the big version.

Comment: @FighterJet I've posted the link on [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/lrT2KCX.jpg) and updated the link my original post. Hope you enjoy it as a desktop background!

Answer (score 16):

**Rialto at night**

[image: Rialto Bridge at night]

Taken on a lovely stroll through the nighttime Venice, Italy. It is remarkably quiet and peaceful there at night.

Answer (score 16):

This is a picture of a RF toy helicopter flying in front of a painting of [Ladakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladakh), painted by my mother.

[image]

Full size image available at [500px](https://500px.com/photo/91326323/let%27s-visit-ladakh-by-aditya-mahajan)

Comment: Wow - almost real!

Comment: Great, it looks super real if you don't know it wasn't a real helicopter :)

Answer (score 16):

### Capture

[image]

Higher-res view and more info on Deviantart: http://fav.me/diowsg

Answer (score 16):

### Green light for love

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Tree in Vedauwoo, WY.

[image: tree]

Larger version [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/larskotthoff/40899113014/in/album-72157689447336222/).

Comment: I really like this. Very nice image!

Comment: @scottbb Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

[image: Just a few well love pencils]

Answer (score 15):

[image]

[Larger Version](http://500px.com/photo/61048020)

I have taken pictures that are much more [technically demanding](http://500px.com/photo/48110746), but I like this one because it makes the most of a drab setting: a small Phoenix, AZ backyard in winter.

- Canon 6D with 24-105mm L
- Edited with Lightroom and Exposure 5

Comment: I love it!! very cute!!

Answer (score 15):

## The roof at Utrecht Central Station

[image]

Answer (score 14):

**Let the day begin!** / [500px](http://500px.com/photo/15151491)

[image: 123123213.jpg]

I wish good luck to all!

Answer (score 14):

[image: Hermit crab]

Camera: Nikon D90 + 18-200
Focal distance: 200mm (like 300mm on 35mm-film)
ISO: 200
Aperture: f/8
Shutter speed: 1/160s
Mode: full auto :-b

I still had not learnt the manual/priority modes, but I'm proud of this photo. Extracted from raw with manual adjustment of chromatic aberration, curves, saturation... Maybe I boosted the contrast too much...

Comment: not that I'm a very good photographer but I'm finding it difficult to concentrate on the main subject.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @SandeepSinghRawat. Maybe I will try a different crop.

Comment: I think the cropping and subject content is OK. Depending on the original I MIGHT have moved the frame right slightly - but maybe not. A link to a larger version and what is outside the cropping would be useful. | One problem with the small image size PLUS the 1.78:1 crop demanded by the format here (if you want a max allowed size image), is that it significantly affects the content and cropping choice. Crop for best appearance and the image often loses "punch" as a header. Crop for max punch and you lose content.

Comment: ... In this case, if you crop to increase subject content you either decrease width or start losing legs at bottom and or shell at top. I think what you've done is a reasonable choice. [This is all my opinion only - others may have quite different ideas. But, I've anguished over best-mix on a number of occasions and so far have had several that made their way to the top, so I guess that at least some agree with me.]

Answer (score 14):

### Low Key, Single Light II

[image: Guen, with hair static]

Tech details:

- Pentax K-5II, ISO 100, and at the ¹⁄₁₈₀th second flash sync speed.
- Pentax SMC DA 70mm Limited @ f/5.6
- Cheetah Light V850 in Westcott Rapid Box at ¹⁄₁₆th power immediately out of frame to the left.

[see larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjB1J.jpg)  (and in portrait orientation, as shot)

Comment: I love this, Matt -- I just wish I could vote it up as an image in its own right rather than as a header for the site. It's too "her" and not enough "pretty, high-quality, but ultimately generic photograph". As a people/product shooter, I get the unfairness of that; I'm utterly uninterested in taking pictures of anything that would make a good site header. In any other sort of competition, though...

Comment: @StanRogers Thanks, I appreciate that very much. I think site header photography really isn't for me either. :)

Answer (score 14):

[image: The Last City]

This was taken recently in Andong South Korea.  Its one of the last (if not last) traditional towns in korea.  While there a few korean towns, this is the only one that people still live in the traditional houses.

Answer (score 14):

Clothespins

[image: clothespins]

This is a photo I took for a contest with the category of Ordinary. I really like the way this came out, so I figured I'd post it.

```
Canon EOS Rebel T3i
Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II kit lens
Aperture: F/5.6 
Exposure: 1/400 
Focal length: 55mm
ISO: 100
```

[Full-size](https://sudodblog.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/img_1219_cr2_embedded.jpg)

Answer (score 14):

This was shot in my Nexus 5. I have no clue about this insect haven't gotten anything from internet search either. Any help on that while you appreciate this beautiful creation.

NOTE: Adjusted the levels in photoshop for this pic.

UPDATE (26-Jun): Resized to posting rules.

[image]

Comment: This has been downvoted against the rules...

Comment: @Jorge, It's also against the rules to downvote. Perhaps the OP can fix the size to conform to the rules.

Comment: I want to cry. I HAVE NOT DOWNVOTED the photo. From the rules "(If you notice a downvote on an entry, make a note in a comment" ... I was just noting it had a downvote in the comments...

Comment: @Jorge. Sorry, I thought your comment was explaining why you downvoted. No problem then.

Comment: @bbh It seeme likely to ne the caterpiullar form of Daphni nerii - the Oleander Hawk Moth - so named because they feed mainly on Oleander leaves - which are fatally poisonous to many creatures - including humans. [**Many images here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=Daphnis+Nerii+caterpillar&biw=1920&bih=1083&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO9qOn8uHJAhUDLKYKHXE5ByQQsAQIHA) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphnis_nerii) and [**Moth photo**](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Oleander_Hawk-moth_Daphnis_nerii.jpg) - wow!.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Answer (score 14):

### The Rusty Rocky Mountains

### as seen on a downpipe

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Ice Storm in Montreal

[image: Ice Storm in Montreal]

[Larger image](http://simplegallery.electricwishbone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/P1040029.jpg)

Comment: I can't see the storm, but maybe it's frozen. Or captured and fixed by your camera. I really like the red, reflecting thing with all its legs hanging (hanging on a little twig) very much! More technical, "the thing" is well in focus and it's color contrasts nicely with the blue in the center on the downside and the golden brown upper left.

Answer (score 14):

### "My horn is my world"

[image]

full size: https://www.flickr.com/photos/szulat/942683641

Answer (score 13):

### Long Neck Karen Tribe

[image]

Full Size [here](http://500px.com/photo/21334407)

Answer (score 13):

## Ready for a long journey

[image]

Nikon D60, Sigma 17-55mm

Comment: I would vote this up, **BUT** It is too tall by 7 pixels, as per the rules it must be 210px tall, and up-to but not necessarily 375px wide.

Comment: Thanks @damnedtruths: I resized the image to 210px tall.

Answer (score 13):

Taken with **Fujifilm Finepix AX280** *(which is a poor, compact camera)*

[image: Nigth]

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Comment: Hi there, please resize the image according to the rules above: Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide

Comment: just resized thx!

Comment: No, still it not resized, height must be 210px. set the height to 210px.

Comment: +1, great!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 13):

**Riddles and runes**

[image]

Answer (score 13):

**Campfire**

[image: Campfire]

Captured while on vacation at my family's summer property.  Larger, uncropped version [here](http://m-braedley.deviantart.com/art/Campfire-472807630)

Answer (score 13):

### Golden clouds

[image]

Answer (score 13):

**@Aero Show India 2015**

[image]

*A member of British aerobatics team Breitling Wingwalkers*

[Full pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jx0ofls9v98hihm/IMG_3356.JPG?dl=0)

Answer (score 13):

### The Pound

[image: The Pound]

Wilpena pound is a formation in the Flinders Ranges, South Australia that was used to contain stock and horses, due to its formidable cliff lines and singular easy access. It forms a bend in the ranges, which extend away to the north and south from the end opposite to that from which this photograph was taken. This view is towards the north west, from a plane on a commercial sightseeing flight. Unfortunately the plane's windows were quite reflective, so I had a little trouble avoiding spoiling my photos.

Comment: Place lens near the glass. Place a dark coat over your head and camera so there are no reflections inside the coat. Added bonus is that you can't see people looking at you funny-like :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Fortunately it was a sightseeing flight, with just the pilot, myself and my Mum, so no funny looks.

Answer (score 13):

**Chateau View**

[image]

- Fujifilm X-E1
- XF18-55mm F2.8-4 R LM OIS @ 18mm
- f/7.1
- 1/350s
- ISO200

(on [flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/32452677@N05/14613306887/))

Answer (score 13):

[image: bee]

Taken in the botanic garden in Munich (Summer 2015).

```
Camera: Panasonic Lumix DMC-FZ1000
Focal Length: 139mm (full frame equiv.: 375mm)
Aperture: f/8.0
Shutter: 1/125
ISO: 125
Marumi DHG achromat +5 dioptries
```

Answer (score 13):

Buck Seeking Fallen Pears

[image: Buck seeking fallen pears]

```
Photographer: Glenn Randers-Pehrson
Camera: SONY a300 + 75-300 zoom
Exposure: 1/125, ISO 400, f5.6, 300mm, no flash
Date: 1 August 2015
Post Process: Crop, resize, slight sharpen with GraphicsMagick
LICENSE: CC-BY-SA-3.0 or 4.0
```

Answer (score 13):

[image: Dubai Sunset from Burj Khalifa]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Photography is a play with the light!!]

Comment: Challenging and beautiful! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 13):

### Deer moment

[image: A deer with antlers looks at something out of shot]

Taken at Richmond Park, London

```
Nikon D7000
Nikon 70-300mm @ 145mm
f/4.5
1/60 sec
IS0-1600
24/10/2015
```

Answer (score 13):

[image: Grenadine]

Grenadine

For a high-res version see [the image on 500px](https://500px.com/photo/131416763/granatapfel-by-hermann-klecker)

Exposure time is about 30s, the only source of light was a torch.

Answer (score 13):

## Clear to Land...

[image]

[Uncropped full size @6000x4000](https://i.imgur.com/rApk7TQ.jpg)

I chased this bee (or one very, very similar ;-) all week.
It would arrive mid-morning & flit around this large yellow flowering bush against a whitewashed wall for 3 or 4 mins, then leave, not to return until the next day.

I was determined to snap it in flight & freeze the wings.

I cannot claim that it is pin-sharp at full resolution, but not bad for a beginner.

Nikon D5500 Tamron 70-300mm f/4-5.6G @185mm macro f/7.1 1/800s ISO 1250 - Full manual, sunlight only.

Answer (score 13):

**Fire is Diabolic, Too**

Can you spot a devil's face? Renamed after descheleschilder pointed it out.

[image]

Nikon D3300, Kit Lens (18mm-55mm), f/7.1, 1/1000 sec., ISO 800

Location: Kerala, India

Date & Time: Mon, 20 May 2017 4:25:23 PM IST

Cropped & Color graded slightly (to make it look like night).

Comment: Nice one again! This fire can't be extinguished anymore (though it can be deleted)! And again I see a little devil [at least his (though many times it's a she) horns], in the center of the picture. Let's send one in each week (which I already did)!

Comment: @descheleschilder Thank you! I hadn't noticed the devil, but I clearly spot a face now in the left hand side (once you notice, it is hard to forget). UPDATE: I've renamed it!

Comment: After some staring, the little devil on the left suddenly popped out! He's looking angry and even seems to have hands! I see why you changed the title! And while I'm looking at your picture right now, the devil in the middle has become a dragon's head. The more you look, the more you see (mostly faces). I've never photographed fire, so I think you know what I'm gonna try.

Answer (score 13):

Smoking away in Moonlight

[image: Smoking away in Moonlight]

Comment: It made me remember one of my life moment.

Comment: Glad! :) thanks...

Comment: actually, I should thank You for posting this. Thank You so much.

Comment: This has a downvote.

Answer (score 13):

Sunbath

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Samsung WB250F
f/5.6
1/180 sec
ISO 800
actual focal length - 50mm
35mm equivalent focal length - 306mm
```

Comment: Yeah, just noticed, sorry for that

Answer (score 12):

**Silhouette of Fountain**

[image: Silhouette of Fountain]

[Larger Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jonakhtar/8624472707/in/photostream)

- Canon 60D
- EF24-70mm f/2.8L USM
- 1/1600
- ƒ/3.5
- ISO 200
- 51 mm

Comment: Love the droplets, +1!

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Captured Using

```
Model: Sony DSC-S2100
Exposure Time: 1/250 sec.
Focal Length: 6.2mm
```

Original Picture can be found [here](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-iwtCaXe4d90/UlK8whOnErI/AAAAAAAACEg/rNB_9L6g4_g/w789-h592-no/DSC02420.JPG)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Photo.SE. Please read the contest rules and resize the image accordingly.

Comment: @BartArondson I have edited the image, please have a look now :)

Answer (score 12):

### Head First

[image: Head First]

Right on the edge of the field, behind our house on a bright sunny day.

Canon EOS 60D, Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM, ISO 100, 100mm, f/5.6, 1/500s, 0 ev

Larger version on [flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/88763641@N06/14298583256/)

Answer (score 12):

**"Spring is sprung"**

[image]

[Larger version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFVym.jpg)

In the Southern hemisphere it's Spring-time - on most days anyway :-).
Sony A77

Answer (score 12):

[image]

[**Larger**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hodz.jpg)

[On Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=447608181979349&set=a.414916571915177.95998.100001905146167&type=1&l=6028ebda9c&theater)

In album [**Last Train to Shuanglong**](http://bit.ly/LastTraintoShuagalong) - randomish selection of street photography over 2+ weeks while working in outer-central Shenzhen.

Answer (score 12):

Not at the level of the other photos but here's a spider :)

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Sunset at Santiago

[image]

[See the original](https://www.flickr.com/photos/123724886@N07/18830323324/in/dateposted-public/)

Answer (score 12):

Curious hawk (kite?) peeks at the excited human below:

[image]

Original (or as close it gets) [on Google Photos](https://goo.gl/photos/ybbN5wweK3Cf46yr8)

- Camera: Nikon D5300 with 18-55 mm VR lens
- Aperture: f/5.6
- Exposure: 1/1600
- Focal length: 52 mm
- ISO: 400
- Taken in Sameer hill, Mumbai, India.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Larger Version: [Here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/rony36/25498042892/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 12):

### Quicksilver

[image]

A grey heron - most of the time due to their colour they tend to blend into the background, or be darker than the background; this is an effort to emulate a more egret-like appearance of glowing white against dark, by catching a slightly backlit heron against a backdrop of dark trees, and making the most of the contrast.

Higher-res view and more info on Deviantart: http://fav.me/da2rfvl

Answer (score 12):

[image: Garden by the Bay]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Pangong Lake Camps, Ladakh, India]

Pangong Lake Camps, Ladakh, India
Canon 750d, Samyang 14mm, 90s shutter

Answer (score 12):

Taken with a Canon SL1

[image]

[full size and some more from that day](https://www.behance.net/gallery/44068341/USAF-Thunderbirds-FLL-Airshow)

Answer (score 12):

**Morning Lights**

[image: It's a morning light entering the city]

Answer (score 12):

### Bonboniere blues

[image]

Comment: Your photos are always classy! Are they right out of the camera (excluding cropping, EV and white balance) or color-graded?

Comment: Hi there Nandakumar! Sorry for reacting so late, but I only now saw your comment. Thanks for the compliment! It's always nice to get one. To answer your question: On some pictures (though the one above, taken in our living room, after removing all other things from the table, when the sun shone wonderfully on the blue glass, represents good what there was to see) I play a bit with the contrast and color. To give the image a little extra than representing reality (though every picture is abstract). I played heavily in the picture with the dark clouds. Very dramatic!!! I'm looking out to you!

Comment: Of courses the pictures are important even though they've had a little bit touch-up. Maybe you could share the links to the originals of at least one or two pics so that those who believe in 'get it in the camera' people can understand their real photographic quality?

Answer (score 12):

"Gaps"

[image]

f/1.8, iso 400, 1/10 sec, 3400k wb. 6/23/17.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

This is a winter view of Lake Michigan from Gillson Park after a recent snowfall.  I used my Samsung Note 4 phone to take the photo using auto setting.

> SM-N910T f/2.21/5964.6mmISO40

Answer (score 12):

[image: Mtk]

**Montauk**
aug 2017

[full version](https://www.flickr.com/photos/charlesrocket/36647747785/)

```
Phase One P40+
Mamiya 35mm
ISO 100
ƒ/6.3
1/1600
```

Comment: man, your flickr account is superb!

Comment: @watchme thank you!

Answer (score 11):

[image: Memories]

The original can be found [here](http://bramvanroy.deviantart.com/gallery/#/d5l8iju).

Comment: Note that someone voted this down. Downvoter, please see the contest rules written in the post above. (I'm going to make a meaningless edit to the post so that you can, if you want, remove your downvote.)

Comment: @mattdm Thank you for noticing!

Comment: purposefully upvoting to undo the downvote.

Comment: A downvote is still there.

Answer (score 11):

## [Fairy Iris](http://500px.com/photo/46562694)

[image]

[Larger here on 500px](http://500px.com/photo/46562694)

Comment: Same iris as here? http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/a/4085/4892

Comment: @dpollitt same bush, but different flowers. Although I admit it does look very similar.

Answer (score 11):

### Flower buds

[image: Flower]

> Camera: Canon EOS 600D,Lens: EF40mm f/2.8 STM, Shutter Speed: 1/1000,
>   Aperture: 2.8, ISO: 100

Comment: A week is 7 days. That much we should wait before posting another photo into the contest.

Comment: @Esa Paulasto i thought as per the contest rule every monday starts the week. am right or not?

Comment: if i am wrong i will delete my post.

Comment: It's a little ambiguous. My personal take is to be relaxed about it and as long as you're not _really_ taking advantage of the system, not worry too much.

Answer (score 11):

**Frosty Bath**

[image: Polar bird bath]

[Larger version here](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7387/11862433523_b995bd4cb5_b.jpg)

It was -16F when I took this through our kitchen window.

Nikon D5300, using a Nikkor 18-200 lens.

Post-processing in Snapseed for iPad: I lightened the shadows a bit; the birds were a little dark against the snow.

Comment: I love it!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you! I'm amazed the heated bird bath held up in those temperatures.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

[flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/rony36/12417558934/lightbox/)

Answer (score 11):

#### Winter lake

[image: Winter lake]

Down by the lake a sunny winter day, just a couple of weeks ago. Now the snow is all gone. Strange winter this year.

Camera: Canon EOS 5D Mark II
Lens: Canon EF 24-70 mm f/2.8 L USM
Focal length: 34 mm
Aperture: 8
Shutter time: 1/320 s
ISO: 100

[Larger image](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=27272)

Comment: Where is it in Sweden?

Comment: @Wok: It's in Gammelby, Västmanland. https://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces?ll=59.869215,16.082911&spn=0.001084,0.002666&ctz=-60&t=h&z=19

Answer (score 11):

[To Build or Not to Build...](http://500px.com/photo/68986791/to-build-or-not-to-build-by-andy-m?from=user_library) That is the question :)

[image]

```
    Canon EOS 450D
    Canon 100mm F2.8 Macro USM
    ISO-100
    F/10
    4s
```

Answer (score 11):

[image]

[Flickr Link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/rony36/12948386933/)

Answer (score 11):

[image]

**Apple snail**

Camera: Nikon D5100
Lens: Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6

Comment: The rules have changed.  You do need it to be 210px tall, however, you no longer need it to be 375px wide.  It can be up to 375px wide.

Answer (score 11):

### Evening at Fish Creek

[image]

- Fujifilm X-E1
- 10-24mm 1:4 @ 10mm
- ISO200 - f/22 - 1/10sec

[link to larger version](http://41.media.tumblr.com/de25828c975b6917cf50f16adc8ab2f5/tumblr_nu2z7pMfiH1qaxrfdo1_1280.jpg)

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[image: A girl running - candid shot]

Comment: This still does not conform to the requirements.  It must be exactly 210 px tall.  It is currently 205.

Answer (score 11):

**Verstappen sparking through Abbey**

[image: Verstappen sparking through Abbey]

Taken at Abbey Corner (turn one) during Qualifying at the British Grand Prix 2018 at Silverstone. The Red Bull cars (this one being driven by Max Verstappen) were very low to the ground through the high speed corner, with the friction throwing up lots of sparks.

Shot with my Canon EOS 1300D, exposure 1/2000 sec.

Answer (score 11):

The evening at **Ponte Vechchio**, Florence, Italy - (2019-05-01)

[image: Ponte Vechchio]

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Stargazer Lily

Answer (score 10):

**Happy smiles...!**

[Larger image here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B13BBmXJu5uMaDBLU1VTN2I1RjA/edit?usp=sharing)

I went to **Danushkodi** , a Indian village destroyed by **storm in 1984**. Since storm life has been very hard for the locals. The only smile i could find there is here for you.

[image: I went to **Danushkodi** , a Indian village destroyed by **storm in 1984**. Since storm life has been very hard for the locals. The only smile i could find there is here for you.]

Answer (score 10):

## [Red Anther](http://500px.com/photo/30375889)

[image]

> **Camera:** Canon 550D 
> **Lens:** Sigma 50mm f/2.8 Ex DG macro
> **Shutter:** 1/800 sec
> **Aperture:** f/2.8
> **ISO:** 100

Answer (score 10):

Ant on flower in our garden!

[image: ant]

Comment: Contest images need to be exactly 210 pixels tall.

Comment: @mattdm I changed photo! thanks for your notice! what is your opinion about my photo?

Answer (score 10):

### Anya in color

[image: Anya in Color, by Matthew Miller. CC-Wiki in this size only.]

[View larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wiev1.jpg)

Pentax K-5ii, DA Limited 40mm f/2.8 stopped down to f/5.6. Developed from RAW in-camera; cropped and resized for the contest format in Gimp. No color tricks — she wanted her hair like that for the first day of school.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Sunrise over Kauai

12/14/2013 - 8:11am

5D Mark iii

24-70 f/2.8L II @ 70mm, f/11, 1/500, ISO 800

Answer (score 10):

A beautiful day

[image: A beautiful day]

Location : Buffalo, United States

Answer (score 10):

#### Bike saddle

[image: Bike saddle]

Caught a bike standing down by the harbour in Höganäs. Old and worn, but still in use. I like how things get character and uniqueness from use.

Camera: Canon EOS 5D Mark II
Lens: Sigma 50-500 mm f/4-6.3 APO DG
Focal length: 417 mm
Aperture: 7.1
Shutter time: 1/400 s
ISO: 125

[Larger image](http://guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=27082)

Answer (score 10):

Title: **Reaching out**

The photo was taken on the Italian island Ischia, after a sunny hot day. I tried to keep it simple.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## Still Life with Fruit

[image]

High-res view and more info: http://fav.me/daocvj8

Answer (score 10):

***The Brown Pelican elegantly gliding over the sea to hunt for lunch*.**

[image: The Brown Pelican elegantly gliding over the sea to hunt for lunch]

This shot was taken in Cancún, Mexico.

Answer (score 10):

[image: myimg]

**Model:**  Canon EOS 700D

**Exposure:**   1/125

**Aperture:**   1.8

**Focal Length:**   50.0 mm

**ISO Speed:**  400

[Full image](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/photography.medericburlet/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/01095346/IMG_9684.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

The Ferocious Small World

[image]

I was hiking around Arizona this summer in the Tonto National Forest east of Roosevelt Lake when I noticed a number of these Diogmites being quite active.  There were also many of these black flies buzzing around.  I saw this Diogmites chase and catch this fly, then alight on a low-hanging branch of this bush.  I had time to put on the macro lens, get down on the ground, and take a series of pictures getting closer each time.  The Diogmites let me get quite close.  They are fast and agile flyers, and I guess aren't bothered much by large animals, so having dinner was much more of a priority than worrying about whatever I was doing.  It probably also helped that I was approaching from just below the sun from its point of view.

12 August 2013 at 14:45, Nikon D3s, 60mm macro lens, f/11, 1/250 s, ISO 400.

Larger version at http://www.embedinc.com/img/d034-2288.jpg

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[flickr link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/106007475@N05/11250573006/)

Comment: Please remove the watermark as per the contest rules. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Thanks :)

Comment: Please resize the image according to the contest rules. Thank you.

Comment: done. thanks :).

Answer (score 9):

**Lueurs**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

#### Sunset over Mälaren

[image]

The last evening light falls over the lake.

Camera: Canon EOS 5D Mark II
Lens: Canon EF 28-135 mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM
Focal length: 28 mm
Aperture: 5.6
Shutter time: 1/80 s
ISO: 100

[Larger image](http://guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=24839)

Answer (score 9):

Tracks from a model train set on a wooden countertop.

[image]

**Details:**

- Taken in HDR+ mode on a Nexus 5 (4mm focal length)
- 1/16 sec. exposure at f/2.4
- Original high-res photo can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBkid.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

#### Jetty in sunset

[image: Jetty in sunset]

An old jetty in the sunset this evening.

Camera: Canon EOS 5D Mark II
Lens: Canon EF 24-70 mm f/2.8 L USM
Focal length: 52 mm
Aperture: 2.8
Shutter speed: 1/40 s
ISO: 100

[Larger image](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=27332)

Answer (score 9):

## Ancient Colours

[image]

Canon IXUS 132, 5.0mm, 1/60, F/3.2, ISO 100.

Comment: It looks like a Walt Disney. Where was the photo taken?

Comment: @Wok I took this while I was visiting Canterbury Cathedral (in Britain). This particular glass stained window was actually at the farthest corner of the building, which is why it's so dark.

Answer (score 9):

### ffm

[image]

This is part of frankfurt am main at night, a view I could enjoy for many years from the office, a perfect time for coding...

Answer (score 9):

**The Abandoned One**

[image: The Abandoned One]

> **Camera**: Nikon D300, **ISO**: 200, **Focal length**: 18mm, **F/stop**: f/16, **Speed**: 1/50

[Large version](https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5598/14988308134_1a0a3ceeba_k.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

Sunset @ Reservoir

[image: Sunset @ Reservoir]

Answer (score 9):

An antiques store
[image]

Comment: Beautiful pic! ;)

Answer (score 9):

## Water Color

[image: Water Color]

f/4, 28mm, ISO 800, 28s

Atchafalaya Basin

Answer (score 9):

This is one of monument in Lucknow known as Chota Imambara Situate in Husainabad near Clock house. This one was build under rule of Muhammad Ali Shah.

[image]

Camera Nikon5200

Comment: Please adjust this image to meet the image requirements.

Comment: @SailorCire As per suggestion i made it of 250x250. Is it not right?

Comment: @rptwsthi it can be max 210px tall, so 210x210 or 250x210 would be better.

Comment: @muru Oh Yes-Yes, it is of that size I had this discussion with mike, http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4191/mikew and he explained me that. As my image have it's feature that are best expressed in square image so I kept it 210x210.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Grey crowned crane]

#### Grey crowned crane

[Original photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/taylor_pj/25747493741). Nikon D40, third party 500mm f/8 mirror lens.

Answer (score 9):

## Serenity

[image]

Portland (OR) Japanese Garden waterfall and koi pond.  This is a very meditative and peaceful space.

Canon 5D3 & EF 100mm f/2.8L
0.6 sec @ f/20, ISO 100

Answer (score 9):

[image]

**A Pine cone**

```
Camera: Canon EOS 1200D
Lens: 50mm f1.8 STM
Exposure Time: 1/40 sec
F-Stop: f/4
ISO Speed: 100
```

Larger Resolution Image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcj9P.jpg

Comment: Can someone please review this image for me. Is there any room for improvement here?

Comment: t looks a bit gloomy to me, and looks better to me if I brighten it by using GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick "convert Pinecone.jpg -gamma 1.4 Pinecone_gamma14.jpg" which is roughly equivalent to old-fashioned darkroom work (PUSH ONE STOP is about -gamma 1.6).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'll try that out

Answer (score 9):

### The still life of shells

[image: The still life of shells]

---

Answer (score 9):

### A misty morning in Amsterdam, along the Amstel river

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Fuji X-Pro 2, 35mm f/1.4, f/4, 1/5400, ISO 200. Ocean Beach, San Francisco, California]

Answer (score 9):

**Fences are Diabolic**

Poets have always warned us about the diabolic nature of fences. Well, here is the photographic proof finally...

[image: Fences are Diabolic]

Nikon D3300, Kit Lens (18mm-55mm), f/5.6, 1/60 sec., ISO 800

Location: Kerala, India

Date & Time: Mon, 15 May 2017  05:58:19 PM  IST

Comment: Not many people get such a good focus on the devil himself!!

Comment: @descheleschilder Thank you! You know, it was in manual mode with manual focus, that too in the third day after getting my first DSLR!

Answer (score 9):

### Seoul, South Korea

[image]

Captured from my motel window by keeping the camera steady on a window pane.

```
Shutter: 8s
Apperture: f/11
ISO: 100
Focal length: 44mm
Camera: Nikon D610 
Lens: Tokina 28-70mm f/2.8 AT-X Pro
Date: 5 June, 2017
```

[Bigger size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P4SA.jpg)

Comment: Nice photo, but please resize it to conform to the contest rules: "Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide." [You can have the contest-conforming image link to the full size one](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5460/11924), if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for resizing it, but unfortunately, the dimensions still do not conform to the contest rules. Images must be **exactly 210 px high**, and **up to 375px wide**. Your resized image is not tall enough. You will need to crop from either, or both, side to get it to meet the dimensions for the contest rules.

Comment: Please read and understand all of the contest rules before making any more edits. Thank you for accommodating the rules by making the requested edits, but "Images **must not contain any artificially added borders**, watermarks, or decorations of any kind." Unfortunately, to use this photo in the contest, you're going to have to crop some of the width in order to make it conform to the size requirements.

Answer (score 9):

### Natural beauty

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Shot with a Canon T3i, north-east of Steamboat Springs, CO.  I was using 3200 ISO, 30 second exposure, and 2.8 aperture.  This photo was enhanced in Lightroom.

Answer (score 9):

## Climbing holds

[image: Part of a small climbing wall in my school's play area]

In my school's playground, there's a wooden climbing wall leading to a raised play space that the younger kids use a lot. The holds are arranged not quite regularly, and I liked the wooden texture, so I decided to capture that.

```
1/125 sec. f/2.4 3.97mm
ISO 146
Shot on a Nexus 5 phone with auto settings.
```

Answer (score 9):

[image: Fire fighting by heliocopter in Spain]

Fire fighting in Spain - carrying water to drop directly on the source of the fire, these guys can tackle fires in otherwise inaccessible areas. Taken with my Nikon 5300 and slightly desaturated in photoshop to highlight the heliocopter

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Photo taken specifically to answer a Photo Stack Exchange question

[How to get soft-blur effect on flowing water with iPhone?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/101364/how-to-get-soft-blur-effect-on-flowing-water-with-iphone)

Click for large version.

```
Samsung Galaxy S6
Time: 4 seconds
Sensitivity: ISO 50
Aperture: ƒ/1.9
Filter: Variable Neutral Density filter at unknown setting
```

Comment: Awesome -- thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Amazing sunset**

[image: Sunset in Corumba - GO, Brazil]

No filter!

In Corumbá - Goiás, Brazil

Comment: Gorgeous example of [crepuscular rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunbeam#Crepuscular_rays)! Nicely captured.

Answer (score 8):

Boat on Loch Ness

[image]

Canon 30D, Sigma 10-22mm f/4-5.6

Comment: I think without the red in the flag this would've been even better!

Answer (score 8):

## [Docking Ferry](http://www.flickr.com/photos/b8i/9429272808/in/set-72157634313639106/lightbox/)

[image]

> Camera: Canon 550D
> Lens: Pentacon auto 2.8/135 MC
> Focal length: 135mm
> Aperture: f/2.8
> Shutter: 1/4000
> ISO: 100

Answer (score 8):

**## Interior**

[image]

***Camera : Canon***

***ISO:100***

Comment: Looks like a spaceship corridor from a Kubrick film

Answer (score 8):

**Side view of *Iceman's* Car @Budh International Circuit, Indian GP 2013.**

[image]

[For more details.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/srikanth_vm/sets/72157637053647814/)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

**Butterfly And Bug**

Seen on a stroll through Schönbuch forest on a sunny day.

[High resolution on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/88763641@N06/10070790464/)

Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM on a EOS 60D, ISO 100, f/4, 1/250s

Comment: I like the way you mentioned the title.

Answer (score 8):

Nature Beauty on Camera Eye, memorable boating in evening river!

[image]

[Here is Higher Resolution of the photo](https://app.box.com/s/04qzenj7gcazzirgjucu)

Comment: Please resize to fit in contest rules; height 210 px, width max 375 px.

Comment: ok thanks, updated size.

Answer (score 8):

### [I,Oculus](http://www.flickr.com/photos/b8i/12577577693/)

[image]

```
Camera: Canon 550D  
Lens: Sigma 18-50mm f/2.8-4.5 DC OS HSM
Focal Length: 50mm
Aperture: f/18
Shutter: 1/250s
ISO: 100
```

Answer (score 8):

**Crystal by the Window**

[image]

I took this in black-and-white because the patterns alone looked so beautiful.

[F-stop f/2.7; Exposure: 1/1600 sec; ISO-200; Focal length: 4mm; No exposure bias; No flash]

Answer (score 8):

Early this morning (~4am), I finally got my courage to try an Astro photograph. This is the result. I'd appreciate constructive advice. This was really fun/exciting.

> > ```
> > Camera: Nikon D700, MC-36 Shutter Remote
> > ```
> >
> > Exposure: ISO:160, F4, 1/125
> >
> > ```
> > Telescope: Meade LX200 10" 
> > Connection: Camera adapter and T-Ring
> > ```

[image]

oh, it's the moon :)

Comment: I would think this is not quite the place to ask for advice on photography, not even if it was your first ever attempt at shooting a moon.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto Definitely not. It specifically addresses this in the rules. The answers become too cluttered and not focused on the photographs themselves enough.

Comment: You can leave the photo but please edit your comment. No constructive advice is allowed in this contest.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[larger version](http://itsuki.fkraiem.org/stuff/DSC01445.jpg)

```
Lake Tazawa, Akita, Japan
Sony DSC-RX100, ISO 125, f/5.6, 1/400
```

Answer (score 8):

### Spring

[image]

[Full version](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/106369837)

Camera: SONY NEX-5;
Lens: Helios 77m-4;
Taken on 2014/04/26 19:24:08;
Exposure: 0.008s (1/125);
Focal Length: 0.00mm;
F/Stop: f/1.000;
ISO Speed: ISO200;
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV;
No flash;

Answer (score 8):

### Opera

[image]

[full version](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/79009265)

Camera: SONY NEX-5;
Taken on 2012/09/16 19:52:43;
Exposure: 0.033s (1/30);
Focal Length: 20.00mm;
F/Stop: f/4.000;
ISO Speed: ISO1250;
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV;
No flash

Answer (score 8):

### [Sea Clouds](https://www.flickr.com/photos/b8i/15285503746/in/photostream/lightbox/)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## Contrasts

[image: sri lanka]

This was shot in Sri Lanka, i like the different levels of contrasts. No idea what the sign says.

Comment: I like it, but feel like all of the water is going to drain out of the right side of this lake!

Comment: hm, now you're saying it...; but the image is level. it's just the shoreline isn't strait.

Comment: Use rule of third

Answer (score 8):

[image: Brick Wall by Johan Wagenheim]

Brick wall in Oslo, Norway. Taken with Nikon D5100/Nikon AF-S Nikkor 35mm 1:1.8G. F/2.6, 1/60s exposure.

Answer (score 8):

**Husky eye**

[image: Husky eye]

[Full size](https://www.flickr.com/photos/l0b0/15827010308/)

Answer (score 8):

[**Detail from National Portrait Gallery in London**](https://www.flickr.com/photos/l0b0/16627361841/)

[image: Door frame with room number 12]

Answer (score 8):

Sunrise

Taken with Canon SX 150 IS

[image]

Link to original large sized version-https://i.stack.imgur.com/zotcu.jpg

Comment: @RussellMcMahon-Is it okay now?

Comment: Tatan - yess - size is OK now. You may wish to add a link to a larger version. Your original imgur version i at http://i.stack.imgur.com/zotcu.jpg and you may have a larger one again.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon-Thanks!!You are one of the most helpful persons I have met across this site....

Answer (score 8):

### Observer

[image]

Higher-res view and more info on Deviantart: http://fav.me/d8tu583

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Sunrise over Étang de la gruère, Jura, Switzerland 
[Big version on 500px](https://500px.com/photo/154804769/%C3%89tang-de-la-gru%C3%A8re-by-michael-bolli)
[image: Sunrise over Étang de la gruère, Jura, Switzerland]

Answer (score 8):

Pieten the Cat

[image: Pieten the Cat]

```
Canon 350D
ISO : 1600
Shutter : 1/125
Lens : Free lens, possibly 18-55mm
```

Comment: there's something strangely fake about the depth of field...

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft fake in a bad way I assume? I can explain roughly what I did if you'd like know

Answer (score 8):

"Pork at Sunset"

[image]

- Nikon D800
- off-camera Nikon SB-910 speedlight flash (to the right obviously)
- f4.5, 1/125th sec
- @ 35mm on Nikkor  18-35mm ED 3.5-4.5f
- ND Grad
- photoshop: Drop highlights, increase shadows, + vibrance, Cropped a bit

Comment: Please rescale to fit the dimensions of the contest (read Submitter Rules).

Comment: Ah yes missed that bit - done :-)

Answer (score 8):

#### A Man and His Dog

[image]

- Canon T5i
- 50mm lens
- f/4.0
- 1/500s
- ISO 100

(Full resolution image can be viewed [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nathan-osman/29804729430/in/dateposted-public/).)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Off the beaten path in Poland, Dolny Śląsk]

I took this picture driving through Poland, late at night.  This streetlight was in the middle of a forest with no other lights for miles around.  I felt that if I had walked out past the light I might have ended up in another world.  I still find it eerily comforting 7 years later.

Comment: I like this one very much! Thanks for sharing ;)

Answer (score 8):

### The Pair

[image: A Pair of Flowers]

```
Camera : Canon EOS 1200D
Lens : 50mm f/1.8 STM
F-Stop : f/8
Shutter speed : 1/320
ISO speed : 200
```

[Higher resolution here](https://500px.com/photo/177710157/img-by-recolightstar?ctx_page=1&from=user&user_id=19865417)

Answer (score 8):

### Upstairs-downstairs

[image]

In a little Italian village

In the middle of a hot day

Answer (score 8):

### Perpendicular

[image]

Comment: I swapped again.This time everything okay!!

Answer (score 8):

[**Water Drops at leaves *(click here for full size image)***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUIIY.jpg)
[image: Water drops at leaves]

Comment: This has a downvote.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Full Image: https://500px.com/photo/245481589/paro-valley-by-ankit-rajpoot

Taken with: Nikkor 18-55mm f3.5-5.6G VRII lens on a Nikon D5200 in Paro, Bhutan.

Exposure: 18mm - ƒ/5.6 - 1/320s - ISO 100

Enhanced in Lightroom.

Answer (score 8):

Jumping Spider

Chihuahua, México

[image]

[Full Size](https://500px.com/photo/279232519)

```
Nikon D3300
f/11
1/80
105mm
```

Answer (score 8):

[image: Cow secrets]

Comment: Great one! Ear cleaning or true love?

Answer (score 8):

**Mindfulness**

[image: Mindfulness]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Perfect colourful nature :)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Just stepped over this awesome illuminated office in Hamburg during one of my photo trips there at night in Oct, 2019.

Answer (score 7):

### She

[image]

[**a larger She**](https://picasaweb.google.com/117160077974455942367/December31201202?authuser=0&feat=directlink)

Comment: Please no more take sad photos!

Answer (score 7):

## Midnight in Kyoto

[image]

This is a hand-held shot with no post-processing. Larger version on [500px](http://500px.com/photo/6449033).

Answer (score 7):

[image]

- Canon 7D
- Canon 28-105mm USM

Comment: Nice neons! I lose neons to NTD on regular basis :( Any link to full tank? :D Sorry, I am a planted tank enthusiast.

Comment: Well thanks. I actually don't have a full shot of the whole tank posted anywhere at this point in time. I'm even newer to fish keeping than I am to photography. Ive only had this tank about 13 months.

Answer (score 7):

Super Moon !

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Comment: could you tell us where was it taken ?

Comment: Sure.  This was taken at Malpe Beach.  Malpe is 6 km from Udipi, Mangalore, Karnataka, India :-)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Long Exposure Camp Gorham, cc-wiki AR]

Canon 5D Mark iii, Canon 24-70f/2.8L II, Long exposure, full moon, YMCA Camp Gorham

[Full Resolution](http://www.ajhenderson.com/terranova/mens2013/content/images/large/OH2A0674.jpg) - Full resolution image licensed under CC BY NC SA

Comment: It's a pity the stars don't show in this size :(

Comment: @EsaPaulasto yeah, it's always a problem at the thumbnail size.  I should probably try posting one of the night shots that is less skyline focused as well.

Answer (score 7):

### Boston, April 20, 2013

[image: Boston, April 20, 2013]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/rony36/11967067964/lightbox/)

Answer (score 7):

### [Persepolis, Shiraz, Iran](https://picasaweb.google.com/117160077974455942367/January202014?authuser=0&feat=directlink)

[image]

Comment: They don't know value of Iran

Answer (score 7):

#### In demand

[image: In demand]

Found this at a restaurant.

Camera: Canon EOS 5D Mark II
Lens: Canon EF 24-70 mm f/2.8 L USM
Focal length: 51 mm
Aperture: 2.8
Shutter time: 1/50 s
ISO: 3200

[Larger image](http://guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=26517)

Answer (score 7):

NYC skyline as seen from the Brooklyn bridge on a lovely evening

[image: Skyline]

Answer (score 7):

#### Reed

[image: Reed]

Reed with the reflection of the setting sun in the background.

Camera: Canon EOS 5D Mark II
Lens: Sigma 50-500 mm f/4-6.3 APO DG
Focal length: 500 mm
Aperture: 8
Shutter speed: 1/500 s
ISO: 100

[Lager image](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=27361)

Answer (score 7):

### **Lounging Lizard**

This is most likely a male Peninsular Rock Agama. It's definitely a member of the Agamid family, males of which often assume bright colours in mating season.

I found this Agama at the site of a Jain temple near Bangalore, in Karnataka, India; some of the marble from the temple is visible in the background. Incidentally, original texts of Jainism based on Mahavira's teachings are also known as "Agamas".

[image]

[A bigger image can be seen here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151916379816503&set=pcb.10151916381611503&type=1&theater).
[F-stop f/5.8; Exposure: 1/200 sec; ISO-100; Focal length: 137mm; No exposure bias; No flash]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

- Camera: Canon EOS 650D
- Lens: 18-55mm

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### Autumn evening

[image: Autumn evening]

[Full version](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/97899086)

Camera: SONY NEX-5;
Lens: Helios 77M-4;
Taken on 2013/10/16 19:22:36;
Exposure: 5.000s;
ISO Speed: ISO200;
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV;
No flash

Answer (score 7):

**Female & Male Spidies**

[image: Female & Male Spidy]

```
Camera : Olympus FE 210
```

> Commonly known as ***Tiger Spider***. The big one is the Female and small one is the male spidy. Seems like time to mate.

Comment: eeewwww! Spooders!

Comment: sorry.. What is that??

Comment: I was referring to the spiders as spooders. It was supposed to be a joke. Sorry if it was confusing. :) Good photo!

Comment: Haha.. Thank you RPi :D..
I actually don't know what spooder means.. sorry :(

Answer (score 7):

## [Road to the wall of tears](https://500px.com/photo/33853951/road-to-the-wall-of-tears-by-jonas-liechti?from=user_library)

[image: Road to the wall of tears, Galapagos Islands]

```
Camera: Canon EOS 450D
Focal Length: 39
Shutter Speed: 1/400
Aperture: 5
ISO: 200
```

Comment: Hey jojo, could you please resize the image according to the contest rules? Thanks in advance!

Comment: and it's done! :)

Answer (score 7):

Unusual eclipse shot --- [bigger version here](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2015/03/21/eclipse/).

[image]

This was shot with a Vivitar plastic fantastic macro (100mm), with a bunch of ND filters on, and the strange shape arised when focusing on the tree instead than to infinity. A pity the flare --- but hey, with 3 filters, 2 step-ups, and the need of a relatively open aperture...  ;-)

Comment: That is amazing.

Comment: @Zizouz212 --- thanks.

Answer (score 7):

**Rainy day on Norway subway**

[image: A rainy day]

Taken with Nikon D7000, on Norway.

Larger version [on my DeviantArt](http://themauker.deviantart.com/art/A-rainy-day-463746069).

Answer (score 7):

### Ducklings

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Autumn**

[image]

[Large size](http://files.rahimi.id.ir/photos/tree.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Iridescent clouds with bird silhouette]

[Iridescent clouds with bird silhouette](https://www.flickr.com/photos/l0b0/24764186011/)

Answer (score 7):

[image: this is kind of an experiment in saturation, voting, and wondering who will read this comment :)]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

### Zzzzzzzzzzzzzooooooooom.....

Answer (score 7):

[image]

### Black and white in black and white

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Maple by Sunset by Brett Petch]

```
 Camera: Canon 550D
 Lens: 18-55mm
 Shutter: 1/2000
 Aperture: f/4
 ISO: 3200
 Taken: July 8th, 2016
```

No filters. Shot in RAW CR2.

Comment: Please rescale to fit the dimensions of the contest (read Submitter Rules).

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuMoy. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Smiling Face]

High Resolution Image at 500px.com -> [Click Here](https://500px.com/photo/177451591/street-portrait-2-by-mohit-aphale?ctx_page=1&from=user&user_id=14392739)

Answer (score 7):

Random Diwali click

[image: Random Diwali clicks]

Comment: Very nice picture! However, it is **1px** too wide, per the contest rules.

Answer (score 7):

Messaging over the black hole

[image: Messaging over the black hole]

Answer (score 7):

Lesser Scaup, Texas Hill Country

[image]

[full size on Flickr](https://flic.kr/p/NuLHz3)

D7000, Nikkor 70-300, monopod

300mm F/5.6 at 1/160 & 200 ISO

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Exif Details:
Camera : Nikon D5300
Lens : 18-55mm VR II
F-stop : f/29
Exposure time : 15sec
Iso : 100
Focal length : 35mm

To view original please visit : [Big Mad's (Parth Pabari)](https://www.instagram.com/p/BSqEXXuloZQ/)

Comment: Very nice image. But please resize it to meet the contest rules: "Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide."

Comment: @scottbb ohh it will lost beauty of picture. okay. am editing my answer to match criteria.

Comment: I edited the link to the image to point to the original full-size that you uploaded on imgur. Or, if you wish, you can edit the link to point to your instagram if you wish.

Comment: @scottbb its fine :)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

**together**

```
Ricoh Singlex II
Fujifilm Superia Xtra 400
Developed with Caffenol-C-M for 11 mins at 20C
Digitized with CanoScan 9000F II
```

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[Find original image file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByszTqH2o5mBcFBJektFVGhPT0E)

Answer (score 7):

**Ranunculus Study, 2017**

[image: Ranunculus Study, 2017]

```
Exposure:  
5s @ f/22, 50mm, ISO 100  

Gear:  
50mm Zeiss Milvus f/2M ZF.2 (Macro), Nikon D800E, Tripod & Cable Release  

Lighting:  
Generic LED 4"x6" Panel

Edits (via Capture One):
Crushed toe of curve to get a pure black background  
Color channel and hue edits to reduce green cast from low-CRI LEDs
Brightness and Saturation boost to enhance rendition of reds (LED fix again)
Additional sharpening to counteract softness of shooting at f/22
```

Larger version available here (with tighter crop): http://meklarian.tumblr.com/post/164299159803/ranunculus-study-2017

Answer (score 7):

Towards the Darkness

Green Pit-Viper (*Trimeresurus trigonocephalus*)

[image: Green Pit-Viper (*Trimeresurus trigonocephalus*)]

Answer (score 7):

infrared view of Wellington city, New Zealand

[image]

[higher-res](https://flic.kr/p/22EDo1w)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

The lake Nisser, Norway

Answer (score 7):

### A tiny, faraway water hose

[image]

Taken some years ago at the Italian island Ischia

Comment: I think you mean waterspout?

Comment: Ah, is that what it is called in English? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### Surprised Lemur

[image]

- **Camera:** Canon 700D
- **Lens:** 50mm
- **Aperture:** f/1.8
- **Exposure:** 1/250
- **ISO:** 200

[Click here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nathan-osman/39491042145) for the full resolution image

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Colorful houses in Stortorget, Gamla stan, Stockholm, Sweden.  I took this photo in 2014-08.

Answer (score 7):

### Bunny

[image: Close-up of a rabbit's face in black & white]

Taken in a garden in rural England.

```
Nikon D7000
Nikon 70-300mm @ 300mm
f/5.6
1/500 sec
ISO-400
2015-08-04
```

Answer (score 7):

**Green Fields in Punakha**

[image: Punakha]

Full Size: https://500px.com/photo/267477507/green-fields-in-punakha-dehazed-by-ankit-rajpoot

I captured this from my hotel room in Punakha, Bhutan. The view was mesmerizing and was only matched by the lovely weather.

Nikon D5200 with a Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6

32mm/ƒ/6.3/1/320s/ISO 100

Answer (score 7):

[image: Photo contest submission]

Macro-photography of flower using a prime lens and extension tubes

```
Camera: Nikon D3300
Lens: 50mm prime + extension tube
Aperture: f/9
ISO: 400
Shutter speed: 1/200 s
```

High resolution image can be found [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/161137455@N03/43886968670/in/dateposted-public/)

Answer (score 6):

Amazing Flower of Nature

[image]

Information of image

> Device Modal : Nikon D90

[LARGER IMAGE](https://plus.google.com/photos/107013515568843102002/albums/5835086137751834369?authkey=CPrph9aZq9jQQA)

Comment: Quote from the contest rules: `Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide. This is the requirement for the header. Please feel free to provide a link to a larger version, but as explained above, the primary focus is on the header image.` Please resize you image to fit that constraint.

Comment: @Dixit: You need to crop and scale the image according to the contest rules. If you do not, I'll have to delete this.

Comment: Thanks & sorry for that

Answer (score 6):

### At School

[image]

See their smiles [**larger**](https://picasaweb.google.com/117160077974455942367/March22013?authuser=0&feat=directlink) !

Comment: I like it.
I'm surprised this hasn't got a few more votes. While maybe not as grabbing as some of the 'visually splendid' offerings it has enough impact that it would not be out of place at the top of the page for a week.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, Thanks for your kindness :)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I like it, because of their smile!!!!!

Comment: What's with the sasquatch walking along at the bottom of the mural in the back?

Comment: @OlinLathrop, To be honest, I didn't get what you mean exactly :)

Comment: There is a dark furry-looking knuckle-dragging being at the bottom of the mural in the top left corner of the picture.  Perhaps you prefer yeti over sasquatch, but I thought yetis are supposed to be white (it's hard to keep all these mythical animals straight).

Comment: @OlinLathrop, He's just a 7-8 year old boy picking sth up (I cannot remember what was that) from the ground. Nothing more :)

Comment: @OlinLathrop You missed mentioning the two pyramids at left rear, the white hooded watcher and the two crows? flying. - Which got me to look at the original. Ah. A mural. I hadn't realised.It also reveals your Sasquatch for what it is, alas - I rather liked the mystical version.

Answer (score 6):

## [5 down](http://www.flickr.com/photos/b8i/9378481046/lightbox/)

[image]

An old-school counter to count stuff.

> Camera: Canon 550D
> Lens: Sigma 18-50mm f/2.8-4.5 DC OS HSM
> Focal length: 50mm
> Aperture: f/16
> Shutter: 1/250
> ISO: 100
> Flash: Fired off-camera

Answer (score 6):

**[A Window at My University](https://picasaweb.google.com/117160077974455942367/September82013?authuser=0&feat=directlink)**

[image]

Comment: Its not even straight!!

Answer (score 6):

[image: Classy and real horse power]

Classy and real horse power

Link to Bigger Image,
http://www.panoramio.com/photo/95220405

Answer (score 6):

[image: Sunset panorama]

Sunset panorama

Nikon D5100, 18-55mm VR kit lens @ 55mm, ISO 200, f/5.6, 1/200s

I stitched a complete panorama from 5 images with Hugin, postprocessed in LR5, you can see the whole thing [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyrWp.jpg) (sorry, imgur caused a lot of JPEG artifacts on that one).

I just realized that it's similar to the current photo of the week, that wasn't intended I swear :).

Answer (score 6):

#### Hoop

[image]

A basketball hoop at the playground where I used to live.

Camera: Canon EOS 5D
Lens: Canon EF 24-70 mm f/2.8 L USM
Focal length: 24 mm
Aperture: 16
Shutter time: 1/30 s
ISO: 100

[Larger image](http://guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=23346)

Comment: I like the atmosphere this piece creates. It's like nostalgic innocence.

Answer (score 6):

### Low Key, Single Light I

[image: Guen with single light]

Tech details:

- Pentax K-5II, ISO 100, and at the ¹⁄₁₈₀th second flash sync speed.
- Pentax SMC DA 70mm Limited @ f/5.6
- Cheetah Light V850 in Westcott Rapid Box at ¹⁄₁₆th power immediately out of frame to the left.

[see larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Si6Q.jpg)  (and in portrait orientation, as shot)

Comment: excellent snap!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
f-stop: f/2
ISO: 3200
Focal Length: 50mm
```

Answer (score 6):

### Rainbow

[image: Rainbow]

full version http://www.panoramio.com/photo/76902131

Camera: SONY NEX-5;
Taken on 2012/08/11 18:34:32;
Exposure: 0.004s (1/250);
Focal Length: 18.00mm;
F/Stop: f/11.000;
ISO Speed: ISO200;
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV;
No flash

Answer (score 6):

### Cafe

[image: Cafe]

[Full version](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/100003977)

Camera: SONY NEX-5,
Taken on 2013/10/20 11:06:18,
Exposure: 0.008s (1/125),
Focal Length: 36.00mm,
F/Stop: f/6.300,
ISO Speed: ISO200,
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV,
No flash

Answer (score 6):

## Fly Agaric

[image: fly agaric]

Taken in Schönbuch forest, on an overcast day.

Larger version on [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/88763641@N06/10070920033/)

ISO 100, f/2.8, 1/50s, 17mm, Sigma 17-70mm f/2.8-4 DC Macro OS HSM on Canon EOS 60D

Answer (score 6):

### Summer landscape

[image: Summer landscape]

Camera: SONY NEX-5;
Taken on 2013/07/27 17:10:56;
Exposure: 0.001s (1/1600);
Focal Length: 18.00mm;
F/Stop: f/10.000;
ISO Speed: ISO200;
Exposure Bias: -2.00 EV;
No flash

Answer (score 6):

[image: coke can on the beach]

[on flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/kyle_jones/634382504/)

Answer (score 6):

### [Emadoddoleh Mosque, Kermanshah, Iran](http://www.itto.org/tourismattractions/?sight=1157)

[image: Emadoddoleh Mosque, Kermanshah, Iran]

Answer (score 6):

## Love In A Mist

[image]

Canon IXUS 132, 5 mm, 1/79, F/3.2, ISO 100.

Answer (score 6):

This photo was taken in Sep 2015, from the "Rock of Cashel" hill (Ireland).

[image]

```
Camera: Panasonic Lumix DMC-FZ1000
Focal Length: 38mm (full frame equiv.: 103mm)
Aperture: f/8.0
Shutter: 1/320
ISO: 125
```

Answer (score 6):

[image: Little girl posing]

Answer (score 6):

[image: butterfly]

Taken in the botanic garden in Munich (Jan 2016).

```
Camera: Panasonic Lumix DMC-FZ1000
Focal Length: 19mm (51mm equiv.)
Aperture: f/3.4
Shutter: 1/80
ISO: 125
```

Answer (score 6):

[image: Echinothrix Calamaris]

Echinothrix Calamaris (Sea Urchin)

Large version [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/lukeharby/6477103655/sizes/o/)

```
Camera: Mamiya 645 Pro
Film: Fuji Pro 400H
Exposure: Probably 1/60th
Aperture: Probably 2.8
```

Answer (score 6):

### Leaving home

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**ELEMENTS**

[image]

- Fujifilm X-E1
- Fujifilm XF 18-55mm F2.8-4 R LM OIS
- 1/125s, f2.8, ISO200

Answer (score 6):

[image]

### Railroad to infinity

Answer (score 6):

[image]

NewYork skyline from liberty island.

Uncropped larger version is [here](https://500px.com/photo/162469179/manhattan-skyline-by-shyju?ctx_page=1&from=user&user_id=10540419)

Answer (score 6):

[image: Maroon Bells Under Moonlight]

*Maroon Bells Under Moonlight*

Taken at the edge of Maroon Lake in the Maroon Bells Wilderness Area, west of Aspen, Colorado, USA, two nights before full moon, at 2:40 AM.

Camera: Nikon D800E
Lens: PC-E Nikkor 24mm f/3.5 ED
Exposure: ISO 3200, ƒ/5.6, 30 sec.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Taken in New York City on the Hudson River on 19th December 2011, on a Nikon D90 with a Nikon 18-55mm f3.5-5.6 AF-S VR lens. Post-processed to increase contrast and colour saturation.

ISO 200, f8, 1/500 sec, 26mm.

Comment: @scottbb Sorry, I overlooked the image width. Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

**Time connects memories.** 
Time is the most powerful thing in this world. You can't actually rewind it, but when you rewind this you call them Memories and you connect to the world you left behind.

Click here for a Full version:
https://500px.com/photo/176449291/time-by-mohit-aphale

Answer (score 6):

[image: Evening sky over the Ulsoor Lake in Bangalore, India. Shot using Google Pixel]

Evening sky over the [Ulsoor Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulsoor) in Bangalore, India. Shot using Google Pixel

Answer (score 6):

- Name: Boblbee
- Description: Bomb shelter in school

[image: Bomb shelter]

[Flickr-full size photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/144300465@N06/29773873784/in/dateposted-public/lightbox/)

Nikon D3300

Answer (score 6):

**Boat On Logs**

[image]

This one fascinated me with it's unique nature. How often you see boat on logs. Higher resolution can be [checked here](https://www.instagram.com/p/BKgiZNrgQVq/?taken-by=rptwsthi).

Answer (score 6):

Evening over Ulsoor Lake, Bangalore. 
Shot using Google Pixel. Minor color retouch in photoshop.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Redhaired Model in apple trees]

Photographer: Igor Masin

Camera: Canon EOS 6D
Exposure: 1/180, ISO 100, f8.0, 100mm, Fill flash

Date: April 2016

Answer (score 6):

## One for the road

[image]

On the train station in the little town (Driebergen) where I live

Answer (score 6):

**Daytime Moon**

[image: Lua]

```
Photo cred: Me :D
camera: Pentax K-S2
lens: Opteka 500mm f/8 mirror lens
exposure: 1/400 iso: 400
developed with RawTherapee
```

Answer (score 6):

## Shoshone Falls at dusk

[image]

```
Canon 5D3 24-105 f/4L at 80mm
Exposure: 0.5s @ f/18 ISO 50
```

Original exposure determined by incident light meter.

Very minor post-processing corrections to highlights, contrast and white level. Otherwise only cropped to fit the required aspect ratio.

Answer (score 6):

**It's time to eat a tree!**

[image]

Nikon D3300, Kit Lens (18mm-55mm), f/5.6, 1/80 sec., ISO 100

Location: Kerala, India

Date & Time: 11 Jun 2017 12:31:33 PM IST

Comment: Haha! Nice one. If only his mouth was big enough...

Answer (score 6):

[image]

"On the Enoree." I spent the morning on the Enoree River testing different settings, shutter speeds, etc. At this point, the river is approximately 45-50 yards wide, and to get this particular shot I climbed across rocks to get the right spot.

You can view the [full size image here](http://markaguinn.com/wp-content/gallery/nature/Enoree_0021-copy.png).

Nikon D5600
32mm, f/29, ISO 100, 1.6 sec

Answer (score 6):

[image: Croatian Beach at Sunset]

Taken in Croatia on a beach in Podstrana at sunset in September

```
Samsung NX1000 @ ISO 100
20mm, f9, 1/500
```

Answer (score 6):

### Rua

[image]

*"Rua" is Portuguese for street.*

Taken from a tram in Lisbon, Portugal.

```
Nikon D610
Tamron 24-70mm @ 24mm
f/10
1/13 sec
ISO-100
2017-03-31
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm Cute!

[image]

Common Gallinule Chick, Central Florida, USA

[full size](https://flic.kr/p/W4S4Rk)

```
Nikon D7000 @ 280mm
1/320 @ f/5.6
```

Comment: Nice photo! Although, at this small size, I couldn't make sense of the apparently **enormously huge talon** compared to the rest of the body. Also, central FL represent — Melbourne, myself. =)

Comment: @scottbb thanks, the gallinules and coots all have enormous feet for walking on lilly pads and stuff, but on the chicks they look even more ridiculous!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Moon before *blood wolf moon*. Will post after next week.

[**Please view larger image** (It's much better)](https://ibb.co/Jrbs1C8)

```
Fuji Film X-T20
XF55-200mmF3.5-4.8 R LM OIS
f/11.0
1/180
ISO 200
1/20/19, 6:24:14 PM
```

Comment: Nice shot. Please note that the rules require that your image is **exactly** 210px tall, and anything up to 375px wide

Answer (score 6):

**A well deserved rest**

[image: A well deserved rest]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Hopeless - original [here](https://500px.com/photo/203516525/hopeless-by-ricardo-viana)

Answer (score 6):

*Loneliness* ([Full Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37IXn.jpg))

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Somewhere between California and Vegas (Probably near Baker)**

[image: Somewhere between California and Vegas]

[Larger Image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/vaishaksuresh/8316670245/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Images must not contain any artificially added borders or of any kind.

Comment: @dpollitt Updated the post with an image without border.

Answer (score 5):

[image]![Dubai - DUBAI][2]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE. Please take a moment to read the rules for this contest. There it states: `Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.` Could you please resize your image and edit your post?

Comment: Oh, and while you're resizing it, could you also please remove the watermark? This is also against the contest rules. Thank you!

Comment: Opps sorry yes i will re size and remove the water mark

Comment: "How about it then?"

Comment: Fixed :) sorry for being late

Comment: Please do not change the actual photo being used in a submission.  Minor changes such as fixes for technical problems (such as exposure), resizing or removal of watermarks and such is fine, but you should make a new entry if you are going to change the actual image.  Additionally, please be aware that the contest rules specify you should only enter one image per week.

Comment: Ok actually, the original file was not accessible to me at that time so that i would have removed the water mark that is why i changed the image and i added the next image after a week. although i just replaced the above .

Comment: This has a downvote.

Answer (score 5):

**Hibiscus**

[image]

Taken in Spain during my holidays.

Camera: Nikon D90

[High resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyiNL.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Light Trails]

Light Trails

An evening at the corner of a bridge in Ahmedabad, India

Comment: +1, light trails - how to do this ?

Comment: @Bala It's relatively easy, just set your exposure time to several seconds and click the shutter when the car comes in sight (actual shutterspeed depends on the speed of the moving subject).

Comment: hello Bala - you need to mount the camera on a tripod, set camera to Shutter/Manual mode, select your focus point, and set a shutter speed lower at about 3 or 4 seconds (you can vary the time depending on the amount of traffic and lights you need) - take multiple pictures varying the Shutter-time and you will get the desired result. I also set a low ISO number (100 or 200). Make sure the camera/tripod are not shaken during the process otherwise it would result in a blurred image. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Prague Castle (Czech Republic)

[image: Prague Castle (Czech Republic)]

4s@f/14 [ISO-200]

Answer (score 5):

### Spring!

[image]

full version http://www.panoramio.com/photo/90198483

Camera: SONY NEX-5;
Taken on 2013/05/10 18:58:18;
Exposure: 0.003s (1/320);
Focal Length: 18.00mm;
F/Stop: f/7.100;
ISO Speed: ISO200;
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV;
No flash

Comment: I like this one. It seems there a bit of distortion, am I right?

Answer (score 5):

> **Flower**

[image: Flower]

Answer (score 5):

### **Relic**

[image]

link to [original on flickr](https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3823/9291162386_4f27eb5dd8_h.jpg)

- EOS 7D
- 50mm f/1.4 USM
- 1/4000s @ f/1.4

Answer (score 5):

**Really Big Rock**

[image]

A large glacial deposit just outside Calgary, Alberta on the border of Okotoks.

[Larger version](http://www.vianesterhuizen.com/landscapes/glb116cgqc1ha7lbg8tkrsyzxw7act)

Answer (score 5):

### Church

[image: Church]

[Full version](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/93815945)

Camera: SONY NEX-5,
Taken on 2013/07/27 15:19:20,
Exposure: 0.001s (1/1000),
Focal Length: 18.00mm,
F/Stop: f/8.000,
ISO Speed: ISO200,
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV,
No flash

Answer (score 5):

### Motherland

[image: Motherland]

[Full version](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/99769505)

Camera: SONY NEX-5;
Taken on 2013/07/27 17:13:36;
Exposure: 0.001s (1/1600);
Focal Length: 18.00mm;
F/Stop: f/10.000;
ISO Speed: ISO200;
Exposure Bias: -2.00 EV;
No flash

Answer (score 5):

[image: Taken in my village in india -> tamil nadu]

Taken in my village in india -> tamil nadu

[**larger image here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qdPO.jpg)

```
Camera Brand: Nokia
Camera Model: Lumia 1020
Date Taken: 2013:12:22
Exposure Time: 1/1279 sec.
Aperture Value: 2.28 EV (f/2.2)
ISO Speed Rating: 100
Flash Fired: Flash did not fire, compulsory flash mode
Metering Mode: Averag
```

Comment: Please do not include the full size image in the answer. It makes the thread more cluttered and less readable. You can include a link to the image if you wish.

Answer (score 5):

### Clouds over Wiltshire

[image: Clouds over Wiltshire]

> Leica M9 | 15mm Voigtlander

Answer (score 5):

**Press any Key**

[image: Key]

[Original](https://500px.com/photo/85714319/press-any-key-by-alexander-serebryakov?from=user_library)

> Model - Canon EOS 650D
>
> Exposure Time - 1/80
>
> Aperture - f/3.2
>
> Lens - Canon EF 50mm f/1.8 II

Comment: What is it? (My first vote on this thread, since it is intriguing enough to stop my browsing)

Comment: @jdlugosz It's a telegraph, I think.

Answer (score 5):

**Alone**

[image]

[Large](http://files.rahimi.id.ir/photos/alone.jpg)

Comment: Nice! What kind of flower is that, if you know?

Comment: @Martha unfortunately, I don't know what its name is! I'm happy that you like it.

Answer (score 5):

**Golden Hour**

I was at the top of the Hyatt Regency in Sacramento when I was snapping pics during golden hour from the balcony with a view over the Capitol building. I was starting to think that it was all just generic shots when I turned around and saw this.

[image: Golden Hour]

Answer (score 5):

Wall detail at Prague castle.

[image: wall detail at Prague castle]

Larger version [on Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/larskotthoff/15051102361/).

Answer (score 5):

## Succulents and Sunshine

[image]

Canon IXUS 132, 5 mm, 1/15, F/3.2, ISO 100.

Answer (score 5):

**Between a rock and a hard place**

[image]

[Larger](http://bit.ly/BoulderDam)

Boulder Dam - or it was until 1947. Since & now = Hoover Dam. You knew that.

Comment: Nice picture Sir!!

Comment: Love this. Very musical and lyrical.

Answer (score 5):

Midnight Sun. No special lighting effects used.

[image: pic]

Comment: Just a tiny bit of advice. When photographing directly into the sun, make sure your lens is completely clean. The out of focus specs all over the photo are bits of dust or even perhaps spray and (for me) it ruins an otherwise lovely image.

Comment: @Chris OK. I got it.

Comment: I actually like the spray on the lens... but the fact that it's out of level bugs me a little. Funny what things irritate different people. :)

Comment: @junkyardsparkle Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Monkey

[image: Monkey]
A Monkey in the enclosure in City Park, Launceston, Tasmania, Australia

Answer (score 5):

**Eclipse through the Clouds**

[image: Eclipse through the Clouds]

I like this picture better than the climax where it looked like a smirking evil cat smiley from a cartoon.

[Large](https://500px.com/photo/102468695/eclipse-through-clouds-by-michael-riosa-nielsen)

> Canon 40D, Manual vintage lens Zeiss Jena 135mm F3.5 + Tamron pro 1.4x extender

Comment: You mean like [this one](http://bachelorburnbook.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/cheshire-cat-5.jpg)? That is what I was reminded of.

Answer (score 5):

**Green, white, red rocks before blue sky**

[image]

```
Canon EOS 600D
1/125s
f/11.3
zoom @135mm (image is cropped down a lot)
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: Dimmuborgir, Iceland]

Dimmuborgir lava fields, near Lake Myvatn, Iceland, in the afternoon. This is a HDR merge of 3 exposures, made using Google HDR Efex Pro 2 as a Photoshop plugin

```
Nikon D80
Nikon 18.0-135.0 mm kit lens @18 mm
f/14
ISO-125
Taken: 06/01/2015
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: Yoga At the beach]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Sunrise somewhere between Denmark.

[Original size](https://www.flickr.com/photos/geralds/23594441860/)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[Full resolution here](http://mmoy.piwigo.com/picture?/1543/category/15-nature)

Comment: What a wonderful collection of Nature photo's (mainly macro´s) you´ve made!

Comment: Thanks! That's the great thing with macro: spend an hour in your garden and come back with several amazing shots :-).

Answer (score 5):

### Lake Louise, Alberta

[image]

<sup>[* High-res version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3sXO.jpg)</sup>

**Camera:** Nexus 6
**Focal length:** 3.8mm
**Exposure:** 1/5988 sec.
**Aperture:** f/2.0

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
Location: Vidyasagar Setu, Kolkata, West Bengal, India. Popularly known as Second Hoogly Bridge, on a rain-drenched evening
Camera: Nikon D5300
Lens: Nikkor AF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 VR II
Focal Length: 38.9mm
Aperture: f/22
Shutter: 1/100
ISO: 1000
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

### Playing with a led ball, light, shadow and reflection

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Yosemite valley**

Nikon D5500 : 18-55mm,
ISO 400,
f/11,
1/500 sec

Answer (score 5):

[image: Sunset over Mam Tor]

[Original on Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/katwesley/31573730710/)

Answer (score 5):

**A wall**

[image: A wall]

```
Nikon D500
Nikon AF-S Nikkor 200-500 F5.6E ED VR @ 200 mm
1/200, ƒ/10, ISO 140
```

Larger: [flickr link](https://flic.kr/p/QaJ6EQ)

Answer (score 5):

### Ice figures in the backyard

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Underneath the surface

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Hurry

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Will it hold?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Striking light

[image]

Answer (score 5):

"Ghosts"

[image]

f/8, iso 100, 279", 3900k wb. 7/25/17.

Answer (score 5):

### Multiple reflections

[image]

Photo made in Utrecht (Holland) at (again) a new shopping mall

Answer (score 5):

**Loneliness, Sea and Sky**

[image: Passenger next to me in a Fast Boat, Maldives]

[Image on 500PX](https://500px.com/photo/236903525/loneliness-sea-and-sky-by-pasan-mallawaarachchi?ctx_page=1&from=user&user_id=24383681)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Glacier from above, Switzerland.**

[See full resolution image on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Switzerland_glacier_from_above.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

**Tugboat in Noorderbuitenkanaal**

[image: Tugboat]

[original size](https://photos.app.goo.gl/TZJCrEvSyW2mcx598)

> Camera: Sony Alpha 6300
>   Lens: Sony SEL-55210
>   Focal Length: 177mm
>   Aperture: f/6.3
>   Shutter: 1/500
>   ISO: 100

Answer (score 5):

Shot on iPhone X in Venice Italy.

[image: Venice, Italy]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

> Camera: Nikon D4
>
> Lens: Nikkor 24-70 2.8

Fullsize image [here](https://circlebphoto.com/lightning-1/)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Holidays]

**Holidays**

A serendipitous shot (the only kind I ever do) from our holidays last year in the South of France.

Answer (score 4):

**White Flower !**

[image]

Using Nikon FM2. [Bigger Image Here !](http://500px.com/photo/34948000)

Answer (score 4):

#### Reflection

[image: Reflection]

Taken at National Park "De Meinweg", The Netherlands. Larger image available [here](http://www.pritaeas.net/public/SO/DSC_0068_resize.jpg).

```
Nikon D40 with Sigma 24mm f/2.8
f/7.1, 1/200s, ISO 200
```

Comment: This would be awesome if framed to be vertically symmetric!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

High Resolution Image here: [Nature by Parth Bhatt @500px](http://500px.com/photo/43035372)

Answer (score 4):

### Nature's Red and Green Show

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Location: Dubai Palm Jumeirah.

**Canon EOS**

**ISO:100**

Answer (score 4):

**My Masterpiece**

[image: Masterpiece]

*[Larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ6TZ.jpg)*

```
Canon 40D, Sigma 17-50mm F2.8 @ 35mm F3.5, iso 1600
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Long shot](http://flic.kr/p/eUGdra)

[image]

```
Camera: Canon 550D  
Lens: Sigma 18-50mm f/2.8-4.5 DC OS HSM
Focal Length: 18mm
Aperture: f/22
Shutter: 10s
ISO: 100
```

Shot in Norway during sunset using the [Black Card Technique](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23836/9161) and probably with a ND8 filter.

Answer (score 4):

As I was performing a backup, this bee decided to check if the disc was connected correctly.

[image: Digital Bee]

Answer (score 4):

### Graffiti

[image]

Comment: Its more like a cyborg.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

- Camera: Canon EOS 650D
- Lens: 18-55mm

Answer (score 4):

## Apricot Blossom

[image: apricot blossom]

Taken on a sunny day in my backyard!

[full image here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/121897599@N03/13683947664/)

Answer (score 4):

## Bangles

[image: Bangles]

You can see larger versions from: https://www.flickr.com/photos/117290766@N08/13908738361/

Answer (score 4):

## [Sunset at Görlitzer Park](http://500px.com/photo/68085737/sunset-at-g%C3%B6rlitzer-park-by-bachtijar-?from=user_library)

[image]

> Camera: Canon 550D
> Lens: Sigma 18-50mm F2.8-4.5 DC OS HSM
> Focal length: 50mm
> Aperture: f/13
> Shutter: 1/250
> ISO: 100

Answer (score 4):

### Sunset

[image: Sunset]

Camera: SONY NEX-5,
Taken on 2013/06/08 21:30:49,
Exposure: 0.025s (1/40),
Focal Length: 18.00mm,
F/Stop: f/4.500,
ISO Speed: ISO200,
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV,
No flash

Answer (score 4):

## [Bright in the eye!](https://flic.kr/p/nrQNCt)

[image]

Taken in the community garden of Tempelhof Airport park in Berlin.

> Camera: Canon 550D
> Lens: Sigma 18-50mm F2.8-4.5 DC OS HSM
> Focal length: 18mm
> Aperture: f/2.8
> Shutter: 1/400
> ISO: 100

Answer (score 4):

### Summer

[image]

[Full version](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/91467511)

Camera: SONY NEX-5, 
Taken on 2013/06/02 15:15:00, 
Exposure: 0.002s (1/640), 
Focal Length: 18.00mm, 
F/Stop: f/7.100, 
ISO Speed: ISO200, 
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV, 
No flash

Answer (score 4):

Orange Line

[image]

This photo includes bits of Somerville, Medford, Everett, and Charlestown/Boston, Massachusetts, all in one seemingly-compressed scene. (Includes the MBTA orange line, control tower for the Amelia Earhart Dam locks, the MWRA 1.5mw turbine, the blue line of a big box store, and various industrial smokestacks.)

[larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQS9D.jpg)

Comment: I really want to like this but I'd want a bit more sky above the tall stack and a smidge of gap between the blade and the right stock, it is bothering me...

Comment: @PaulCezanne Thanks for the feedback. I agree that the crop is too tight, especially on the sky — that's mostly an artifact of the crop I made for the contest.. it's hard to fit everything in and be large enough to show the detail.

Comment: I also see what you're saying about the windmill blade and the stack; I also think that works better larger.... but I like it this way in a way I can't quite articulate... something about the square that's made, maybe, and a kind of connection between the disparate elements.

Comment: (I'll go back to my series from the day and see what I passed on; there are others from different perspective and with the blades in a different configuration.)

Answer (score 4):

[image: The Puppa]

This picture took with my Olympus FE-210 from my village in kerala.

Comment: Hi! It's nice to see you participating in the contest, but please take a look at the submitter rules. There it says `You may enter one photo per week. This is on the honor system, but abuse will eventually earn a strong talking-to.` Please change your entry accordingly.

Comment: @BartArondson: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. I didn't noticed it. I changed the entry.. Thanks for notifying me. :)

Comment: @BartArondson I believe the bigger issue is that two photos should not be in the same answer, else the moderators have no way of determining which image is the one everyone is voting for.

Comment: It was the bigger issue, but I saw no rules against it and addressed the problem in this way.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Orchid]

**Cute Little Orchid**

```
Camera : Olympus FE 210
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/FaBZNKV.png :)

Comment: Hi @eogavy, May I know why you added this photo in imgur website?

Comment: I could not add it via Stackexchange comments. Be assured, I've added it marked as "hidden", it does _not appear on the homepage/stream ([page](https://imgur.com/a/g3gcmyJ)) and I've added attribution in the description.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my contribution :

[image]

```
Canon EOS 6D
F/6.3
1/60 seconds
ISO-800
100 mm
```

[Bigger version here](http://500px.com/photo/81336581/-by-andy-m?from=user_library)

Answer (score 4):

### Warszawa

[image: Warszawa]

[Camera: SONY NEX-5;
Taken on 2013/08/13 11:30:16;
Exposure: 0.004s (1/250);
Focal Length: 24.00mm;
F/Stop: f/11.000;
ISO Speed: ISO200;
Exposure Bias: 0.00 EV;
No flash](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/101101900)

Answer (score 4):

[image: A busy street in New York]

**A busy New York street**

This picture was taken in the late afternoon at a busy New York street. The lights coming from the shops, restaurants, the reflection from the vehicles passing on the street, the faded paint of the old building, and a recent movie poster altogether were making this whole scene so colorful. I had to do the HDR processing of the image to really bring out all the details, and colors.

The full sized image can be seen here: https://copy.com/TkeMOnT2rfvjXRry

Answer (score 4):

**Fall**

[image]

A blurry image as a contrast to all the sharpness. It's a single exposure using a 1.6-second shutter, during which the camera was panned and then held still.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Hey there!**

[image: Animal]

Answer (score 4):

**Single and many (একা এবং কয়েকজন)**

[image]

[F L I C K R](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ihossain/16906057092/)

Answer (score 4):

[image: The Stray]

Comment: This has been downvoted against the rules...

Comment: Which rule has this broken?

Comment: No, i'm flagging the fact this has had a downvote. There's nothijg wrong with this pic. Downvotes are not allowed in photos in this contest.

Comment: Oh I see. You are saying the downvote was against the rules. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 4):

Red Flower.
[image: Red Flower.]

Answer (score 4):

Resting on a lazy day.....

[image]

Taken with Canon SX-150 IS

Comment: Please resize your image to conform with the rules: 210px high and upto 375px wide.

Comment: @damnedtruths-I have tried to resize it and posted an answer below but its too small...can you help me to resize the image??

Answer (score 4):

### [Mallcop](https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/12108770_10153613332993771_553598248160267877_n.jpg?oh=8982f15df24cf9a4f98d2c94dcfdde69&oe=56BBB3F3)

[image]

Shot from the hip,
at a one/six-forty clip
of the time.

Opened f-over-four, <sup><sup>(and a half)</sup></sup>
brought light all the more,
Kept the senses all low to a 100
and fine.

Answer (score 4):

Inyo National Forest, California, USA. Taken four years ago on my vacation.
[image: Inyo National Forest, California]

Answer (score 4):

Moon seen trough 300mm lens.

[image: Moon seen trough 300mm lens]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Smoke from chimneys, Paris]

Answer (score 4):

Covered bridge with a canon T5i

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Bee**

[image: bee]

[Large version](https://500px.com/photo/139656083/bee-by-tobias-margiani)

Answer (score 4):

An empty road at Sunset Crater Volcano National Monument, in Flagstaff, Arizona ([somewhere around here](https://www.google.com/maps/@35.4320679,-111.3904731,3a,75y,78.81h,72.23t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sYkusb-tLPfJ9JTLVY87njw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1))

[image]

Cannon EOS Rebel T2i • `1/100, f/20, ISO 100`

[View full size here](https://c8.staticflickr.com/2/1560/26680913055_c1e63121e3_h.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

***Delicate Arch - and beyond***

[image]

This shot was done from behind Delicate Arch, in *Arches National Park*, UT.

After hearing about the possibility, I spent about an hour climbing around and finally getting to the top of the ledge behind it. You can see a person standing in the middle of the arch (about two pixels high...). Most people never see the vast deep canyon that opens up right behind the arch.

10 mm, f 3.5, 1/2000, ISO 100, Exposure Bias -0.3. Shot on 2016-06-06 with a Canon T3i, processed in LR.

*View large [here](https://plus.google.com/+WillPirnasch/posts/8UsVD8RuDuD?pid=6308311228840555570&oid=107261077020442589198)*

Answer (score 4):

[image]

### Skyline of Amsterdam

Answer (score 4):

[image: Silhouette of Madam Liberty]

Statue of Liberty, as seen from the Staten Island Ferry, with the sun trying to peek through the cloud-cover.

Nikon D5200 with stock 18-55mm, 1/2000s @ f/10 28mm and ISO 100. 
Minor processing in Picasa.

Comment: The correction has been made. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Drei im Korb]

Canon 5D, EF 100 2.8 @ f/10, Studiolights.

[larger version on 500px](https://500px.com/photo/142588443/drei-im-korb-by-hermann-klecker)

Answer (score 4):

Moss

[image: Moss]

Clicked on Lumia 950xl
Full size image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcabY.jpg)

Comment: Can someone please help me with getting this into the right size please..

Comment: What image editing software do you have available?

Comment: @mattdm Nothing really. I can install one if you tell me - I have Linux, Mac and Windows running.
I am trying Paint.net. Will that do ?

Comment: @mattdm Figured it out ! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Yes, Paint.net should be just fine. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @mattdm Thank you ! The current one is fine, right ?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Golden Sunset over Hong Kong Airport]

Answer (score 4):

[image: victoria memorial, million mask march, London]

victoria memorial, million mask march, London - Buckingham Palace

Answer (score 4):

Tree Mushroom, shot using Google Pixel.

[image: Tree Mushroom, Shot using Google Pixel]

Comment: This has a downvote.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Connecticut College Arboretum]

Answer (score 4):

**Low tide**

[image]

Picture has been taken with an old Nokia 520 mobile phone. Vignetting is due to optics only. This picture has an unusual composition (sky has very few space) to give strength to the sand and the silhouette of rocks, the light reflected by the wet shore and the nice drawings left by the water on the sand during low tide.

Answer (score 4):

### Once upon a time on a ceiling

[image]

Comment: I like the composition, but it seems you rescaled the picture badly and got it pixelated (see the white fringe near the right border).

Comment: Yeah,I see what you mean, but what could I do?

Comment: Most decent programs will use a better rescaling algorithm than the one you used. If you don't know what to use, then try GIMP for example.

Comment: Alright! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Light in the walking shadow

[image: Light in the shadow]

Answer (score 4):

f6.3 1/500s 70-300mm #D5300

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Retro Tech]

This seemed appropriate for a tech themed site :)

Image created a while ago for the *Macro Monday* Flickr group, weekly theme "Rules" - full version here: https://flic.kr/p/DqHJJw

Answer (score 4):

[image: Alaska]

Taken in Alaska

```
Nikon D200
```

[Original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9lih4cha4lwMzdYdU0tWExVY00/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4):

Water drops on daisy
[image]

Shot with Sony a5000, f6.3, 1/400s, 55-210mm

Answer (score 4):

## Morning gold

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Water and Sky]

Shot at around 3:45pm, slightly reduced brightness but otherwise unedited

```
Samsung NX1000
Samsung 20-50 @ 20mm 
ISO 100 
1/100s 
f4.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Curious Olive-backed Tailorbird

Bali, Indonesia

[image]

[full size](https://flic.kr/p/22cSETY)

```
Nikon D500
1/320 @ f/5
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**Domino tower from the inside.**

[See full resolution uncropped version.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Domino_tower_inside.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Evening walk - Mangalore, Karnataka, India]

Answer (score 4):

[image: A morning sun bath]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yegYq.jpg), compressed by uploading to Google Photos and re-downloading.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Sunset @Köhlbrandbrücke, Hamburg

Answer (score 4):

**Bowling Pins**

[image: bowling pins]

Eindhoven, Netherlands

Answer (score 4):

#### Montopolis Bridge's new life

[image]

[Repost](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/113789/77292) of my entry from the new photo contest on the main site.

The photo depicts Montopolis Bridge, an important vehicular river crossing originally constructed in the 1930s and had around 30,000 vehicles crossing every day on average at its peak, but just this year, was closed to vehicles and got a new life as an exclusively pedestrian and bicycle path.

Shot on black-and-white film (Ilford HP5 Plus 400 pushed one stop).

Answer (score 4):

[image: Strange new world]

It's a strange new world out there.

Answer (score 4):

I hope my image will be seen.

[image]

I know it may not be the best, but it's one of my favourites.

This was taken with a NIKON D5000, with:

```
shutter speed: 1/500
ISO: 800
F-stop(aperture): F4.5
```

I am only 13 yrs old, and I know this is definitely not the best(in terms of geometry).

I can't upload the original because it is too large.

I hope you like it!

Comment: These are some beautiful colors! As a word of advice: watch the corners of your photos. Having things cut off by a corner or a side of the photo makes for a distracting effect. It's best to watch for it when shooting, but you can often crop so that the photo does not cut through anything. As a last resort, you may use the clone tool to cover these things.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica Thanks man! I will use the clone tool to cover it up. I really wanted to have the bottle show up, but I guess you are right.

Comment: It was just advice. If it goes against something you wanted with the photo, there's no need to follow it. What you wanted is more important than technical advice.

Answer (score 3):

[image: House, London, United Kingdom]

Taken during a stroll through London, United Kingdom. Larger version available at http://www.flickr.com/photos/tiredpixel/8466050072/.

Answer (score 3):

### Children in Boston

[image: Children in Boston]

Playground with iconic Zakim Bunker Hill Memorial Bridge in the background, the day after the marathon blast suspect showdown is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

God at work!

[image: God at work!]

Answer (score 3):

**Vast Ocean**

Here is direct link to view large size. [Link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/100150296@N05/9491005433/)

[image]

Comment: Hi Abhishek, to be eligible for this contest your image needs to be scaled or cropped to be 210px high and **UP TO** 375px wide. This is so that the image can fit in the header on the main site. Thanks.

Comment: @damnedtruths thanks for notifying, i will add cropped image too.

Comment: Sorry, your cropped image is still 3px too tall

Comment: Just put the cropped image in your answer. You can always put a link to the large image.

Comment: Now its in correct dimension.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekGahlot, could you please post the cropped version **only**? Although it's not explicitly stated in the rules I think it keeps this thread organised and uniform, preventing people from grabbing attention with extra large images. As Abhranil Das states you can link to a larger image (that is hosted somewhere else, like on Facebook, Flickr, 500px, etc...). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Miniature Monument in Berlin](http://www.flickr.com/photos/b8i/9833299435/)

[image]

```
Camera: Canon 550D
Lens: Sigma 18-50mm F2.8-4.5 DC OS HSM
Focal length: 50mm
Aperture: f/10
Shutter: 1/60
ISO: 250
Post-processing: Graduated Blur Filter in Lightroom
```

Comment: Where is the monument?  I see a bunch of buildings and a parking lot, but nothing that looks like a monument.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the size, but open up de flick link and it becomes clear that "the parking lot" is actually the Holocaust monument in Berlin. I agree it's not the best picture for the contest.

Comment: For clarity: it's [this monument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorial_to_the_Murdered_Jews_of_Europe) seen from a higher point.

Answer (score 3):

3D Sky!

[image: sky]

[Full size](http://files.rahimi.id.ir/photos/3Dsky.jpg)

Comment: Please resize the image according to contest rules. Thank you.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto thank you! I fixed it

Answer (score 3):

### [Yesterday's Campfire](http://www.flickr.com/photos/b8i/9129106751/)

[image: Yesterdays Campfire]

> Shutter: 1/4000
>   Aperture: f/5.0
>   ISO: 400

Answer (score 3):

### Calm in the Center of the Storm

[image: chill]

On the Esplanade Thursday after the Boston Marathon bombing. Suspects still at large. This area is normally full of activity.

Answer (score 3):

**Happy Flowers**

[image: Happy Flowers]

Answer (score 3):

**Ladybug!**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Shining

[image: Shining]

[Full version](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/78326392)

Camera: SONY NEX-5,
Taken on 2012/09/02 17:45:27,
Exposure: 0.001s (1/1000),
Focal Length: 18.00mm,
F/Stop: f/8.000,
ISO Speed: ISO200,
Exposure Bias: -1.30 EV,
No flash

Answer (score 3):

## [Epipremnum aureum](https://www.flickr.com/photos/117290766@N08/14136526856/)

[image: Epipremnum aureum]

Answer (score 3):

Sparrow Chick Sparrow

[image]

Fujifilm X-E1, 35mm, f/1.4, 1/125s, ISO 200

Answer (score 3):

**Potato flowers!**

[image: Potato flower]

Taken in my garden!

[See full size](http://files.rahimi.id.ir/photos/potato.flower.JPG)

Answer (score 3):

**Separation**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

***Into the Sky***

[image: Into the Sky]

> Camera : Olympus FE 210

Answer (score 3):

Taken with SLT A58 at 2.10 pm in the afternoon. No post processing, 1/2 second exposure, ISO 800, F/4.5

[image: Taken with SLT A58, at 2.10 pm in the afternoon. No post processing, 1/2 second exposure, ISO 800, F/4.5]

[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytzij.jpg).

Comment: "*Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide. This is the requirement for the header.*"

Comment: I see, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: You have exceptionally interesting afternoons!. Where was that taken?

Comment: From the Paris of the North, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromsø The two panorama pictures featured in the Wiki article were taken from the top of the hill you see on the left in my image. I was standing approximately behind where you see the boat in the second panorama picture. At 350 km North of the Polar circle, in the Winter you only have a bit of light around Noon time, dawn from 10.30 till 12.00 and then dusk from 12.00 till 13.30, and then it quickly gets very dark.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Gulab Jamun - Indian Dessert

[Larger version](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58285095/DSC_0503.JPG)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[Orginal Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93201119/ClikZ/rakesh_kr_12.jpg)

Comment: that would make a god top of page photo BUT please note the maximum allowed photo size. In the submission rules it says "Images **must** be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide. This is the requirement for the header. Please feel free to provide a link to a larger version ..." - this is an essential requirement as the image MUST fit as-supplied in the space on the front page. Height MUST be 210. Width can be 375 or less. So both size and aspect ratio may need adjusting. I have added a cropped downsized adjusted version of your image as an example only. Please replace with your version.

Answer (score 3):

Christmas old days

[image]

[Link to the original photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/hmilad/16164633552/)

Answer (score 3):

White-Breasted Nuthatch in winter.

[image]

[Larger here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2apNq.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

Strawberry, a macro picture using extension tube

[image: Strawberry]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

while i went to trekking at ooty of tamilnadu snaped this image at my xolo hive mobile phone

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Equipment: Canon EOS1200D, Canon 50mm f/1.8 STM.
1/80s
ISO100
f/1.8

Answer (score 3):

**Tree silhouette in clear sky.**

[image]

Capture with samsung j5. UNEDITED picture. no filters.

Answer (score 3):

#### [metal thorns / uninhabited watchtower](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwzrN1KmDAUDXzhfV3djbno5R1k/view?usp=sharing)

[image: the photo]

I think, any equipment could do. I used `Nikon D7100` + `Nikon AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR`.
Parameters: `f/16, 1/60 seconds, 44mm focal length, ISO 560`; I think I was using `Av` mode, because I use it almost always. Also I was probably using a polarizing filter.
It was shot about 8 months ago.
There's not very much editing apart from bringing up shadows—just some standard steps necessary to process a **raw** file.

Answer (score 3):

[image: In the Gardens by the President's House, University of Illinois. Pentax K5-II, 230mm, f/8.0, 1/320 second]
In the Gardens by the President's House, University of Illinois.  Pentax K5-II, 230mm, f/8.0, 1/320 second

Answer (score 3):

### Arthur on the Esplanade

[image: Arthur on the Esplanade]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

### On the boat to Ischia

Answer (score 3):

Spiders Prey
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Beautiful Yellow Flower | GALAXY S6**

```
Exif:  
SM-G920F
4.3mm/ƒ/1.9/1/261s/ISO 40
```

[View Large on 500px](https://500px.com/photo/169239655/yellow-flower-jpg-by-khizar-ahmed#)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Roses**

[image: Etwas Blumen]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Elk]

Answer (score 3):

## Waiting for the flower colors

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

- North London, UK
- Olympus mju ii / Kodak Gold 200 - 135

Answer (score 3):

***Mobile Click***

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Winter in Düsseldorf

[image: Winter in Düsseldorf]

Comment: Sorry -- my mistake... it looked like the wrong height to me (maybe because of the different aspect ratio), and I think I misread the result when I measured.

Comment: @Caleb No problem. But why measure? You can always see exact image dimensions in its properties (available on right click in most browsers).

Answer (score 3):

### "Don't go so fast!"

### "Don't yóu go so slow!"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Target!!!!**

[image]

Check the full version of image [here](https://www.eyeem.com/p/117204955)

**PS:** Trying my hands on DSLR for first time.

Answer (score 3):

**Fisherman @ sea**

[image: **Fisherman @ sea**]

This pic was taken at sea near chennai using my Iphone 7
[Click here to view high quality image](https://www.facebook.com/digiphotogal/photos/rpp.659549744096364/1788917134492947/?type=1&theater)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Samsung 9+]

```
Camera: Samsung SM-G965W (Galaxy S9+)
Aperture: F2.4 | Focal length  6.00 mm
ISO 32         | Exposure time: 1/152 s
```

Trying out my new camera and it's computational photography DOF feature.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Lovely Pollachi- **Modern Rice Mill**,

Mobile: 13MP Rear Camera

Answer (score 3):

[image: Sunset over the Golan]

Sunset over the Golan Heights.

This was snapped with my GoPro Hero 7 Black. Full version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i1GP.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

## Cockatoos at Sunset

[image: Coackatoos at Sunset]

Answer (score 3):

**Marsden village in pre-dawn light.**    16/02/19

[image: Marsden village in pre-dawn light]

```
    Camera: Olympus E-520 @ iso 100 30 seconds
    Lens: Olympus ZD 11-22mm f2.8-3.5 @ 18mm f3.2
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: Gang of five]

Answer (score 3):

**In the Dark**

[image]

Taken using Samsung Galaxy A-30 mobile device.

```
Aperture: F/1.7

Exposure: 1/245 s

ISO: 40
```

As seen from the exif data.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Pretoria Bridge over the Rideau Canal]

Answer (score 2):

**A wallaby has called me**

[image: Jardin des Plantes]

Taken in the [Jardin des Plantes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jardin_des_Plantes) at the beginning of May 2013.

Here is [a link to a higher resolution of the picture](http://wakaziva.pagesperso-orange.fr/photo/Image-Wallaby-2013-grand-format.jpg).

Comment: Note that the resolution of your post does not match the required resolution for submissions.  It needs to be 210 tall by 375 wide to fit in the banner.

Comment: it's only 210 pixels wide and 158 tall.  It has to actually be 375 pixels wide in addition to being 210 pixels tall.

Comment: it's not by choice.  It's a technical limitation of what fits in the banner.  The top vote each week goes in the spot on the top of the main site and the image has to be exactly 375 by 210 in order to fit correctly.  It's a custom feature that StackExchange hacked together for us, so more or less "beggers can't be choosers" applies in terms of what support the layout gives us.

Comment: @AJHenderson (and wok) The image does not **need** to be 375px wide. It **MUST** be 210px tall and must be landscape. The 5th dot point of "Submitter Rules" says "Images must be 210px high and **up to** 375px wide"

Comment: @damnedtruths - well what do you know.  I guess I had missed that part way back when.  Good to know.

Comment: @AJHenderson: Or you missed when that detail of the rules changed. An exact width was a requirement a while back.

Answer (score 2):

### View of Stokkalandsvatnet

[image: View from Stokkalandsvatnet in Sandnes, Norway]

> Taken with:
>   Camera: Olympus E-420
>   Focal length: 60 mm
>   Aperture: f/7.1
>   Shutter speed: 1/160

Answer (score 2):

**[Floating Format](http://500px.com/photo/78518299/floating-format-by-imtiaz-emu?from=user_library)**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Evening Church View**

[image: Evening Church View]

> Camera: Olympus FE-210

Answer (score 2):

### Macro Flowers

[image: Macro Flowers]

[Larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51kLG.jpg)

0.5s f/16 ISO 200

Answer (score 2):

**Little FLY trying to be in focus :D**

[image]

Here's a click from my garden. Captured with my Samsung j5 using PicsArt app's camera, AutoFocus, Unprocessed, original picture

Answer (score 2):

*No, you can't have my fish!*

Camera: Canon 700D + 70-300 lens
Settings: 1/400, ISO 400, f6.3, 300mm, no flash
Location: Mures river, Arad, Romania
Post-processing: Gimp - crop and resize

[image]

A little bit bigger versions on [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BBDs2MLFUzm) or [facebook](https://web.facebook.com/photozz.zz/photos/a.205758723105431.1073741834.205693383111965/205759019772068)

Answer (score 2):

**Miles to go before I sleep**

[image]

captured with picsart App camera.

Device : samsung j5

[see full size image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghrYt.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Taken with a 300mm lens.

Full resolution can be found [here](https://flic.kr/p/GkVgyS).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A view from one of the paths going into the Grand Canyon

[image: Grand Canyon]

Cannon EOS Rebel T2i • `1/30, f/32, ISO 100`

[View full size image here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jojodmo/27470714031)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

### Work in progress

Comment: Please make sure all your images are no more than 210 px high, and 375 wide.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

### Wyanne, mother of Dotty

Answer (score 2):

My Submission:

[image: A bee doing its job]

You can find the enlarged image here: http://atulbhats.com/file/se2.jpg

Clicked with Xiaomi Mi4i Smartphone with 13MP, f/2 camera

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Taken in Mexico.

[image]

```
Camera: Samsung
```

Comment: This submission seems to have been downvoted illegally

Answer (score 2):

[image: LA subway, NYE, 31 Dec 2016]

NYE subway in LA

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Nature's Curves

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Original image Link : [ClickHere](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_modKDkygByRDFZemRxcXNQZ2c)

Location : Meenambakkam, Chennai, Tamilnadu.

Cam : samsung note 3 neo.

Answer (score 2):

***Alone.***
Nikon D3100

```
Shutter:1/800  
Aperture f/5.6  
ISO-200  
Focal Length:200mm
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJZyT.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### hgoG naV

[image]

Abstract reflections, taken outside the Van Gogh Museum, Amsterdam, Netherlands.

```
Nikon D7000
Nikon 18-135mm @ 48mm
f/9
1/125 sec
ISO-250
```

Comment: This entry has been downvoted, which is against the rules -- the downvote will not be counted.

Comment: Great title for a great picture!

Comment: @descheleschilder Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Apple iPhone 6S, f/2.2, 1/299 sec.

Taken in [Cambridge, on the River Cam. (52.2084N, 0.1158E)](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@52.2084,0.1158,21z?hl=en), facing North.

Full size [avaliable on iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/#B0JGY8gBYL1oz6)

Comment: My curiosity is provoked: why did you choose to shoot the scene facing north rather than the scene facing south from the exact same spot?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I did both - south when we punted there, north punting back. Unfortunately we were very off centre on the river, so the bridge is at a frustrating angle - hopefully one day I will get to try again!

Answer (score 2):

**A family**

[image: A family]

Answer (score 2):

The ugly bee.

[image: Friendly Bee]

```
Camera: Samsung SM-G965W (S9+)
Aperture: F2.4
Focal length: 4.30mm
ISO 50
Exposure time: 1/645 s
```

Answer (score 2):

**Prambanan Temple, Indonesia**

[image: Prambanan Temple, Indonesia]

Using OPPO A83 Camera

Answer (score 2):

[image: Town hall, Stockholm, Sweden]

**Town hall, Stockholm, Sweden**

[Find more information and full sized photo on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stockholm_town_hall_from_court.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Ornamental basin from 1663, exhibited in the Kunsthistorisches Museum.]

**Ornamental basin from 1663, exhibited in the Kunsthistorisches Museum.**

[See larger version of the photo and more information on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wien-khm-kunstkammer-basin-0.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Do squirrels eat their crusts last?

[image: Pizza!]
Click to see larger image.

```
Camera: Samsung SM-G965W (S9+) 
Aperture: F2.4 
Focal length: 6.00mm 
ISO: 32
Exposure time: 1/100 s
Zoom: 10x
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: treetop on a stormy day in Los Angeles]

Fujifilm X-E1, 300 mm f/6.3 catadioptric lens, 1/60 s.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Gavle-vallbacksskolan-1]

**Vallbacksskolan, Gävle, Sweden**
School building built in 1897, architect Herman Teodor Holmgren (1842–1914).  [See full sized photo on Commons.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gavle-vallbacksskolan-1.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Monument to Eugene Delacroix, Jardin du Luxumbourg, Paris, France, July 2019]

Monument to Eugene Delacroix, Jardin du Luxumbourg, Paris, France, July 2019

Answer (score 2):

**Perched Hummingbird**

[image]

Camera: Nikon Coolpix L120

Specs: f/5.8 - 1/250 sec. - ISO 80

Answer (score 2):

On the prowl:

[image: Skunk on the prowl at night, closeup]

```
Camera: Samsung SM-G965W (S9+) 
Aperture: F1.5
Focal length: 4.30mm 
ISO: 1250
Exposure time: 1/6 s
Zoom: 1x (4 feet away)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sony a6300 with a Görlitz Telemegor 250mm F5.5 / ISO 2000 / 1:1000

It was a quite normal day, no rain and the sun was quite diffused by the clouds in the afternoon. The dove was drinking some water from the roof, I was almost sitting on the floor to get a steady shot. I picked a higher shutterspeed, so I can freeze the dove. It paid off, even if I had to increase the ISO quite a bit. I love the little waterdrops in the air, that gives the picture some story IMO.

One thing I am proud of is, that I got the eyes of the dove in focus, probably luck, but maybe a good "guess" with the manual focus on this old lens.

And this bokeh, I just love it !

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Leap

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Friendly ducks!**

[image]

[Large size](http://files.rahimi.id.ir/photos/ducks-large.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Picture of a swamp rat in Melbourne, Australia.

Bigger picture at: https://flic.kr/p/CyKT7n

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Cactus as it grows in Kerala, India]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Black swans after their grandiose performance

[image]

[Full size link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/146708456@N05/29155063220/in/album-72157672354416861/)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

After the rain, little waterfall on the castle's floor, Castle of Lleida, Spain.

[the original](https://www.flickr.com/photos/146834039@N08/30102123816/in/album-72157674815960025/)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Large version of the photograph can be found [here](https://i.imgur.com/EsOptE5.jpg).

Comment: This answer has been downvoted illegally

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> SONY DSC RX-100 M3
>
> 8.8 mm / 4.0
>
> ISO: 125
>
> 1/320 sec

Comment: "Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide"

Comment: This has a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

**life like a leaf**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Peace!

[image]

iPhone 7.
Light Adjustment using Photos(Mac) application.

Answer (score 1):

***Industrial Decay***

[image: Part of one of the abandoned gravity fed wagon ways at Llanberis Quarry in North Wales]

Shot on a Fujica ST705 using stock Fujinon 55mm kit lens on Bergger Pancro 400 film - 1/500s exposure at f16.

I have slightly reduced the brightness to accentuate the shading, but no other edits have been made aside from cropping to meet the entry requirements.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A cardboard house made from some pieces of wood and cardboard.

Answer (score 1):

**Christ the Redeemer**

[image: Christ the Redeemer]

Rio de Janeiro - Brazil

Answer (score 1):

Standalone Gold
[image]

Taken with: Sony DSC - S85

Reason: I chose this because I like the way that the background is blurred and the sun makes the flower glow.

Comment: Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide to qualify.

Answer (score 1):

**Venkateshwara Swamy**[image]

This was taken with my point and shoot https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/675614-REG/Canon_4181B001_PowerShot_SD1400_IS_Digital.html.  Since it was so bright there, I  put a setting in the camera called beach. Basically it makes the sun light on the Venkateshwara swamy structure look natural and it wont make it  brighter then how it is naturally. I like this photo because of the decoration and because of the sunlight that makes the Venkateshwara Swamy glow. Sorry for the date stamp.

Comment: Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide to qualify.

Answer (score 1):

[image: LONELY MOOD]

### ATMOSPHERE

With some editing, I tried to capture the atmosphere of an Ischian sunset.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Bee enjoying herself some nectar on our balcony.

Nikon D5600
f/5.6 1/1000s ISO-400 70mm
Sigma 17-70mm f/2.8-4.0 HSM MACRO

Answer (score 0):

[image]