# How to download larger version of image in banner?

Tags: feature-request

There is a snowflake image right now on the banner and I want to download full-screen version of it to set it as a wallpaper. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [photo contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) displays the current winner as well as upcoming winners. They sometimes link to larger versions in their entry, however it's usually courteous to ask the photographer if it's okay that you use their image even for something like a wallpaper.