# How can a view full image which is shown at the header part of site

Tags: discussion

How can i see the original full preview of the image shown at the top of the [photo.stackexchange.com](http://photo.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the [contest question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) on meta, the current header image will still be there until next week when the new winner is chosen. After that, you'd have to have sufficient rep to see deleted answers in order to do that as the link doesn't carry to the hall of fame.

Comment: And a full res version of the image is available only if the OP gave a link to it. Some do, some don't.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto - True, though most of them do supply a link.

Comment: Also do note that while the small size version used in the header is required to be released under CC WIKI, it is not necessarily the case of the full version if you were considering reuse.