# Auto-updating link to Image of the Week

Tags: feature-request, featured-photo

I was reading over [Weekly Featured Image: Ongoing Contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest), and I joined Photography strictly to see the image, and vote on some other pictures. I am in no way a professional photographer, as I use simply point-and-shoot digital cameras, and my cell phone. I do, however, love the photos that get selected every week!

Is there a way, built in to the website or SE, that we can find the URL automatically of the photo, and use a method on our individual PCs to save the image as our background? Bing Search does the same type of thing, with much larger images.

If such a function is not possible, would it be appropriate to raise this request on Meta.SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This probably wouldn't effectively be possible.  It might be possible to make a link that would be updated with the header version of the image, but it would be far too small to use as a background.

While full size images are often made available, they fall outside the licensing scope required for use in the contest and are not necessarily licensed for personal use of the image.  Only the small version actually has to be released under CC-Wiki.