# How to participate in weekly hall of fame contest

Tags: discussion, contest, hall-of-fame

Hi I have been watching there is contest going on like hall of fame, winners photos will be displayed on the sites header.

Can anybody help me how to participate inthat contest (if really there is contest)

for that do I need reputation if so How much ?

I have searched in site but I did not find any

Please help
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contest is hosted here on Meta - [Weekly Feature Image: Ongoing Contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and you have sufficient reputation to participate. Please read the rules and conditions, especially around image size, carefully and enjoy.

Good luck!

Comment: Is that same place for every week to post photos ? Do you suggest me to bookmark that question to post my pics for every week contest

Comment: @looser - yes, it's ongoing.