# How do I submit a photo for the weekly contest?

Tags: discussion, contest

I´ve been on the weekly foto contest page, but it´s not clear how to upload a photo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go right down to the [bottom of the contest page](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest?answertab=active#tab-top), and click on the Answer This Question button.  The editor that appears has an image button to upload your image.

Comment: I clicked the Answer this question button but no editor appeared with an image button to upload an image. I think the Answer this question button is only for answering questions!

Comment: the contest is a question, and you definitely submit photos as "answers" to that question.  There is a warning that pops up saying there are >200 answers, are you sure you want to answer this question.  Are you seeing that?  Possibly try another browser?

Comment: I finally know what you meant! Thanks!

Comment: I see it now.  Nice image!

Comment: Once again: Thanks. I also wrote a body of text, but that isn´t visible. Do you how to make it visible?

Comment: Fixed it for you :)

Comment: From now on I´m gonna call you Big Mike!!

Comment: @MikeW could you explain when selecting is it time sensitive? Posted within the week? The month? The year? I can't figure it out or find the information

Comment: Post images anytime you like. Roughly each week or 10 days we choose the one with the most accumulated votes and post that one up and remove it from the list.  So the ones you see posted have been around for many months (or years).  We have discussed refreshing the contest to start over periodically, but haven't yet done so.