# How can I also show the people see a big version of the photograph I send in?

Tags: support, featured-photo

If I send in a photo to show, I see many examples of photo's of which you can also let the people see the big version of your send in photo. How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're talking about the photo contest, correct?

The syntax to make an image link somewhere else is:

```
[![image alt (hover) text][embedded-image]][linked-image]

 [embedded-image]: https://example.com/small.jpg
 [linked-image]: https://example.com/full-size.jpg
```

For example, using your most recent submitted photo, I can do this:

```
[![The small version is displayed][small]][big]

 [small]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97kfns.jpg 
 [big]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97kfn.jpg
```

(I made the embedded image small by appending `s` to the end of the filename (but before `.jpg`). This is a feature of imgur.com (the image hosting service for Stack Exchange))

[image: The small version is displayed]

The link destination doesn't have to be an image; it can be any destination URL. I often do this when I embed images from Wikipedia in my answers — I'll make the image link go to the Wikimedia Commons page where I actually got the image from.

Comment: +1 but beware off-site links — or even images uploaded to imgur outside of the Stack Exchange form. Stack Exchange has a contract with imgur to provide hosting, and so images uploaded here are going to stay as long as SE is up. Other links might vanish, and it's super-annoying when they do. Even on Wikipedia, stuff might move around.

Comment: @mattdm great point. Just to clarify my usage of external links to Wikipedia, I embed a copy of the image locally (because WP images are licensed CC BY-SA, CC0, or public domain), and then link to the source of the image (the commons.wikimedia.org page for the image). [Example of link destination](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lens1.svg).  This is consistent with best practices for using and crediting CC BY-SA content.