# How do I upload my picture for the " Photo of the week" thing?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to this community and I have a trouble in uploading a picture. Where am I supposed to be uploading to get in to the contest and how? Could you please be brief?

Answer (score 2):

You make an answer on this post:

[Weekly Featured Image: Ongoing Contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest)

It is protected so it requires 10 reputation on the site to post an answer.  Note that even if you have an association bonus from having high enough rep on another site, you need 10 reputation on Photography specifically.