# Several 404s when visiting the website

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When I was visiting the photo.SE yesterday, I noticed the following:

[image: 404]

In case these links go broken again, these SE files for banners etc. should not be kept on imgur IMO.

Update: I can't seem to upload a screenshot but this might be a Safari thing. I'll try downloading Chrome and redoing it.

Answer (score 1):

[Stack Exchange has an agreement with imgur.com for image hosting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60821/175991). The missing banner image you're seeing at the top of the page in your screenshot is the current winner of the [Weekly Featured Image Contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) weekly winner of the Photo of the Week contest here at Photo.SE. The image is manually rotated by moderators every week.

Submitters to the weekly featured image contest upload their photos to imgur, using Stack Exchange's "upload an image" function.

I'm not sure site mods have the ability to add image resources to Stack Exchange's servers. The ability to SE to "host" images for answers was specifically why they contracted with imgur.

Comment: But why did they break?

Comment: Don't know. Can't repro here. ;-) But more seriously, there are a whole host of reasons that could be on your end, or could be because you happened to request a page when a mod saved an edit with a typo, or... or... Can it repro for you?

Comment: Oh, do you see them?

Comment: Yes. Do you still not? Are you running an particular extensions that might block imgur? Are you connecting through a proxy that doesn't pass imgur links? I'm just grabbing at straws here...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot that our country banned imgur but where I work doesn't have that restriction.

Comment: Oh wow. That certainly explains the issue then.